# How can I find out whether a number is a quadratic residue in a large modulo?

Tags: number-theory, math-software

Without strenuous arithmetic.

Is there a program I can download to do so?

What are the quadratic residues modulo $5^4$ or $5^5$?

Thanks!

Comment: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=what+are+the+quadratic+residue+modulo+3125 for example.

Answer (score 6):

The [Euler criterion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_criterion) is easily generalized to yield the following test for squareness $\!\rm\bmod n$.

**Theorem** $\ $ Let $\rm\ a,\:n\:$ be integers, with $\rm\:a\:$ coprime to $\rm\:n\ =\ 2^e p_1^{e_1}\cdots p_k^{e_k},\, \ p_i\,$ primes.

$\rm\quad\quad \ x^2\ =\ a\pmod{n}\, $ is solvable for $\rm\:x\:$

$\rm\quad\quad \: \iff\ \ \: a^{(p_i\ -\ 1)/2} \ \ \equiv\ \ 1\ \ (mod\ p_i)\quad\quad\ \ $  for all $\rm\ i\le k$

$\quad\quad\ $ and $\rm\quad\ \ e>1 \:\Rightarrow\: a\equiv 1\ \ (mod\ 2^{2+\delta}\:),\ \ \ \delta = 1\ \ if\ \ e\ge 3\ \ else\ \ \delta = 0$

**Proof**: See Ireland and Rosen,  A Classical Introduction to Modern Number Theory, Proposition 5.1.1 p. 50.

The above criterion is practical if one knows a full factorization of $\rm\:n\:$, since the exponentiations may be quickly computed by repeated squaring.

**Beware** $\ $ The criterion *cannot* be expressed equivalently as a simple [Jacobi symbol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobi_symbol) calculation. For example we have $\rm(8|15) = 1\ $ but $8$ is not a square (mod $15$).

Comment: Just in case anyone got confused like me, to be clear, if `n = 2^1 * 3^1 * 5^0 * 7^1`, then `p_i = {3, 7}`, NOT `{3, 5, 7}`

Answer (score 5):

If you want to know the squares modulo $p^m$ where $p$ is an odd prime,
they are congruent to $0$ or to numbers $a p^{2k}$ where $0\le k < m/2$
and the Legendre symbol $\left(\frac ap\right)=1$. For large primes $p$,
Legendre symbols can be calculated by regarding them as
[Jacobi symbols](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobi_symbol) and using the law of quadratic reciprocity
for Jacobi symbols.

I don't regard $5$ as a large prime. :-)

Comment: And there are many freely available software packages that use arbitrary-precision integers and can efficiently compute Legendre symbols.  In linux, Pari would be one.  The underlying code is called the GNU Multi-Precision library.  As Asaf Karagila points out, there are on-line applications as well.

Comment: Pari is also available for Windows and Mac OS X.

Answer (score 1):

Here is some code for answering whether $a$ is a quadratic residue modulo $n$, that correctly handles the case when $\gcd(a, n) > 1$, and also when $a$ or $n$ may be negative (except of course $n$ can't be zero).

```
def peel(a, p):
    # Returns (k, b) such that a = p^k * b and b is minimal.
    if a == 0: return (1, 0)
    k = 0
    while a % p == 0:
        k += 1
        a = a // p
    return (k, a)

def is_quadratic_residue(a, n):
    for (p, e) in factor(n):
        (k, b) = peel(a % p**e, p)
        if b == 0: continue
        if k % 2: return False
        if p == 2:
            if e == 1: continue
            if b % 4 != 1: return False
            if e >= 3 and b % 8 != 1: return False
        else:  # Euler's criterion
            if power_mod(b, (p - 1)//2, p) != 1:
                return False
    return True
```

As you can see above, it is written in Python, and further relies on two functions (which are available in [Sage](http://www.sagemath.org/), but if you're using this elsewhere you'd have to implement yourself):

- a `factor(n)` which returns a list of pairs `(p, e)` such that the product of these $p_i^{e_i}$ is $n$ — for example, `factor(126)` returns `[(2,1), (3,2), (7,1)]` because $126 = 2^1 3^2 7^1$.
- a `power_mod(x, n, p)` that returns $x^n \bmod p$. This is easy to implement yourself using repeated squaring.
- it relies on the fact that `a % m` always returns a positive result when `m` is positive, even if `a` is negative. This is how [Python does it](http://python-history.blogspot.com/2010/08/why-pythons-integer-division-floors.html), but if you're using one of the languages that [do it differently](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Modulo_operation&oldid=892599239#Remainder_calculation_for_the_modulo_operation), you may have to change some of the definitions (not a big deal; instead of `x % p != 1` you can check `(x - 1) % p != 0`).

---

A sidenote: you may wonder whether it's possible to answer whether $a$ is a quadratic residue mod $n$, without factoring $n$. If it were possible to do so *and* also find a square root when $a$ is a quadratic residue, then this would give an algorithm for factoring: pick random $x$ and ask whether $x^2 \bmod n$ is a quadratic residue; if you get a square root $y$ then with probability $1/2$ the fact that $x^2 \equiv y^2 \pmod n$ gives a nontrivial factorization of $n$ by taking $\gcd(n, x-y)$. For only answering yes or no (the [quadratic residuosity problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Quadratic_residuosity_problem&oldid=864436718)), it is believed to be hard as well (not known whether it is equivalent to factoring, and not known to be easier than factoring).

Comment: **Note** the code is simply a Python implementation of the Theorem in my answer (posted $9$ years prior).

Comment: The remark about factoring $n$ given a nontrivial square root is also $9$ years old, e.g. see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4604/242) where more general results are proved.

Comment: @BillDubuque Yes indeed, my main reason for posting an answer with the Python code is that I kept needing it, but every time I looked it up from scratch I'd keep finding answers assuming $\gcd(a, n) = 1$ or that $a, n > 0$ (and not being clear about whether these assumptions mattered). So (for reasons of practical usability) I wanted to do the grunt work carefully and write it down for the general case once, as future reference.

Comment: @BillDubuque (Also the question asked "Is there a program I can download to do so?" which is probably why I posted it here rather than on some other question.)