# How to compute $k$'th roots $\!\bmod m$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, cryptography

I have the following equation:

$$
n \equiv M^k\pmod b
$$

where $n, k, b$ are integers, and $M$ is an unknown integer. How can I solve this equation to find $M$? Here $k$ and $b$ are public keys of the RSA algorithm and $n$ is the result of encryption. I need to find the encrypted message.

Comment: Decimal numbers? Don't you mean integers?

Comment: @naslundx
yes, my bad

Comment: Read this http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_(cryptosystem)

Answer (score 4):

Generally it's difficult to compute such $\rm\:k$'th roots in $\rm \mathbb Z/b\ $ except for simple special cases, e.g. [when $\rm\ gcd(k,\phi(b)) = 1.\,$](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3188192/242) Otherwise one generally has to resort to factoring $\rm\:b\:$ to get $\rm\: \phi(b)\: $ and hence the factorization of $\rm\ \Bbb Z/b^*\ $ into a product of cyclic groups. Then one may apply generalizations of the [Shanks or Tonelli square-root algorithm.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tonelli%E2%80%93Shanks_algorithm) See for example Section 3.2: Extensions of Shanks's algorithm to r'th roots in cyclic groups in Lindhurst: [Computing roots in finite fields and groups, with a jaunt through sums of digits](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.144.2770&rep=rep1&type=pdf). One can also generalize the Euler criterion for square-roots - see my [post here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/5424/how-can-i-find-out-whether-a-number-is-a-quadratic-residue-in-a-large-modulo/5433#5433) and Chapter 4 of Ireland and Rosen, *A Classical Introduction to Modern Number Theory.*