# If the congruence $ x^2 \equiv n \bmod{P} $ has a solution then $(n \mid p_i) = 1 $ for each prime $ p_i $ that divides $ P $

Tags: number-theory, analytic-number-theory, quadratic-residues, legendre-symbol

From section 9.7 "The Jacobi symbol" of Introduction to Analytic Number Theory by Tom M. Apostol

> **Definition** If $P$ is a positive odd integer with prime factorization $$ P = \prod_{i=1}^r p_i^{a_i} $$ the Jacobi symbol $(n \mid P)$ is defined for all integers $n$ by the equation
> $$
> (n \mid P) = \prod_{i=1}^r (n \mid p_i)^{a_i}, \tag{6}
> $$
> where $(n \mid p_i)$ is the Legendre symbol. We also define $(n \mid 1) = 1$.
>
> The possible values of $(n \mid P)$ are $ 1 $, $-1$, or $0$, with $(n \mid P) = 0 $ if and only if $(n, P) > 1.$
>
> If the congruence $$ x^2 \equiv n \bmod{P}$$ has a solution then $(n | p_i) = 1$ for each prime $p_i$ in (6), and hence $(n \mid P) = 1$.

Is the last sentence true? It does not seem true to me. For example, take $n = 9$ and $P=15$, so we get the congruence $x^2 \equiv 9 \bmod {15} $. This congruence clearly has a solution $x = 3$. But the Legendre symbol $(9 \mid 3) = 0$, so it contradicts the claim that $(n \mid p_i) = 1$ for each prime $p_i$ in (6).

Is the book incorrect here or am I missing something?

Comment: You're correct: the additional assumption $(n,P)=1$ is required for the implication to be true.

Comment: See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/5433/242) for a correct statement (and generalization)