# Is there a possibility that we graph a sub-plane in xy plane using an equation based on 2 variables?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

An equation with 2 variables (x and y) is observed to be giving a graph of a point or a curve at most, in xy-plane. But since an Equation with 2 variables can give a graph of multiple points (a curve), ain't it make it possible for such an equation to give a graph of a sub-plane (a plane smaller than xy-plane) that lies anywhere in xy-plane ?

I mean we may yet haven't found such a 2 variables-based equation but there is always a possibilty that such entity exists, right?

**In case you haven't got me:**

If you haven't got me yet here I have something for you that might help. Suppose we have a random equation in 2 variables xy-3x=6, we all know that when we plot these kind of equations in xy-plane, we get a curve. So my question is, can there be a similar equation (equation in 2 variables; x and y) which actually gives us a graph of a plane (surface) when we plot it in xy-plane? I mean, can it (equation in 2 variables) give us the coordinates (x, y) of a rectanglular region or any 2D-region upon solving?

Comment: Your assumptions are wrong, even for the one-variable case. $x=|x|$ gives the entire non-negative real line, not a point.

Comment: But when you are not in xy-plane i.e you have only x axis, x=x defines a point only but I got you. I should have made it clear. @ParclyTaxel

Comment: `graph of a sub-plane (a plane smaller than xy-plane)` What does that even mean?

Comment: `can it (equation in 2 variables) give us the coordinates of a rectangle (x, y)` For example $\,(x^2-1)^2+(y^2-1)^2=0\,$ has the vertices of the unit square $\,(\pm1, \pm1)\,$ as solutions, if that's what the question is about.

Comment: @dxiv i mean a simple plane drawn in xy-plane. Suppose you draw a rectangle on a page, considering the page as the xy-plane. That kind of plane.

Comment: `a simple plane drawn in xy-plane` There is no such thing math-wise. A rectangle is not a plane, and the interior of a rectangle is not a plane, either. It would help your question if you clarified what you are asking in terms others can understand.

Comment: Ok I will try. Thanks.

Comment: Made an Edit @dxiv have a look

Answer (score 2):

Using that $\,a+|a|=0 \iff a \le 0\,$:

- $\,y-|y|=0\,$ represents the upper half-plane $\,y \ge 0\,$;
- $\,x^2+y^2-1+|x^2+y^2-1| = 0\,$ represents the unit disc $\,x^2+y^2 \le 1\,$;
- $\,\big(x^2-1+|x^2-1|\big)^2+\big(y^2-1+|y^2-1|\big)^2=0\,$ represents the square $\,x,y \in [-1,1]\,$.

---

[ *EDIT* ]   If the equations are restricted to *polynomial* equations, however, then the answer is negative:  if the zero set of a bivariate polynomial includes an open disk then the polynomial is identically zero on the entire plane, in other words it is the zero polynomial (see e.g. [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/36970/a-polynomial-that-is-zero-on-an-open-set)). Therefore it is not possible to write a polynomial equation whose solution set is the interior of a 2D curve.

Answer (score 1):

I don't quite understand what you want but maybe it is something like this,

$$
x+y < 5
$$

This when [graphed](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/kfvjpdhex9) looks like what you are calling a "sub-plane"

Is this what you wanted?

Note that you can easily get the whole $XY$ plane by writing something like this,

$$
x^2 + y^2 \geq0
$$

If you only want a equation and not an inequality then a example would be,

$$
x+y = x+y
$$

This also maps the whole $XY$ plane.

Comment: x+y=x+y becomes 0=0. And I can't really imagine it being plotted. Any additions?

Comment: @Anonymous $0=0$ is another way of saying that no restrictions on the points you can choose. Any point will satisfy the self identity $x+y=x+y$ hence all the points on the $XY$ plane will be plotted.