# In a finite field there exists an irreducible polynomial of degree at least $n$ for $n \in \mathbb{N}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, finite-fields, irreducible-polynomials

This question already has an answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/144703/existence-of-irreducible-polynomials-over-finite-field), but I'm looking for a solution that doesn't use field extensions. It's relatively easy to find a polynomial without zeros for every $n$ but as far as I know this doesn't imply that the polynomial is irreducible (maybe in a finite field it does?). Thank you for your answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $F$ be a finite field of characteristic $p$ and let $n\in\Bbb{N}$. Let $k$ be an integer coprime to $p$. Then the polynomial $x^k+1$ is separable over $F$, so it is a product of *distinct* irreducible factors. For any degree $d$ there are only finitely many (irreducible) polynomials of degree $d$ with coefficients in $F$, so for sufficiently large values of $k$ it must have an irreducible factor of degree $n$.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint** use Euclid's idea: consider $1+p_1\cdots p_k$ where the $p_i$ are all irreducibles of degree $< n$

Comment: If two polynomials have different values for every element in the field, does this imply they can't be the same polynomial? If so the answer follows quickly.

Comment: OK, never mind, don't have an answer.

Comment: @InsertNameHere It's not clear how your question is related to the above answer. Do you understand the answer?  There are many prior answers that discuss formal vs. functional polynomials, e.g. [here.](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/25030/242)