# Square root of 1

Tags: arithmetic

I know this is a dumb question but I can't get the answer to another follow up question,

1. What is the square root of 1?
2. If the square root of 1 is itself then why does other square root of number not equal to themselves?
3. Is there other square root of 1 aside from 1?

This question is somewhat a deconstruction of the fundamental logic of mathematical concepts but I can't find a good reason to answer this questions. Hoping for a good reason.

[Edit] if we're going to talk about principal square roots then therefore -1 would be included but i'm only referring to non negative numbers therefore 
3.1. if there are other square root of 1 which could be between 0 and 1?

Comment: no one has mentioned that $0 \cdot 0 = 0$. This can be attained from the equation $x^2=x \implies x(x-1)=0 \implies x=0 \, \mathrm{ or } \, 1$

Comment: The square of a positive number less than 1 is less than itself: $0\lt x\lt 1$ implies $0\lt x^2\lt x$ (multiplying through by $x$); so no number between $0$ and $1$ can be the square root of a larger number (in particular, of $1$).

Comment: @sergiol No it doesn't: $-1^2=1\not=-1$. 

What you might be confused by: $-1$ *does* satisfy $x^2=\sqrt{x^2}$, but that's because square roots don't work the way they "should."

Answer (score 20):

In a *field* such as $\,\mathbb Q,\ \mathbb R,\ \mathbb C,\,$ we have $ \ x^2 = 1 \iff (x-1) (x+1) = 0\iff x = \pm 1.\, $ In rings that are not fields there can be more than two square-roots, e.g. modulo $15$ there are two additional roots $ \ (\pm\,4)^2\equiv 1\pmod{\!15}.\,$ In some contexts authors define single-valued square-root *functions* that uniformly select one of the roots, e.g. the non-negative root, or principal branch, etc.

In ring theory we can adjoin a "sign" = *generic* square root of one $\,s = \pm1\,$ to a ring $ \,R\,$ as follows $ R[s]\cong R[x]/(x^2\!-\!1).\,$ If $\,2\,$ is invertible, CRT $\Rightarrow R[s] \cong R[x]/(x\!-\!1) \times R[x]/(x\!+\!1)\ \cong R^2,\, $ via $\, f(x)\to (f(1),f(-1));\,$ informally, this ring product implements arithmetic in two parallel universes (rings), where in the first world we have $\,s = 1\,$ , and $\, s = -1\,$ in the second.

As to your second question concerning why there aren't other numbers that are their own square root, note that $ \ \sqrt{x} = x\ \Rightarrow x = x^2\ \Rightarrow\ x\ (x-1) = 0\ $ so $ \,x = 0\,$ or $ \,x = 1\,$ in a field (or domain). Elements satisfying $ \ x^2 = x\ $ are known as *idempotents*. Idempotents that are nontrivial ($\ne\, 0,1$) are intimately connected with nontrivial factorizations. In the above example $\,\mathbb Z/15 =$ integers $\!\bmod 15,\,$ we have a factorization $ \mathbb Z/15 \cong \mathbb Z/3 \times \mathbb Z/5\,$ arising from idempotent $\,6,\,$ i.e. $ (0,1)\in \mathbb Z/3 \times \mathbb Z/5.\,$ Note that if $ \,e\,$ is idempotent then $ \,(1\!-\!2\,e)^2 = 4\,(e^2\!-\!e)+1 = 1,\, $ so $ \,2e\!-\!1\,$ is a square-root of $1;\,$ it is a nontrivial square root $ \,2e\!-\!1\ne \pm 1\,$ if $\,2\,$ is cancellable. In our example $ \,e=6,\,$ so $ \,1\!-\!2e \equiv 4\,$ which does indeed square to $ \,1\pmod{\!15}.\,$ We can quickly factor $15$ from this nontrivial sqrt $ \,s,\,$ namely $ \,\gcd(15,s-1) = \gcd(15,3) = 3\,;$ $ \ \gcd(15,s+1) = \gcd(15,5) = 5.\,$ In fact many integer factorization algorithms work by searching for nontrivial square-roots. This way of factoring by simple gcd computations works more generally. One can quickly factor $ \,n\,$ given any polynomial with more roots $\!\bmod n\,$ than the degree of the polynomial - see my [post here.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4597/simple-explanation-and-examples-of-the-miller-rabin-primality-test/4604#4604)

Comment: Dear Bill, sorry for going off-topic, but out of curiosity, why do you typeset all your variables in a roman (i.e. not italic) style?

Comment: @Rahul: I find the default italic fonts far too ugly. Alas, they messed up the roman fonts too with the recent font changes.

Comment: If on your system the default italic font here looks different from the typesetting that TeX produces, then that could be a website/browser incompatibility issue worth raising on Meta. (On the other hand, if it looks just like TeX output, and you just don't like the look of TeX, then never mind...)

Answer (score 6):

1. The square root of $1$ is $1$.
2. This is because the number $1$ has the special property $1\cdot 1=1$. This is not true for $2$, for instance: $2\cdot 2$ is not $2$.
3. Yes, there is another number $x$ with $x^2=1$, namely $x=-1$. Usually, this solution is not called a square root of $1$, however, because you want "square root" to be a function, so that its value has to be unique.

Edit: To see that there are no further solution to $x^2=1$, notice that $x^2=1$ implies $(x+1)(x-1)=0$ and thus $x=\pm 1$.

Comment: aside from 1 or -1?

Comment: @rich  I included an answer to this in my answer.

Comment: i have edited my description on the question to give you further details thanks for the reply

Answer (score -2):

1. The square root of $1$ is $\pm1$.
2. $1$ is the only number which when multiplied by itself equals $1$.
3. $-1$ multiplied by itself equals $1$.

Comment: "The" square root refers to the principal branch of the square root; to make square root into a function, we pick the nonnegative one, so "The" square root of $1$ is $1$, not $\pm 1$ (if it was really two things, it would be "the square root **s**" not "the square root"). You are confusing $\sqrt{1}$ with "solutions of $x^2=1$". The first clause of your second statement contradicts the second clause of that statement.

Comment: Your point 2 is not right. (-1) multiplied by itself gives 1 as result