# Finding the smallest positive integer a

Tags: elementary-number-theory, contest-math

Can we find the smallest positive integer $a$ such that $1971|50^n+a.23^n$ where n is odd?

Source:Problem Solving Strategies by Arthur Engel

Comment: Presumably you want this to hold for **all** odd values of $n$? Is that period between $a$ and $23^n$ a multiplication sign? The TeX-code \cdot gives you that.

Comment: I added an IMHO relevant tag.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

HINT:

1971 = 27 * 73. Use modular arithmetic and congruences.

Comment: My answer is 512.I used Diophantine equations to minimize a.Thank you for the suggestion.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: $50^2\equiv 23^2\pmod{1971}$

Comment: Nicer idea than the solution in Engel's book.

Comment: @Andre: I don't have the book. What is the solution?

Comment: @mixedmath: $50^n+23^n a\equiv (-4)^n +(-4)^na\equiv -4^n(a+1) \pmod{27}$, $50^n+23^n a \equiv (-23)^n +23^n a \equiv 23^n(a-1)\pmod{73}$. Then standard solving of $a\equiv -1\pmod{27}$, $a\equiv 1\pmod{73}$.

Answer (score 1):

For coprime $\rm\: b,c\in \mathbb Z\:,\ \  a\: =\: -(b/c)^{2\:k+1} =\: -(b^2/c^2)^{k}\ b/c\: \equiv\: -b/c \pmod{b^2-c^2}\:.\:$
So the extended Euclidean algorithm will efficiently  compute $\rm\:a \equiv -b/c\pmod{b^2-c^2}\:.$

Alternatively note $\rm\:a\equiv -1\pmod{b-c}$ since then $\rm\  b\equiv c\ \Rightarrow\ a = -b/c \equiv -c/c\equiv -1\:.\: $
Similarly we infer $\rm\ a\:\equiv\ 1\ \pmod{b+c}\:.\:$ When  $\rm\:b,c\:$ have opposite parity, $\rm\:b-c,\ b+c\:$ are coprime, so we may employ $\rm CRT$ to efficiently  compute the unique solution $\rm\: (mod\ \ b^2-c^2)\:.$

Such nontrivial $(\ne \pm 1)$ square-roots of $1\:$  exist modulo composite $\rm\:m\:$ that are not prime powers. In fact, given such a nontrivial square root $\rm\:a\:$ one may  compute a factor of $\rm\:m\:$ by $\rm\:gcd(a\pm1,m)\:,\:$ e.g. above $\rm\ a = 512,\ \ gcd(511,1971) = 73,\ \ gcd(513,1971) = 27\:.\:$ This is the way many integer factoring algorithms work, e.g. Fermat's method of difference of squares and its generalizations, e.g. MPQS. [See here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/33000/square-root-of-1/33028#33028) for more on relations between factorization, nontrivial sqrts and idempotents.

Answer (score 0):

Find the smallest positive integer $n$ for: $$\left(\frac{1+j}{1-j}\right)^n =1;\quad (j^2 =-1)$$

Comment: How is this relevant to the question?

Answer (score 0):

Since $50^2\equiv23^2\equiv529\pmod{1971}$ and $(529,1971)=1$, we have
$$
\begin{align}
50^{2n+1}+a\cdot23^{2n+1}&\equiv0\pmod{1971}\\
50\cdot529^n+a\cdot23\cdot529^n&\equiv0\pmod{1971}\\
50+a\cdot23&\equiv0\pmod{1971}
\end{align}
$$
Using the [Euclid-Wallis Algorithm](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/68021)
$$
\begin{array}{r}
&&85&1&2&3&2\\\hline
1&0&1&-1&3&-10&23\\
0&1&-85&86&-257&857&-1971\\
1971&23&16&7&2&1&0\\
\end{array}
$$
we get that $857\cdot23\equiv1\pmod{1971}$. Therefore,
$$
a\equiv-50\cdot857\equiv512\pmod{1971}
$$