# In how many ways can a debt of $69$ dollars be paid exactly using only $5$ dollar bills and $2$ dollar bills?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, number-theory

I can find the answer by listing all the possible ways but I want to know a more logical way to solve this problem. Can someone help me?

Comment: Start by choosing how many $\$5$ bills there are. There has to be an odd number of $\$5$ bills(by parity). Then the number of $\$2$ bills will follow once you choose the number of $\$5$ bills.

Comment: Would you be interested in seeing a general method to figure out recursions for this kind of thing?

Comment: It can help,  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/80822/solutions-to-linear-diophantine-equation-15x21y-261

Answer (score 2):

Solving this equation $5x+2y=69$ in positive integers

$2y=69-5x$

x is an odd number and $0<x<14$, since $69-5x>0$ is a multiple of 2 and positive that is an even number

There are 7 solutions.

Comment: Sorry, this doesn't help the questioner much. E.g., why "7", in terms of the other parameters? What process did you carry out...?

Answer (score 0):

It is easy to find the first two dozen terms and a lookup in OEIS finds that it is [sequence A008616](https://oeis.org/A008616) which has a generating function of $1/((1-x^2)(1-x^5))$. The entry also has a formula $a(n) = \lfloor n/10+ (3+(-1)^n)/4\rfloor.$ Thus $a(69)=7.$
If you want a list of these solutions you can use an extended g.f. of
$1/((1-x^2)(1-x^5y))$ and get the coefficient of $x^n$ as a polynomial in $y$.