# Proving that $ \gcd(a,b) = as + bt $, i.e., $ \gcd $ is a linear combination.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility

For any nonzero integers $ a $ and $ b $, there exist integers $ s $ and $ t $ such that $ \gcd(a,b) = as + bt $. Moreover, $ \gcd(a,b) $ is the smallest positive integer of the form $ as + bt $.

I know of one proof of this question, in which we consider
$$
S = \{ am + bn ~|~ \text{$ m,n \in \mathbb{Z} $ and $ am + bn > 0 $} \},
$$
but I didn’t manage to get the proof. Can someone please explain this theorem?

Comment: There are two types of standard proof, the one you allude to and the one(s) that trace the Euclidean algorithm for the gcd. The one you mention is slightly abstract, but very quick.

Comment: Some links: [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bezout%27s_identity), [ProofWiki](http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout%27s_Lemma), [AoPSWiki](http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/Wiki/index.php/Bezout%27s_Lemma)

Comment: A different proof: [Proof of Bezout's Lemma using Euclid's Algorithm backwards](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/310637/proof-of-bezouts-lemma-using-euclids-algorithm-backwards)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is known as Bezout's Identity and you can study section 4 of this
[http://math.bard.edu/belk/math332s09/NumberTheory.pdf](https://web.archive.org/web/20170830051222/http://math.bard.edu/belk/math332s09/NumberTheory.pdf)

Comment: This link has expired.

Answer (score 12):

Take the set $$S=\{ax+by>0:x,y\in \Bbb Z\}$$

Without loss of generality, assume that $a<b$. Then $b-a>0$ is in $S$, so $S$ is a nonempty set of positive natural numbers. By the well ordering principle, there exists a least element $d\in S$, which we know is of the form $ax'+by'$. By the division algorithm, there exists $q,r$ with $0\leq r <ax'+by'$ such that $$a=qd+r$$

But then $a-qd=r$ is a nonnegative number of the form $ax+by$ yet smaller than $d$, so it must forcefully be zero. This means that the remainder when $d$ divides $a$ is $0$; which means $d\mid a$. By a completely analogous argument, it follows that $d\mid b$. So $d$ is a common divisor of $a$ and $b$. But if $c$ is any common divisor of $a$ and $b$, it must divide $ax'+by'=d$. By the definition of the $\gcd$, we just proved that $\gcd(a,b)=d$. $\blacktriangle$

Comment: Said succinctly: $ $ S closed under subtraction $\Rightarrow$ S closed under remainder $\Rightarrow$ S closed under gcd. $\ \ $

Comment: What if $a = b$. Is that a trivial case?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not too quick, so I usually find it useful to look at concrete examples (say, $\gcd (83, 56) =1$) before considering the general one.

If you can show why this process (in general) terminates, I think you would be done.

$83 = 1 \times 56 + (83-56)$

$56 = 2 \times (83-56) + (56 - 2 \times (83-56))$

$83-56 = 13 \times (56 - 2 \times (83-56)) + (83-56-(13 \times (56 - 2 \times (83-56))))$

and that last remainder, $1=\gcd(83,56)$.

$1=(83-56-(13 \times (56 - 2 \times (83-56))))$

$1=83-56-(13 \times (-2 \times 83 + 3 \times 56)$

$1 = 83-56 + 26 \times 83 - 39 \times 56$

$1 = 27 \times 83 - 40 \times 56$

And you have your coefficients.

Answer (score 0):

Do you know how to compute the gcd of $a$ and $b$ with the Euclidean algorithm?

If so, an elementary way to produce $s$ and $t$ is to go up the Euclidean algorithm.

This is explained [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm#Mathematical_applications) under Bezout's identity.