# Proving uniqueness that if $S = \{as+bt|as+bt>0, a,b \in \Bbb N\}$ and $d, d' \in S$ and $d|a$, $d|b$, $d'|a$, $d'|b$ $\rightarrow$ $d = d'$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, gcd-and-lcm

I was looking through proofs of [Bezout's identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm#Mathematical_applications), and the various posts ([1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1835304/smallest-positive-element-of-ax-by-x-y-in-mathbbz-is-gcda-b?noredirect=1&lq=1), [2](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/321061/proving-that-gcda-b-as-bt-i-e-gcd-is-a-linear-combination), [3](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/718827/show-gcda-1-a-2-a-3-ldots-a-n-is-the-least-positive-integer-that-can-b)) that $gcd(a,b)$ is a linear combination $as + bt$, but I'm struggling to prove that if $d \in S$ where $S = \{as+bt | as+bt>0, a,b \in \Bbb N\}$ and $d|a$ and $d|b$ that $d$ is necessarily the smallest element in $S$. If not, then $$\exists d,d' \in S,\\ d|a,d|b,\\ d'|a, d'|b, \\d<'d$$ and the smallest element $d \in S$ is not $gcd(a,b)$.

There's some consequence of the proof that I suppose I'm missing, and admittedly, there are infinite choices of $s$ and $t$ which yield the same $d$ smallest element, for example, $d = as + bt \rightarrow d=as+bt+ab-ba=a(s+b)+b(t-a)$ so the choices of $s'=s+b$ and $t'=t-a$ yield $d=as'+bt'=as+bt$, but I'm interested in proving the uniqueness of an element $d\in S$ which divides both $a$ and $b$. Thank you!