# Is $B = A^2 + A - 6I$ invertible when $A^2 + 2A = 3I$?

Tags: linear-algebra

Given:
$$A \in M_{nxn} (\mathbb C), \; A \neq \lambda I, \; A^2 + 2A = 3I$$

Now we define:
$$B = A^2 + A - 6I$$

The question:

> Is $B$ inversable?

Now, what I did is this:

> $A^2 + 2A = 3I \rightarrow \lambda^2v + 2\lambda v = 3v \rightarrow \lambda_1 = 1, \lambda_2 = -3$

Is what I suggested correct? I know that if so, I just do the same to B and calculate the determinant.

Comment: Question 1: What are the eigenvalues of $A$? Question 2: What are the eigenvalues of $A^2+A-6I ?$

Comment: Question 1: Those are the ones that I calculated, IF they exist, no?
Question 2: I just apply B to v and see what I get?

Comment: Note that the factorization $A^2+2A-3I=(A-I)(A+3I)$ implied by your solution of the corresponding quadratic equation can also be used to obtain the equation $(A-I)(A^2+A-6I)=(A-2I)(A^2+2A-3I)$ used in robjohn's answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that
$$
\begin{align}
(A-I)B
&=(A-I)(A^2+A-6I)\\
&=(A-2I)(A^2+2A-3I)\\[4pt]
&=0
\end{align}
$$
Thus, unless $A=I$, and therefore, $B=-4I$, $(A-I)B=0$ implies that $B$ is not invertible.

**Clarification:** Suppose that $B^{-1}$ exists, then
$$
\begin{align}
A-I
&=(A-I)BB^{-1}\\
&=0B^{-1}\\[6pt]
&=0
\end{align}
$$
Thus, if $B^{-1}$ exists, then $A=I$. This is the contapositive of "if $A\ne I$, then $B$ is not invertible".

---

**A bit of explanation**

I used the [Euclid-Wallis Algorithm](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/68021) to try and write $(A^2+A-6I)x+(A^2+2A-3I)y=I$ to compute an inverse for $A^2+A-6I\bmod A^2+2A-3I$:
$$
\begin{array}{c|c}
&&1&-A+I\\\hline
1&0&1&A-I\\
0&1&-1&-A+2I\\
A^2+A-6I&A^2+2A-3I&-A-3I&0
\end{array}
$$
Unfortunately, this showed that $A+3I$ was the GCD of $A^2+A-6I$ and $A^2+2A-3I$. However, this did show that
$$
(A-I)(A^2+A-6I)-(A-2I)(A^2+2A-3I)=0
$$
which was used in the answer above.

Comment: why is it $=0$?

Comment: @TheNotMe: because we are given $A^2+2A=3I$

Comment: If $A\neq I$ then $(A-I)B = 0$ implies that $B=0$ thus its' determinant $=0$ so it is not invertible, and we know that $A\neq I$ so $B$ is for sure $=0$?

Comment: @TheNotMe: I am not appealing to determinants. If $B^{-1}$ exists, then $$\begin{align}A-I&=(A-I)BB^{-1}\\&=0B^{-1}\\&=0\end{align}$$ Thus, if $B^{-1}$ exists, then $A=I$.

Comment: Note that $(A-I)(A^2+A-6I)=(A-2I)(A^2+2A-3I)$ can also be found using the factorization $A^2+2A-3I=(A-I)(A+3I)$ implicit in the OP's solution of the corresponding quadratic equation.

Comment: @joriki: thanks for that; it's nice to have several approaches. I was not trying to imply that what I had done was the only way; I was simply explaining how I came across the answer I gave.

Comment: Sure :-) I just wanted to point that out because it implies that the OP had made more progress towards a solution than it might have seemed.

Comment: @joriki: Ah, nice. I hadn't yet seen your comment to the OP. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

$B=A^{2}+A-6I$

$B=(A+3I)(A-2I)$

$det(B)=det(A+3I)det(A-2I)$

now attention :

$A^{2}+2A=3I$

$A^2+2A-3I=0$    $\to$  $det(A+3I)det(A-I)=0$

$A^2+2A-3I-4A+4I=-4A+4I$

$(A-I)^2=-4(A-I)$ $\to$ $if det(A-I)=-4$ then B willnot be inversable

in other word if -3 or 2 be eigen value of A then B will not be inversable

Comment: indeed this question tell us if 1 not be eigen value of A then -3 will be eigen value and B will not be inversable

Comment: I did not understand why $(A-I)^2 = -4(A-I)$ means that $ifdet(A-I) = -4$ then $B$ will not be inversable.

Comment: if det(A-I) not be equal t0 0 then det(A+3I) must be equal 0 (because  det(A+3I)det(A-I)=0) and so B will not be inversable

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Using Jordan normal form for $A$.

Comment: We have not learned this and I do not think this is the method I should go through! Although I looked it up in wikipedia and it seems very interesting. Thanks, though!

Answer (score 1):

We have 
$$B=-3I-A$$
and we can see easily that the spectrum of $B$ is
$$\mathrm{sp}(B)=\{-3-\lambda_1,-3-\lambda_2\}=\{-4,0\}$$
so $B$ is not invertible.

**Added** Since $A^2+2A-3I=(A+3I)(A-I)=0$ and since $A\not= \lambda I$ then the minimal polynomial of is $x^2+2x-3$ which is  a product of distinct linear factors over $\mathbb{R}$ then $A$ is diagonalisable and $-3$ and $1$ are it's eigenvalues hence there's $P\in\mathrm{GL}_n(\mathbb{R})$ s.t. $A=PDP^{-1}$ where $D$ is a diagonal matrix and then we have $$B=-3I-A=-3PP^{-1}-PDP^{-1}=P(-3I-D)P^{-1}$$
so we can deduce  the spectrum of $B$ from the spectrum of $A$ as explained above.

Comment: Can you please explain how did you calculate the spectrum? (sorry for the stupid question)

Comment: How do you know that $0$ is **indeed** present in the spectrum of $B$?

Comment: Ok, how do you know that $-3$ is **indeed** present in the spectrum of $A$?

Comment: Okay so we know the spectrum is B. And again, excuse me for ANOTHER stupid question (new to diagonalization), why does ${-4,0}$ as a spectrum of a matrix $B$ means that $B$ is not inversable?

Comment: @Sami Ben Romdhane: Sorry, but all eigenvalues of $A$ equal to 1 doesn't imply $A$ is equal to the identity matrix.

Comment: @TheNotMe: The only problem is that "$0$ is in the spectrum" is not yet proven.

Comment: Wait wait. Let us ask this question: Is what I did in the beginning really correct? I mean, what if A has no real eigenvalues? Why am I allowed to calculate eigenvalues if I know not for sure that they exist, as real numbers?

Comment: @SamiBenRomdhane: What about $\left(\begin{array}{cc} 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 1\end{array}\right)$? Who are its eigenvalues? Do you know that there exist non-diagonalisable matrices?

Comment: that all its eigenvalues are equal to 1 and it's not the identity matrix, obviously.

Comment: Can I just say, that regarding the $D$ matrix we found for $B$, that $B$ has a line of zeros, thus, its' determinant is equal $0$, thus, it is non-invertible?

Comment: @SamiBenRomdhane: You've been assuming $A$ is diagonalizable, and other folks haven't. In fact, because the minimal polynomial has distinct roots, $A$ must be diagonalizable.

Comment: So, I assume that what you did is correct?

Comment: @TedShifrin In our case $A$ is diagonalisable as you explained by the minimal polynomial but the method remains the same even $A$ is not diagonalisable since it's at least triangularisable in $\mathbb{C}$

Comment: @Sami Ben Romdhane: I suggest you delete your answer or complete your reasoning. In the present form it is incomplete and simply wrong.

Comment: Once again: what is written presently is wrong, call it hint or whatever you like.

Answer (score 0):

$A$ is a root of the polynomial $x^2 + 2x - 3=(x-1)(x+3).$

Since $A$ is not of the form $\lambda I,$ this is the minimal polynomial of $A.$ 
Consequently $-3$ is an eigenvalue of $A.$

$$\color{red}{B=A^2 + A - 6I=A^2+2A-3I-A-3I=-A-3I}$$

$-3$ is an eigenvalue of $A\implies\det(A+3I)=0\implies\det(-B)=0\implies\det B=0.$