# Find all $x$ such that $11\mid 3x+7$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, divisibility, chinese-remainder-theorem

I found this question in Beachy and Blair: Abstract algebra book, they even have a solution to this but its not satisfactory for me. They only say "$x\equiv 5 \pmod{11}$ ". Which one can "feel" simply by trial and error. I would like to know what is the proper approach. Thank you in advance!

Comment: what has been tried ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We need $3x+7\equiv 0\pmod{11}$

Add 4 to both sides:

$$3x+11\equiv 4\pmod{11}$$

reduce:

$$3x \equiv 4\pmod{11}$$

multiply both sides by a number to make the coefficient on the left equivalent to $1$. In this case, $4$ works:

$$12x\equiv 16\pmod{11}$$

reduce:

$$x\equiv 5\pmod{11}$$

Does that work for you?

Comment: It would help those learning if  you explain *why* you multiplied by $4$ and why/how  you chose the factor $4$.

Answer (score 3):

${\rm mod}\ 11\!:\,\ 3x\equiv -7\equiv 4\iff x\equiv \overbrace{\dfrac{\color{#c00}4}3\equiv \dfrac{\color{#c00}{15}}3}^{\large \color{#c00}{4\  \equiv\ 15}}\equiv 5$

**Remark** $ $ More generally we can use the [extended Euclidean algorithm](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/85830/how-to-use-the-extended-euclidean-algorithm-manually/85841#85841) (esp. simple in [fractional form)](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2100615/242) to invert $3$ modulo $11$. But for small numbers other methods are often simpler, e.g. adding $\pm\rm modulus$ to make the division exact (e.g. above we added $11$ to $\color{#c00}4$ to make it divisible by $3)$

**Beware** $\ $ Modular fraction arithmetic is well-defined only for fractions with denominator *coprime* to the modulus. [See here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/921093/242) for further discussion.

Answer (score 2):

It's simpler to use  congruences: $11\mid 3x+7$ means $3x+7\equiv 0 \mod11$, or 
$$3x\equiv -7\equiv 4\mod4,$$
so all we have to do is finding the inverse of $3$ mod. $11$.

This comes with a *Bézout's relation* obetween $3$ and $11$:
$4\cdot 3-11=1$, thus $4\cdot 3\equiv 1\mod 11$, therefore
$$4\cdot 3x\equiv 4^2\iff x\equiv 5\mod11.$$

Comment: But $x\equiv -5 (mod 11)$ is not correct@Bernard

Comment: @Atul Mishra: I've seen that and already fixed it (I had swapped $-7$ and $4$ in the first display equation). Thanks for pointing it!

Answer (score 2):

$11\mid 3x+7$ is the same thing as saying there exists an integer $y$ such that $3x + 7 = 11y$.

Trying $y=0, 1$ and finally $y=2$, we find that $x=5$ and $y=2$ is a solution. So we consider solutions of the form $x = 5+u$ and $y=2+v$.

\begin{align}
   3x + 7 &= 11y \\
   3(5+u) + 7 &= 11(2+v) \\
   15 + 3u + 7 &= 22 + 11v \\
   3u + 22 &= 11v + 22 \\
   3u &= 11v \\
   3 &\mid 11v \\
   3 &\mid v
\end{align}

So $v = 3t$ and $y=2+3t$ for some integer $t$. The "for some" part is a problem. It suggests that, sometimes, $y=2+3t$ may not be a solution. It is very easy to show $y=2+3t$ is always going to be a solution.

Start with $3x+7=11y$ and let $y = 2+3t$.

\begin{align}
   3x+7 &= 11y \\
   3x + 7 &= 11(2+3t) \\
   3x + 7 &= 22 + 33t \\
   3x &= 33t + 15 \\
   x &= 11t + 5
\end{align}

But, of course, saying $x = 11t+5$ for any integer $t$ means that $x \equiv 5 \pmod{11}$.

Answer (score 2):

We need to find all integers $x$ such that

$3x = 11y - 7$ for some integers $y$

$3x = 11(y-2) -7 + 22 = 11(y-2) + 15$ and we get $3x - 15 = 11(y-2)$.

So $11 \mid (3x - 15)$ which can be written $11 \mid 3(x-5)$. $\gcd(3,11) = 1$ and by Euclid's Lemma $11 \mid (x-5)$ then $x = 11t+5$ ($t$ integer) are all the integers such that $3x+7$ is divisible by $11$.

Answer (score 1):

We need $$3x+7=11y\iff11y-3x=7(12-11)\iff11(y+7)=3(x+28)$$

$\implies\dfrac{3(x+28)}{11}=y+7$ which is an integer

$\iff11|3(x+28)\iff11|(x+28)$ as $(3,11)=1$

$\implies x\equiv-28\pmod{11}\equiv-28+33$

Comment: It might be worth adding a few lines to explain some of the steps, I am struggling to follow everything you've written. Some justification for some of the steps would be nice

Answer (score 1):

According to you $$3x+7\equiv 0 \pmod{11}$$ $$3x\equiv -7\pmod{11}$$ $$3x\equiv 4\pmod{11} $$ $$3x+11y=4$$
Note that $$3(4)+11(-1)=1$$ which can be deduced by Bezout's identity

Multiplying throughout by $4$ $$3(16)+11(-4)=4$$ which gives $$x=16$$ $$x\equiv 16\pmod{11}$$ $$x\equiv 5\pmod{11}$$

Not so impressive solution but an easier approach to solve this

Comment: Type 3x + 7 \equiv 0 \pmod{11} in math mode to obtain $3x + 7 \equiv 0 \pmod{11}$.

Comment: So you found  a particular solution($x_0$)  and  used $x\equiv x_0 \pmod {11}$?

Comment: Yes you are getting me @VidyanshuMishra