# Solving linear congruence in $Z_{350}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, modular-arithmetic

I need some help on how to begin a problem. The question is:

> Solve $[17][x]=[27]$ in $Z_{350}$. Show how to get the answer without
>   guessing. Express your answer as a class $[x]$ where $x$ is greater
>   than or equal to $0$ and less than $350$.

This is what I tried: $a-b=nk$ where $k$ is some integer. $17x=27$, so $a=17,be=350,c=27$. I then tried to take the $\gcd$ of $a$ and $b$ but the answer to that is $1$. I figured I did something wrong.

Comment: This is what I tried. a-b=nk where k is some integer. 17x=27, so a=17,be=350,c=27. I then tried to take the GCD of a and b but the answer to that is 1. I figured I did something wrong.

Comment: You didn't do anything wrong and you seem to be on the right track.  Since $\gcd(17, 350) = 1$ then you can write $17r + 350s = 1$ for some integers $r, s$.  This $r$ will be the multiplicative inverse of $17$ in $Z_{350}$, so multiplying both sides of $17x = 27$ by $r$ will cancel the factor of $17$ on the LHS and give you the answer for $x$.  So you just have to find the $r$ and $s$ as above, which you can do by reversing the steps of the Euclidean algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

$\!\bmod 350\!:\ \dfrac{27}{17}\equiv\dfrac{17+(10-350)}{17}\equiv 1-20\equiv 331.\ $ The idea is $\,\overbrace{27\equiv 350}^{\Large \color{#c00}{a\ \equiv\  n}\,}\pmod{\!17}\ $ and

$\!\bmod\ n\!:\quad \dfrac{a}{b}\ \equiv\ \dfrac{a-j\,n}b\ $ is an **exact quotient** if $\ j\equiv \color{#c00}{\dfrac{a}n}\pmod{b}\ \ \,$[so $\, \color{#c00}{a\equiv n} \Rightarrow j\equiv 1$]

Comment: More algorithmically we can use the [extended Euclidean algorithm](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/85830/how-to-use-the-extended-euclidean-algorithm-manually/85841#85841) (esp. simple in [fractional form)](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2100615/242)

Comment: **Beware** $\ $ Modular fraction arithmetic is well-defined *only* for fractions with denominator *coprime* to the modulus. [See here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/921093/242) for further discussion.

Comment: Interesting technique. I did notice $340$ up near $350$ as a multiple of $17$, but didn't notice the consequence that $27\equiv 350 \bmod 17$.

Answer (score 0):

the beginning is to solve
$$ 17 t \equiv 1 \pmod {350}.  $$
This is often called the Extanded Euclidean Algorithm, I prefer the continued fraction way of writing this:

$$  \gcd( 350, 17 ) = ???    $$

$$ \frac{ 350 }{ 17 } = 20 +  \frac{ 10 }{ 17 } $$ 
 $$ \frac{ 17 }{ 10 } = 1 +  \frac{ 7 }{ 10 } $$ 
 $$ \frac{ 10 }{ 7 } = 1 +  \frac{ 3 }{ 7 } $$ 
 $$ \frac{ 7 }{ 3 } = 2 +  \frac{ 1 }{ 3 } $$ 
 $$ \frac{ 3 }{ 1 } = 3 +  \frac{ 0 }{ 1 } $$ 
 Simple continued fraction tableau:
 $$ 
 \begin{array}{cccccccccccc}
 & & 20 & & 1 & & 1 & & 2 & & 3 & \\ 
  \frac{ 0 }{ 1 }   &   \frac{ 1 }{ 0 }   & &   \frac{ 20 }{ 1 }   & &   \frac{ 21 }{ 1 }   & &   \frac{ 41 }{ 2 }   & &   \frac{ 103 }{ 5 }   & &   \frac{ 350 }{ 17 }  
 \end{array}
 $$ 
 $$  $$ 
 $$ 
 \begin{array}{ccc}
  \frac{ 1 }{ 0 }   &     \mbox{digit}  &  20  \\  
  \frac{ 20 }{ 1 }   &     \mbox{digit}  &  1  \\  
  \frac{ 21 }{ 1 }   &     \mbox{digit}  &  1  \\  
  \frac{ 41 }{ 2 }   &     \mbox{digit}  &  2  \\  
  \frac{ 103 }{ 5 }   &     \mbox{digit}  &  3  \\  
  \frac{ 350 }{ 17 }   &     \mbox{digit}  &  0  \\  
 \end{array}
 $$

$$ 350 \cdot 5 - 17 \cdot 103 = -1 $$ 
 $$ -350 \cdot 5 + 17 \cdot 103 = 1 $$

$$ 103 \cdot 17 \equiv 1 \pmod {350}, $$
$$ \frac{1}{17}  \equiv 103 \pmod {350}. $$

$$ (27 \cdot 103) \cdot 17 \equiv 27 \pmod {350}. $$

Comment: Ignoring the numerator misses the chance for a nice optimization - see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Given $[17][x]=[27]$ in $Z_{350}$, we need to find $k=[17]^{-1}$ such that $[17]k=[1]$ and thus $[x]=[27]k$.

Since $17$ is coprime to $350$, we can be sure that the inverse exists and can find it through the [extended Euclidean algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm):

$\begin{array}{c|c}
n & s & t & q \\ \hline
350 & 1 & 0 &  \\
17 & 0 & 1 & 20 \\
10 & 1 & -20 & 1 \\
7 & -1 & 21 & 1 \\
3 & 2 & -41 & 2 \\
1 & -5 & 103 & 3 \\
\end{array}$

This gives $-5\cdot 350 + 103\cdot 17 =1$ and thus $17^{-1}\equiv 103\bmod 350$.

Then $103\cdot 27 = 2781 = 2800-19\equiv 331 \bmod 350$.

Comment: Algorithms always work, but they miss simple optimizations - see my answer.

Comment: How did you get 331 mod 350? I have the u and v values and the 2781.

Comment: @Storm $2800 = 8\times350\equiv0,$ and $-19\equiv350-19=331.$ Or you can just do long division of $2781$ by $350$ and take the remainder.

Comment: @Storm as DavidK says - I noticed a nearby multiple of $700=2\times 350$