# Can we say that $\frac{0}{0}$ is every number?

Tags: indeterminate-forms

Suppose we have an equation $ab=0$. This equation is true when statements $a=0$ or $b=0$ are true.

If $a=0$, then $b=\frac{0}{0}$. That means $b$ could be any number for $ab=0$ to be true. If the set which groups all the numbers is the complex set, then $b$ will every number within $\mathbb{C}$, so $\forall z\in\mathbb{C}:b=\frac{0}{0}=z$. Therefore, $\frac{0}{0}$ is every number.

I know it really is not defined as number but conceptually it is every number, right?

Is this right, or am I missing something?

Comment: "conceptually it is every number" No. "Conceptually" or not, "it" is no number since "it" does not exist.

Comment: If  it is every number, what would be the result of $2 \cdot \dfrac 00$?

Comment: In math, you need to be a little more specific with your definitions, and be able to answer some questions. Is your number in $\mathbb{R}$? If so, which element of $\mathbb{R}$ is it? If no, then which set is it in? How do you define addition and multiplication between elements of $\mathbb{R}$ and your set? etc.

Comment: Why is this question getting so much hate?

Comment: @tilper: Not sure.  I upvoted compensatorily (that's totally a word).  It seems like a reasonable question.

Comment: @Ovi $0\over0$.

Comment: If $\frac{0}{0}$ would be considered every number, then we could say that $$1=\frac{0}{0}=2$$

Comment: @Blake Sorry but where did you see that 1/1 is "every number", "technically" or not? 1/1 is exactly a single number, namely, 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When we say that $ab=0$ we define $a$ and $b$ as being unique numbers. So when saying $b$ *is all the numbers* we are saying that $b$ is **not** unique. That leads to a contradiction so $b$ is undefined.

Answer (score 5):

No, it is not every number.

You are correct that for every number $x$ we have that $0 \cdot x = 0$, but we want the ratio to be a single number, because we want it to act like a function ... so it is exactly because we don't have a unique solution to $0 \cdot x = 0$  that we say that $\frac{0}{0}$ is not a number ... and certainly not all numbers.

Instead, we say that $\frac{0}{0}$ is 'indeterminate'.  Interestingly, if we define the relationship over natural numbers '$a$ divides $b$' as there exists some natural number $c$ such that $a \cdot c = b$, then that means that we can also say that '0 divides 0'.  But that still doesn't mean that $\frac{0}{0}$ is defined!

Comment: You can try \cdot instead of *

Comment: @Olba12  Thanks! :)

Answer (score 3):

There are some contexts where it is helpful to consider *multiple-valued* fractions $\,x = a/b\,$ that denote the *complete solution set* of $\,b\,x = a.\,$ Then  $0/0$ denotes the solution set of $\,0x = 0,\,$ which is satisfied by every element of the domain.

One simple context where they arise is modular arithmetic, e.g. consider the fraction $\,x\equiv 6/2\pmod{\!10}.\,$  We have $\,2x\equiv 6\pmod{\!10}$ $\iff 2x = 6+10k\,$ $\iff x = 3 + 5k$ $\iff x\equiv 3\pmod{\!5}$ $\iff x\equiv 3,8\pmod{\!10}.\, $ So this fraction takes *two* values mod $10.\,$ Such fractions arise naturally in the [fractional form of the extended Euclidean GCD algorithm .](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2053174/242)

For example, see the Remark in the linked post, where we bootstrap the Euclidean modular reduction process with  $\, 0/18 \equiv 0/0 \pmod{\!18}.\ $ We could avoid using $\,0/0\,$ there, but since multiple-valued fractions occur throughout the algorithm, it is natural to allow *all* such fractions.

That said, generally such notions are avoided in elementary contexts since it is very easy to make mistakes if one does not have a solid grasp on the fundamentals.

Comment: That's a fair point.  I'll adjust my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer:  No.

Slightly longer answer:  Still no, but here's a slightly related concept which I think is "as close as we can get" to an affirmative answer to your question, and maybe you already know this and it's why you asked the question in the first place.  But anyway..

It is possible to get $0/0$ from direct substitution in a limit whose value can be any (fixed) number.

A well-known limit typically introduced no later than a first-semester calculus course is:
$$ \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\sin x}x = 1$$

Direct substitution of $x=0$ into this limit gives us $\dfrac{\sin 0}0 = \dfrac00$, which is indeterminate.  But the actual value of the limit is $1$.  Therefore we can multiply $\dfrac{\sin x}x$ by any real (or complex) constant $c$ to get $c$ as the limiting value as $x \to 0$, while direct substitution still gives $0/0$.
$$ \lim_{x\to0} \frac{c \sin x}x = c \lim_{x\to0} \frac{\sin x}x = c \cdot 1 = c,$$
and direct substitution gives us the indeterminate form $\dfrac{c \cdot 0}0 = \dfrac00$.

Comment: For the record, you don't need to introduce $\sin x/x$ - using $x/x$ will work just fine.

Comment: @Wojowu, thought about that but I don't think $x/x$ is instructive enough as an example.  It simplifies trivially and I didn't want to give the impression that this would only happen for limits of expressions that simplify trivially.  Plus $\lim_{x\to0} \sin x / x$ has the added bonus of being a limit that OP is likely to (have) encounter(ed) depending on OP's math background.

Answer (score 0):

Ultimately, it's not a number, or every number, because it isn't useful to interpret it that way.  It might be interesting from a philosophical perspective, but since we generally can't move it into another context and expect it to do anything predictable, we typically treat it as undefined.  (See Bill Dubuque's answer for an interesting counterpoint, however.)

Often, the expression $\frac{0}{0}$ might show up as a result of comparing two continuously varying values that just happen to equal $0$ simultaneously—something like

$$
\frac{f(a)}{g(a)}
$$

if both $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ happen to have zeros at $x = a$.  But for such situations, we use limits, and instead of the foregoing, we instead substitute

$$
\lim_{x \to a}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}
$$

In some cases, we have $\infty$ in place of $a$, to refer to the ultimate ratio of the fraction $\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$ as $x$ increases without bound.

In the case of your expression, you have $b = \frac{0}{a}$, which is ordinarily just $0$.  But because $a$ itself is also equal to $0$, you have concluded $b = \frac{0}{0}$, which you choose to interpret as $b$ being able to take on any value.  However, you might have just concluded that $b$ can take on any value without going through the intermediary expression $\frac{0}{0}$.  And because that expression is essentially useless when performing analysis, that is exactly what mathematicians typically do: simply say that $b$ can take on any value.

Answer (score 0):

You can say $\frac 00$ is a pink elephant that eats dinosaurs if you want.  But if you say that then you *can't* say $\frac 00$ is a distinct number that when multiplied by $0$ results is zero.

So if you $\frac 00 $ is every number, you can not say $\frac 00$ is a distinct number that when multiplied by $0$ results in $0$.  "Every number" is not a distinct number.  "Every number" is a set of numbers.  "Every number" is a the set of all numbers.

$\frac ab$, by definition, is *a* distinct *number*, $x$ so that $x*b = a$.  It is not, by definition, a set of multiple numbers.

So what we say instead is: As there are multiple numbers, $x$ such that $x*0 = 0$ and indeed for *any* number, $x$, we have $x*0 = 0$, there is no *distinct* number so that $x*0 = 0$, therefore $\frac 00$ can not be defined with the usual definition.  However we can say $X = \{x \in R| x*0 = 0\} = \mathbb R$.  But that is an entirely different statement than: $\frac 00 = \mathbb R$.

Actually if you want to get ... obtuse.  You can define $X_{a,b} = \{x \in \mathbb R| x*b = a\}$ and define $\frac ab$ as the single element of $X_{a,b}$ if $X_{a,b}$ has only a single element.  We can show that if $b \ne 0$ then any set $X_{a,b}$ will have a single element and thus $\frac ab$ is uniquely defined.  If $b = 0$ and $a \ne 0$ then $X_{a,b} = \emptyset$ and if $b=0; a=0$ then $X_{a,b} = \mathbb R$, and in either case $\frac ab$ is defined if and only if $b \ne 0$.

But that'd be silly.

====

Note:  I *did* say with the "usual definition".  See Bill Dubuque's answer for alternate definitions.  As well, in the extended number line, $\frac 10 = \infty$ is acceptable but then $\frac ab$ no longer is defined as the number $x$ so that $b*x =a$.

Answer (score 0):

You may call $\frac00$ "every number" if you like but that leads you nowhere. Because you can't use this "every number" in further arithmetic operations.

For instance, zero times "every number" is still undefined, and it would be a wrong idea to define it as zero.

Answer (score 0):

Lets check

$\frac{0}{0}=5$

We multiply both sides of equation by $5$

$5 \cdot \frac{0}{0} = 5 \cdot 5$

$5 \cdot 0 + 0 = 25$

$0 + 0 = 25$

$0 = 25$

No, we can't. Logically $b$ cannot be a value and an operation at the same time.

Comment: Where did the "5.0 + 0" come from?

Comment: The second zero is not required after plus sign. It is just a pattern, the same way as in: even = 2 times odd + 0 || 2

Comment: ??? How do you get from $5*\frac 00 =5*5$ to $5*0 +0 = 25$? Why would you think $5*\frac 00 = 5*0$?

Comment: I think when it comes about zero which is neither positive nor negative, call it neither increasing nor decreasing , the operation of division here don't change the state in space, since our dividend starts at point $0$, then moves nowhere, which is defined by divisor, so quotient becomes value of $0$ at the same point.

Comment: Um, Aren't you assuming a completely different argument in order to make you current argument.  You are trying to show that $\frac 00 = 5$ leads to contradiction and yet you assume for utterly unstated reasons that $5*\frac 00 = 5*0 + 0$.  I simply do not see according to anything that you are saying how that follows.

Comment: I like your curiosity, fleablood. Somewhere in this month I will be putting a question where I explain zero-balance symmetry plane, where you can understand this concept.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/53044/discussion-between-usir0-and-fleablood).

Answer (score 0):

In the ordinary number systems division by zero is undefined. It is possible to define extended number systems including objects as $\frac{1}{0}=\infty$ and $\frac{-1}{0}=-\infty$, "infinite numbers" and $\frac{0}{0}$, "indefinite number". The rules wouldn't differ that much but the system would not gain much either. The most theorems would be possible to rehabilitate, but would mostly be more ugly. I guess.

Answer (score 0):

You may think of the form $0/0$ as a variable; but I think that is misleading outside the context of functions. Rather, we say it is an indeterminate, or a non-determinate, or an unknown, but certainly not some number in $\Bbb C$, or even a set of all numbers as you seem to think.

Answer (score 0):

There's actually nothing too wrong with taking $\frac{0}{0}$ to have every real number as a value. That is, as you point out, the most logical thing to do when you consider the defining equation for division:

$$b \left(\frac{a}{b}\right) = a$$

which gives, when $a = b = 0$,

$$0 \left(\frac{0}{0}\right) = 0$$

and any substitution for the putative quantity $\frac{0}{0}$ will work, and make this equation hold good true (something that does *not* happen when $a \ne 0$ and $b = 0$!). Moreover, in many geometric limiting contexts, this makes a lot of sense, too: if you do this, the graph of the equation

$$y = \frac{0}{x}$$

is a cross, which is the exact limiting case of the hyperbolas

$$y = \frac{a}{x}$$

as $a \rightarrow 0$.

So why isn't it done? Simple: We like to have division be a *function*, and not just a one-to-many (many many!) relation. Having it take all real values at even one point would destroy that. So the standard option is the alternative: limit the domain so that $(0, 0)$ is absent therefrom. This leaves $\frac{0}{0}$ undefined.

But there is nothing inherently *wrong with* considering such non-function operations: the inverse trigonometric functions, the square root, etc. are all most properly thought of as one-to-many relations, and they pop up in many other areas as well.