# Dividing Modulo

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, congruences

In the solution to a

$ax \equiv b \pmod m$

$71x \equiv 1 \pmod{771} \implies x \equiv -76 \pmod{771}$

and

$71x \equiv 1 \pmod{77} \implies x \equiv -13 \pmod{77}$

I'm unsure of how these congruences hold, how does one divide modulo $771$?

Comment: My apologies, I'll learn how to format properly when next I ask a question, however I hope the current format isn't too difficult on the eyes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's worth to notice that $1\equiv -770\pmod{771}$ and $71\equiv -700\pmod{771}$ then you can divide by $70$ to get $$-10x\equiv -11\pmod{771}$$ which is equivalent to $$10x\equiv 11\pmod{771}$$ and since $11\equiv -760\pmod{771}$ we have $$10x\equiv-760\pmod{771}$$ dividing by $10$ we get $$x\equiv-76\pmod{771}$$

Comment: Thanks very much, you've clarified this instance, however what about with smaller modulo, e.g.     77x = 17mod33?

Comment: I've got it down as => 7x = 17mod3 => 7x = 2mod3 so far.

Comment: You can't really solve this one as $77\equiv 11\pmod{33}$ and $11x\equiv 11,22,0\pmod{33}$.This is because $\gcd(11,33)\neq 1$ so this example is doesn't have a solution so you can't find it though in general you could solve $11x\equiv 22\pmod{33}$ for example by dividing everything by $11$ to get $x\equiv 2\pmod{3}$

Answer (score 0):

The calculations are easy using [a fractional form](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2053174/242) of the Extended Euclidean Algorithm.

${\rm mod}\ 77\!:\, \ \dfrac{0}{77}\overset{\large\frown}\equiv \dfrac{1}{71}\overset{\large\frown}\equiv\dfrac{-1}6\overset{\large\frown}\equiv\dfrac{13}{-1}$

Equivalently, without fractions

$\begin{array}{rrl} 
[1]\!:\!\!\!& 77\,x\!\!\!&\equiv\ 0\\
[2]\!:\!\!\!& 71\,x\!\!\!&\equiv\ 1\\
[1]\ \ -\ \ [2]=:[3]\!:\!\!\!& 6\,x\!\!\!&\equiv -1\\
[2]-12[3]=:[4]\!:\!\!\!& -x\!\!\! &\equiv 13\\
\end{array}$

Similarly for the first inversion

${\rm mod}\ 771\!:\,\ \dfrac{0}{771}\overset{\large\frown}\equiv \dfrac{1}{71}\overset{\large\frown}\equiv \dfrac{-11}{-10}\overset{\large\frown}\equiv \dfrac{-76}1$