# Divisibility Check in different Moduli

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

So I'm working on modular arithmetic and encountered the following problem:

Assume that $(a \cdot b) \mod m = c$ and that I know $c$. Can I still check for divisibility of $c$ by $a$? A quick example tells me that checking whether $c \mod a = 0$ does not work:

$((29*200) \mod 512) \mod 29 = 23$

But is this check impossible if $m < a \cdot b$ or is there a way to find out whether $a | c$? Maybe if $m$ and $n$ are primes?

Thanks!

Comment: $a\cdot b \pmod m$ or $\pmod n$?

Comment: The question is not at all clear. Please give a concrete example.

Comment: I edited the question, I hope it's clearer now.

Comment: You seek to solve $\ ax\equiv c\pmod{m}\ $ for which see [this answer.](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2053174/242)