# How to calculate modulo of a factorial?

Tags: modular-arithmetic

I am using C++ programming language. 
We are given 3 integers $x,y,z$ and I have to calculate 
:-

$(x +y +z)!/(x!*y!*z!) $ modulo  $p$

where , $p=10^9+7$

Also , 
$0<=x,y,z<=10^5$

I tried many approaches but none of them worked. Fermat's theorem also does not work here :(

In C++,the maximum value an integer can have is 10^18.

Comment: What are the values of $x,y,$ and $z$?

Comment: @Cardioid_Ass_22  I've mentioned it. They can be anything between [0,10^5]...I want to know a way to calculate this in my  C++ compiler :-)

Comment: Are you looking for an approach to simplify the calculation in general, rather than a specific answer? If so, please clarify in your question what size of value you can handle in your calculation.

Comment: @Cardioid_Ass_22  Yes, you got it right :-)

Comment: Is this a [Project Euler](https://projecteuler.net/) question?

Comment: @BrianTung No.....but maybe similar to some of its questions..

Comment: I don't think it's good idea to bloat MSE with programming challenges off the whole website.

Comment: All operations involved are binary operations: $+$, $\cdot$ and even the factorial is just a multiplication. So if you keep reducing all the operations modulo $p$ along your way, the worst case will be to multiply two number close to $10^9$ which should still be in the range of C++ representation of integer.

Comment: This is better suited to be a question on https://stackoverflow.com if you are even facing a problem to code or have an mvce.

Comment: (Towards the answer: build tables of $n\mapsto(n!\bmod p)$ and $n\mapsto(n!^{-1}\bmod p)$ for $n\leqslant N:=3\cdot 10^5$. The first is built using $0!=1$ and successive multiplications $\bmod p$; the second is built downwards, using $N!^{-1}\bmod p$ computed from $N!\bmod p$ any way you like, and again successive multiplications $\bmod p$.)

Comment: @metamorphy I think it is problematic to calculate n!-inverse mod p ..

Comment: @metamorphy  This is how I calculate n!mod p = (1%p*2%p*3%p*4%p*5%p*....n%p)......but the question is how do I calculate n^-1 ! mod p ??

Comment: What is "problematic"? Extended Euclidean, or even just modular exponentiation (since $a\not\equiv 0\implies a^{-1}\equiv a^{p-2}\pmod{p}$).

Comment: Say, in our case, a=n! .... So I have to calculate (n!)^p-2 (mod p) .........Try to know that  (x^y)%n can only be calculated when x<=10^9.....in our case, x=n!>>>>10^9

Comment: You can use [PARI C library](https://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/). Let `p=10^9+7;x=10^5-1;y=10^5-11;z=10^5-21;`, check in **pari/gp** calculator `Mod((x+y+z)!/(x!*y!*z!),p)`, output is `Mod(912505566, 1000000007)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question was asked by me and I have found the answer.

You basically want to calculate $ k!/a!*b!*c!$ mod $p$

which can be re-written as :- $(k!$ mod $p)$ * $(1/a!)$mod $ p$ * $(1/b!)$mod $p$ * $(1/c!)$ mod $p$

To calculate m!%p:-

int fact[Maxn];

fact[0] = 1;

for(int i = 1; i < Maxn; i++)

{

```
fact[i] = 1LL * fact[i - 1] * i % Mod;
```

}

To calculate (1/x!) mod p :-

int ifact[Maxn];

ifact[0] = 1;

for(int i = 1; i < Maxn; i++)

{

```
ifact[i] = 1LL * ifact[i - 1] * inverse(i, Mod) % Mod;
```

}