# For which positive integer values of $n$ does $a|mn-b?$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I am taking a number theory class, and I was not able to solve this homework problem.

Let $a,$ $b,$ and $m$ be constant positive integers. For which positive integer values of $n$ does $a|mn-b?$

I tried this out for a couple of values, and the values of $n$ satisfying this expression seem to occur in a cycle.  (For example, let $m=2019,$ $a=20,$ $b=19.$ The values of $n$ that work are $1,21,41,61,....$) However, I am not able to show that this always happens.

Comment: Welcome to Math Stack Exchange.  Cf. [Bezout's identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout%27s_identity) $mn+ka=b$

Comment: Wouldn't this be $mn-ka=b?$

Comment: You are correct

Comment: let S be the set of integer values n such that : $a|mn-b$ and let D be the following set :
               $$D=\{0\leq r\leq a-1 \;  / a|mr-b \}$$ you can  prove that : $$S=\{aq+r \; / q\in\mathbb{N} \;  r\in D\}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\,d = \gcd(a,m).\,$  $\ d\mid m\ $ & $\ d\mid a\mid nm\!-\!b\,\Rightarrow\,\color{#c00}{d\mid b}\,$ so $\:\!\color{#90f}{{\rm cancelling}\ d}\,$ from the divisibility

$$  a\mid nm-b\!\!\overset{\large\color{#90f}{\div\ d_{\phantom{.}}}\!\!}\iff  a/d\mid n(m/d) - b/d\iff n\equiv \dfrac{\color{#c00}{b/d}}{\color{#0a0}{m/d}}\!\!\!\pmod{a/d}\qquad$$

i.e. to evaluate a (multivalued) modular fraction $\, n\equiv b/m\pmod{\!a},\,$ cancel $\,d = \gcd(a,m)\,$ *everywhere*, i.e. from the top $\,b\,$ & bottom $\,m\,$ & modulus $\,a\,$ (if $\,\color{#c00}{d\nmid b}\,$ then it does not exist, by above). Notice that $\,\gcd(a/d,m/d) = 1\,$ so $\,\color{#0a0}{(m/d)^{-1}}$ exists $\!\pmod{\!a/d}\ $ (e.g. by Bezout).

See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2053174/242) for much further discussion (including how to use such multivalued modular fractions in the extended Euclidean algorithm)

Comment: why does $d|b?$

Comment: @Naleba $\ d\,$ divides $mn$ and $\,mn-b\,$ so also their difference $= b\ \ $

Comment: So, the final result was that $n\equiv b/m \pmod a?$

Comment: See the displayed congruence. The final result is the RHS. There are examples in the linked answer (and questions linked to that).

Comment: The linked answer states that $x \equiv ad/bd \pmod{md}$ is the same as $x\equiv a/b \pmod{m},$ which would mean in this case that $n \equiv b/m \pmod{a},$ right?

Comment: @Naleba Yes, *if* we interpret that "fractional" notation in the multivalued manner  I describe there.