# Number Theory, GCD and Absolute value

Tags: number-theory

Find all $|kh - ij|$ such that there are infinite integers $x$ such that $gcd(xh + i, xj + k) = 2019$ given that $(h, i, j, k)$ are all integers.

I tried using the Euclidian Algorithm, but I'm not that good with mods so I didn't get anywhere.

Comment: Related to recent questions [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3434945/242) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3430589/242)