# Solving congruences/modular inverses with a polynomial modulus

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, divisibility

After going through easily a couple dozen answers here (in particular by @BillDubuque) and articles elsewhere, I'm still stumped something that seems like it ought to be simple. First, here's the setup; all variables are non-zero integers.

**Lemma**: Given $(a,b) = 1$ and $(a, c,d)=1$, and $a > b \geq 1$:

$$
\left\{
\begin{array}{lr}
u = ax + bc \\ 
v = ay + bd \\
\end{array}
\right\} \iff \left(u \mid v \iff y \equiv c'dx \pmod u \right)
$$

where $c'$ is the modular inverse of $c$ in modulus $u$, because I hate typing the exponent every time.

*Proof (Sketch)*: The required coprimes ensure all our variables have unique modular inverses. Thus, starting with $u = ax + bc \equiv 0 \pmod u$, and continuing in the same modulus:

$$ax \equiv -bc \iff adx \equiv -bcd \\
u \mid v \iff u \equiv v \equiv 0 \iff ay \equiv -bd \iff acy \equiv -bcd \\
acy \equiv adx \iff cy \equiv dx \iff y \equiv c'dx$$

This was discussed some in a simpler form [in this post and its answers.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4022306/585349)

---

This has been useful in analyzing [sequences like this](https://oeis.org/A112540), in particular examining which primes divide the numbers generated by each entry. But I've run up against a bit of a wall with modular inverses in a variable modulus.

Let $a=15, b=1, c=-7, d=2$. In addition, $x>0$ is even and $u$ is prime. (This formulation asks: What primes of the form $15k-7$ (with $k$ even), e.g. $[23, 53, 83, \dots]$ divide numbers of the form $15n +2$ (with $n$ odd), e.g. $[17, 47, 77, \dots]$?)

To find $y = c'dx$, we need to solve for $c'$, giving the equation

$$-7c' \equiv 1 \pmod{15x-7}$$

and $c'$ should be a function of $x$. And I can't find a way to do it. I know the *solution* but I don't know how to show the process of getting to that solution. Extended Euclidean algorithm, polynomial long division, throwing things into Sage to see what comes out... either I get no solution, conflicting values, or infinite loops.

The solution (or one form of it), determined empirically (it's not hard to force a computer to calculate a few hundred thousand inverses), is $c' \equiv 2-x' \pmod {15x-7}$.

But I can't *prove* it, or show where it came from. Is the problem that there are some values of $x$ (i.e., $x = 7k$) for which there is no answer, therefore no *general* solution exists that one can readily solve? Does anyone have thoughts on how to solve what I feel like should be a simple modular inverse?

---

Edit to add: an example of a congruence similar to this that *is* solvable is $2a \equiv 1 \pmod {2x+1}$, for which the solution is $a \equiv x+1$. $2$ has a modular inverse in any odd modulus. Similarly, $x$ is its own inverse mod $x+1$. Is there a method of determining when these problems have solutions, and when they don't? Is it merely a matter of "if it's *possible* for the integer or polynomial you're trying to invert to not be coprime to the modulus, it can't be solved"?

Comment: $\!\bmod p=\color{#c00}{30k-7}\!:\,\ 0\equiv 17+30n\!\!\!\overset{\times\ k\!}\iff\!  0\equiv 17k+\color{#c00}{30k}n\equiv 17k+\color{#c00}7n\iff n/k\equiv -17/7\ $ (or, using fractions: $\ \color{#c00}{7/k}\equiv 30\equiv -17/n\,)\qquad$

Comment: e.g. $\,k\!=\!1\!:\, \bmod p\!=\!23\!:\ n\equiv \dfrac{-17}7\equiv \dfrac{6}7\equiv \dfrac{18}{21}\equiv \dfrac{18}{-2}\equiv -9\equiv \color{#0a0}{14},\,$ and $\,17\!+\!30(\color{#0a0}{14}) = 23(19)\qquad$

Comment: Generally $\ 19(30k-7) = 30(19k-5)+17\,$ by $\,n\equiv \dfrac{-17}{30}\equiv\dfrac{19(\color{#c00}7)-5(30)}{\color{#c00}{30}}\equiv 19\color{#c00}k-5\qquad$

Comment: @BillDubuque, do you feel the problem lies in using mod $15x \pm b$ rather than the (maybe more natural?) $30x \pm b$? I ask because I was hoping for a more general solution--solving individual cases is quite easy. I'd still like to find an expression in $x$, i.e., $c' \equiv f(x)$, of the sort I mentioned in the edits.

Comment: It's not clear what "problem" you refer to.

Comment: Apologies; darn English synonyms. Does the *issue* lie in using mods with $15$ rather than $30$? Also, I realize I don't entirely follow your first comment; what is the $n$ equal to and/or where did it come from? And where does the $30n+17$ come from? $30k-7$ is just subbing $x=2k$, that I follow, and the part *after* that I follow, but I don't see the introduction of $n$. Also, like I said, I'm trying to find a way to prove a more general solution: I know $x=2,4,6,...$ gives $y \equiv 6,10,14,... \equiv 4x-2 \equiv c'dx$, but proving it is something else.

Comment: $N$ odd $\Rightarrow N = 2n+1\,$ so $\,15N+2 = 15(2n+1)+2 = 30n+17\,$ so your example is equivalent to asking when a prime $\,p = 30k-7\,$ divides $\,30n+17,\,$ i.e. when $\, 30n+17\equiv 0\pmod{\!p},\,$ which is what I begin with in my first comment. Please give an example of the more general problem that you cannot solve the above way.

Comment: For your Lemma: $\ ax\!+\!c\mid ay\!+\!d\, \color{#c00}\Rightarrow\, ax\!+\!c\mid dx\!-\!cy\ [= x(ay\!+\!d)-y(ax\!+\!c)],\,$ and the $\rm\color{#c00}{arrow}$ reverses (i.e. they are equivalent) if $\, 1 = (x,c)\ [= (x,ax\!+\!c)]\ \ $

Comment: Aha! That was enough to get me on the right path. The thing is I'm looking for the final "solution" to be a function $y(x)$ that gives the residue $y \pmod u$ without knowing $u$. Following your logic gets me there, I think, by: (mod $15x - 7)$: $$\color{green}{-7y \equiv 2xy} \iff 15y \equiv 2 \iff 15y \equiv 15x-5 \iff \\ 3y \equiv 3x-1 \iff 3y \equiv 33x-15 \iff \color{red}{y \equiv 11x - 5 \equiv -4x+2}$$ which is the negative of what I was expecting, but is close enough to work for the moment--would you be willing to check for error?

Comment: The first part isn't clear: $-7y \equiv 2x (cy \equiv dx) \iff 15xy \equiv 2x$ (since $15xy \equiv -7y$ in this mod), then divide by $x$.

Comment: I showed how to solve for $\,y\,$ in my 3rd comment above using the Bezout GCD equation, i.e.
$$ (a,c)=1\Rightarrow \exists\, j,k\!:\ \color{#c00}{ja\!-\!kc=-d},\,\ {\rm so}\, \bmod ax\!+\!c\!:\,\ y \equiv \dfrac{\color{#c00}{-d}}a\equiv \dfrac{\color{#c00}{ja\! - \!kc}}a \equiv j + k x\qquad $$

Comment: In your example $\,ja-jc = -d\,$ is $\,15j+7k = -2,\,$ so $\!{\bmod 7\!:\ j \equiv -2},\,$ so $\,\color{#0a0}{j = -2\!+\!7n},\,$ so $\,k = (-2\!-\!15j)/7 =  (-2\!-\!15(\color{#0a0}{-2\!+\!7n)})/7 = 4-15n\ \ $

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\,\rm\color{#90f}{prime}$ $\,ax\!+\!c\mid ay\!+\!d\,$  then $\,\color{#90f}{(a,c)=1}\,$ (except degenerate cases), thus by $\rm\color{#c00}{Bezout}$

$$ (a,c)=1\Rightarrow \exists\, j,k\!:\ \color{#c00}{ja\!-\!kc=-d},\,\ {\rm so}\, \bmod ax\!+\!c\!:\,\ y \equiv \dfrac{\color{#c00}{-d}}a\equiv \dfrac{\color{#c00}{ja\! - \!kc}}a \equiv \bbox[5px,border:1px solid #c00]{j + k x}\qquad $$

Explicitly: $\,\ {(ax\!+\!\color{#c00}c)\color{#c00}k = \color{#c00}a(kx\!+\!\color{#c00}j)\color{#c00}{+d}}$

e.g. your $\,15x\!-\!7\mid 15y\!+\!2\,$ has $\,ja\!-\!jc = -d\,$ $\leadsto \,15j\!+\!7k = -2,\,$ so $\!{\bmod 7\!:\ j \equiv -2},\,$ so $\,\color{#0a0}{j = -2\!+\!7m},\,$ so $\,k = (-2\!-\!15\:\!\color{#0a0}j)/7 =  (-2\!-\!15(\color{#0a0}{-2\!+\!7m)})/7 = 4-15m,\,$ so $\,j+kx \equiv -2\!+\!4x +(7\!-\!15x)m,\,$ which agrees with your sought solution for $\,m=0$.

Note $\,(a,ax\!+\!c)\! =\! (a,c)\!=\!1\,$ so $\bmod ax\!+\!c\!:\ a^{-1}$ exists, so  $\,\frac{n}a := na^{-1}\,$ uniquely exists too.