# Solving system of Congruences with Two Variables (x and y)

Tags: discrete-mathematics, modular-arithmetic, chinese-remainder-theorem

I know a bit about the Chinese Remainder theorem but what do I do in the case I was asked to solve a system of congruences such as this with two variables:

$3x + y = 7$ (mod 8)

$4x + 3y = 1$ (mod 8)

Comment: Welcome to Math Stack Exchange.  What would you do if you had two equations to solve in $\mathbb R$ like those in $\mathbb Z/8\mathbb Z$?

Answer (score 3):

Approach these equations as you would equations over $\mathbb R$.

Multiply the first by $3$ to get $x+3y\equiv5\pmod 8$.

Then subtract that from $4x+3y\equiv1\pmod 8$ to get $3x\equiv1-5\equiv9-5=4\pmod8$.

Multiply by the inverse of $3$ (which is $3\pmod8$) to get $x\equiv4\pmod 8$.

Now can you solve for $y$ given $3x+y\equiv7\pmod8$?

Comment: When you say to multiply the first one by 3, how did you get $x + 3y = 5$ (mod 8)

Comment: $(3\times3)x+3y\equiv3\times7\pmod8\implies9x+3y\equiv21\pmod8\implies x+3y\equiv5\pmod8$ because $ 9\equiv1 $ and $21\equiv5\pmod8$

Comment: Ok thanks. I understand.

Comment: Ok, so the approach these types of questions is to multiply one of the equations by a number and then add/subtract the second equation to eliminate one of the variables. Then solve the first variable like x in this case and then using the first variable, solve the second? Just like normal algebra.

Comment: Just like normal algebra

Comment: What if they are different mods?

Comment: @slayer6969 **Beware** Generally you cannot "approach ... as you would over $\Bbb R$" because $\Bbb Z/8$ is not a field, so you have to be more careful, e.g. scaling by noninvertible elements (here even integers) does not yield equivalent equations (that is not done above so there is no problem, but it is a pitfall that deserves explicit emphasis).

Answer (score 0):

Solve the system of equations without the $\pmod 8$. You will get $x = 4, y = -5$.

Comment: Why can we just ignore the mod (8). I do agree that these solutions work, but would these work if the mod's were different for each equation?

Comment: If you change the last equation to $4x+3y=9$ for example, you will get $x = \frac{12}{5}, y = -\frac{1}{5}$, which is equivalent to $x = \frac{12+8}{5} = 4, y = \frac{-1+8*2}{5} = 3$ modulo $8$. You basically have to solve $12+8x \pmod 5 \equiv 0, -1+8x \pmod 5 \equiv 0$ which you can do by taking the inverse of both sides.

Comment: You can also use Bill Dubuque's [technique](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2053144/solving-ax-equiv-c-pmod-b-efficiently-when-a-b-are-not-coprime/2053174#2053174) on how to reduce these fractions.

Answer (score 0):

The first equation is in a form suggesting substitution method as you have $y$ with coefficient $1$:

- $y \equiv 7-3x \pmod 8$

Plug this into the second equation and solve for $x$:
$$4x + 3(7-3x) \equiv 4x +21 -9x \stackrel{21=16+5}{\equiv} -5x +5 \equiv 1 \pmod 8$$

Now, note that the $5^2 \equiv (24+1) \equiv 1 \pmod 8$. Using this you get
$$\Leftrightarrow 5x \equiv 4 \pmod 8 \stackrel{\cdot 5}{\Leftrightarrow} \boxed{x =} 20 \equiv \boxed{4 \pmod 8}$$

Plugging this back into the equation $y \equiv 7-3x\pmod 8$ gives
$$\boxed{y=} 7-3\cdot 4 \equiv -5 \equiv \boxed{3 \pmod 8}$$

Comment: nice approach; also $4x+21-9x\equiv1\pmod8\implies-5x\equiv-20\pmod8\implies x\equiv4\pmod 8$

Answer (score 0):

Cramer's rule ($\rm\color{#0a0}{scale}$ by $\color{#c00}{\rm adjugate}$) works over any commutative ring (here $\Bbb Z/8 = $ integers $\!\bmod 8)$

$\qquad\quad\ \begin{align} \rm\color{#c00}{\begin{bmatrix}\rm 3 &\!\!\! \rm -1 \\ \!\!\rm -4 & \rm 3 \end{bmatrix}} {\bf \color{#0a0}\times} &\, \left\{\, \begin{bmatrix}\rm 3 & \rm 1 \\ \rm 4 & \rm 3 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} \rm x \\ \rm y \end{bmatrix} \,\equiv\, 
\begin{bmatrix}\rm 7 \\ \rm 1\end{bmatrix}\, \right\}\\[.2em] 
\Longrightarrow &\,\qquad\qquad\,  
\begin{array}\ 
\rm\ 5\ x\   \equiv\, \ \ \rm \color{#c00}3\cdot 7 \color{#c00}{- 1}\cdot 1\, \equiv\ \ \  20\iff x\equiv\, 4\\ 
\rm\ 5\ y\ = \rm \color{#c00}{-4}\cdot 7 + \color{#c00}1\cdot 3 \,\equiv -25\!\iff y\equiv -5\end{array}^{\phantom{|}} \end{align}$

$ \begin{align}{\rm using}\ \ \ \rm\color{#c00}{\begin{bmatrix}\rm d &\!\!\! \rm -b \\ \!\!\rm -c & \rm a \end{bmatrix}} {\bf \color{#0a0}\times} &\, \left\{\, \begin{bmatrix}\rm a & \rm b \\ \rm c & \rm d \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} \rm x \\ \rm y \end{bmatrix} \,=\, \begin{bmatrix}\rm X \\ \rm Y\end{bmatrix}\, \right\}\\[.2em] 
\Longrightarrow &\,\qquad\qquad\,  \begin{array}\ \rm\Delta\ x\   =\, \ \ \rm \color{#c00}d\ X \color{#c00}{- b}\ Y \\ \rm\Delta\ y\ = \rm \color{#c00}{-c}\ X + \color{#c00}a\ Y \end{array}^{\phantom{|}} ,\ \ \ \ \rm \Delta\ :=\ \color{#c00}{ad-bc} \end{align}$

**Beware** $ $ The determinant $\Delta = 5\,$ is invertible $\!\bmod 8$ so we can cancel it to (uniquely) solve for $x$ and $y$. If it is not coprime to the modulus then it is not invertible so we need to be more careful, and there may  be zero or multiple solutions. The same caveat holds if you instead perform  (Gaussian) elimination, where scaling an equation need not yield an equivalent equation if the scale factor is not invertible. Thus you cannot generally "solve as you do in $\Bbb R$" as suggested elsewhere on this page  (but that is true for *prime* moduli $p$ where $\,\Bbb Z/p\,$ is a field like $\Bbb R,\,$ i.e. nonzero elements are invertible).