# How many possibilities are there for the number of solutions of a linear congruence modulo 20

Tags: modular-arithmetic

So I was given this question and I'm not very good at this if anyone could provide a little help

I know that $ax\equiv b\pmod{20}$ and by using $gcd(a,20) = 1$ unique solution
and $gcd(a,20) = 2,4,5,10,20$

what do I do next? Do I test out all of the gcd?

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://www.onemathematicalcat.org/MathJaxDocumentation/TeXSyntax.htm) to format your posts.  To begin with, surround math expressions (including numbers) with `$` signs and use `_` for subscripts.  `$x_1$` comes out as $x_1$.

Comment: If $gdc(a,20)\neq 1$, the equation may have no solution. For example, $2x\equiv 3 (\mod 20)$. If $1\neq c = gdc(a,20)$, then $c\mid b$

Comment: By [general theory](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2053174/242) there are no solutions if $\,d = (a,20)\nmid b,\,$ else there are $\,d\,$ solutions. What more do you need?