# Why we cannot divide one zero divisor by another one? Or can we?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, hypercomplex-numbers

For instance, in split-complex numbers we definitely have $2\cdot(j/2+1/2)=j+1$, which is absolutely valid. Can we then say that $\frac{j+1}{j/2+1/2}=2$? If not, why we cannot define it this way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Division by a zero divisor can never give a *unique* quotient. Suppose that $a$ is a zero divisor, so $\,\color{#c00}{a\hat a=0},\,\ a,\hat a\neq 0.\,$ Then $\, a\:\!\:\!x = b\Rightarrow \color{#c00}a(x+c\color{#c00}{\hat a}) = b,\,$ so there is no unique solution $\,x := b/a.\,$  OP is case $\,a = r(j+1),\ \hat a = j-1,\ r = \frac{1}2,\,$ where $\,a\hat a = r(j+1)(j-1)=0,\,$ by $\,j^2=1.$

Comment: But the equation $x(j/2+1/2)=j+1$ has unique solution $x=2$ does not it?

Comment: @Anixx  No, since the answer proves that $\,x = 2+c\color{#c00}{(j-1)}$ is a solution for all $\,c.\ $ The map $\,x \to zx\,$ has nonzero kernal so it cannot be $1$-$1\ \ $

Comment: Oh I see, $x=3/2+j/2$ also satisfies it...

Comment: But then, can we talk about a kind of *main value* of such division?

Comment: @Anixx What do you mean by "main value"?

Comment: Something along the lines of $0^0=1$ even though $\log_0 x=0$ for any non-zero $x$

Comment: @Anixx It's unsolvable - just scale by $1+j\,$ (or eval at $j = 1).\,$ You deleted the comment but I'll leave this till you see it.

Comment: Yes, I see it, thanks. I realize it's insolveble because in $\mathbb R^2$ there is no solution for $(x,y)(1,0)=(0,1)$.

Comment: Well, given that the main value (and the only algebraically sane choice) for $0/0$ is $0$, we should be able to divide $(0,2)/(0,1)=2$, and so $(j+1)/(j/2+1/2)$. Even though there are many solutions to the equation.

Comment: Again, what is the "main value"? How do you propose to *canonically* choose a solution from an infinite set of solutions? (and why try to do so?)

Comment: Cauchy main value at complex plane of $0/0$ is $0$. also, it is the only non-contradicting choice.

Comment: E.g. in $\,\Bbb Z_{15}\!:\,\ \color{#c00}{3\cdot 5 = 0}\,$ so $\,3x = 6\,\Rightarrow\, \color{#c00}3(x\!+\!\color{#c00}5c)= 6,\,$ which yields the *three* solutions $\,x=2,\,2\!+\!5,\,2\!+\!2(5) = 2,\,7,\,12.\,$ Therefore the "fraction" $\,x = \frac{6}2 \,=\, 2,7,12\,$ is *multi-valued*. $ $ In some contexts it proves convenient to extend fractional arithmetic to such solution *sets*, e.g. see [the Remark here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2053174/242) on their use in the extended Euclidean algorithm in fractional form.

Answer (score 6):

**You can define whatever you want**

You can define $\frac{j+1}{j/2+1/2}$ to mean whatever you want.

But the notation suggests we are working in a field where $j+1$ has an inverse. This is not true for the split complex numbers so will confuse the reader.

For example if you write $\frac{j+1}{j/2+1/2}=2$ then your fraction bar does not work the same way the normal fraction bar works. If it did we could multiply both sides by $j-1$ to get

$$\frac{j+1}{j/2+1/2} =2$$

$$\implies \frac{j+1}{j/2+1/2} (j-1)=2(j-1)$$

$$\implies \frac{(j+1)(j-1)}{j/2+1/2}  =2(j-1)$$

$$\implies \frac{0}{j/2+1/2}  =2(j-1)$$

$$\implies 0  =2(j-1)$$

which is untrue.

Comment: Hmm, but $j-1$ is another zero divisor and it is not evident that we can multiply the both sides by it even if the fraction is valid.

Comment: @Anixx That's even worse. In every other context, we can perform the same operation on both sides of an equality sign. If you have to break that rule to introduce your new notation that means it is **really bad notation**.

Answer (score 1):

Given a commutative ring. Division is an operation derived from multiplication, i.e., $c=a:b$ is defined as $c=a\cdot b^{-1}$, where the divisor $b$ must be invertible. Note that invertible elements (units) are not  zero-divisors. Similar situation for subtraction which is derived from addition.