# How to find all solutions for $12x \equiv 12 \pmod {30}$?

Tags: modular-arithmetic

How to find all solutions for $12x \equiv 12 \pmod{30}$ ?
$12x \equiv 12 \pmod{30}$ gives $12x=12+30y$ 
$\gcd(30,12)=6$
$30=2\cdot12+6$
$12=2\cdot6$
$6=30-(2*12)$
Multiply all with 2:
$12=2\cdot30-4\cdot12$
Switch sides for easier reading:
$2\cdot30-4\cdot12=12$
I think I am right this far (correct me if I'm wrong). But how do I finish this problem? I don't understand what I'm supposed to do now.

Comment: You applied the Euclidean algorithm and found a solution ($x_0=-4$), but it was useless here since there is an obvious solution, $x_1=2$. Once you have a solution ($x_i=x_0$ or $x_1$), the other solutions $x$ are given by $30\mid12(x-x_i)$, i.e. $5\mid2(x-x_i)$, i.e. $5\mid x-x_i$.

Comment: Every time you use an asterisk to represent multiplication outside computer code, a mathematician somewhere dies a tiny bit inside. Please use "\cdot" ($\cdot$) or "\times" ($\times$) in MathJax.

Comment: By [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2053174/242), cancel $(12,30)\!=\!6$ to get $\bmod 30\!:\ 12x\equiv 12\iff\bmod 5\!:\  2x\equiv 2\iff x\equiv 1,\,$ by $(2,5)=1\Rightarrow 2$ is invertible so cancellable $\!\bmod 5\ \ $

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$12x=12+30y$

$2x=2+5y$

$2x\equiv 2 \space mod \space 5$

Since $(2,5)=1$

$x\equiv 1 \space mod \space 5$ or $x=1+5k$ for some integer k

Comment: Please strive not to post more (dupe) answers to dupes of FAQs, cf. recent site policy announcement [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508/242).