# Why does Gaussian elimination sometimes work in rings where it should not?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modular-arithmetic, gaussian-elimination, finite-rings

I think it's best to illustrate this with an example.

Take for instance the ring of integers modulo $6$. If I have the system of equations:

$$ \begin{aligned} 2x + 2y &= 4 \\ 3x + 4y &= 3 \end{aligned} $$

I divide the first equation by $2$:

$$ \begin{aligned} x +  y &= 2 \\ 3x + 4y &= 3 \end{aligned} $$

Subtract $3$ times the first equation from the 2nd equation to arrive at a solution for $y$:

$$ \begin{aligned} x + y &= 2 \\ 0 + y &= 3 \end{aligned} $$

Thus, $y = 3$ and $x = 5$.

From my understanding, this should be not possible as in ${\Bbb Z}_6$ there is no equivalence to $\frac12$ as $2$ does not have a multiplicative inverse in this ring, but yet I get a solution that works.

The best answer I have is that this is just a particular example in which dividing by $2$ was possible from construction, even if it makes no sense in the ring. I know I can invent situations where this would not be possible, for instance, if equation 1 was:

$$ 1x +3y = 1 $$

I'm curious if there is anything else at play here, or if it's just luck of construction that an answer could be found.

Comment: Even though there are good answers already, let me just add that what you did is analogous to the situation when you have equation $x^2 = 4$, then you apply square root to conclude that $x = \sqrt 4 = 2$. Yes, you got *a solution*, but you missed the solution $x = -2$. The problem is that squaring $x\mapsto x^2$ is not injective on whole of $\mathbb R$, just like multiplying by $2$ is not injective on $\mathbb Z/6\mathbb Z$, meaning $2z = 4$ has more than one solution. You just picked one of the solutions.

Comment: @Ennar Maybe your intension is different, but when we apply the *square root* operation to $x^2=4$ we get : $\sqrt {x^2}=\sqrt 4$ which is equivalent to $|x|=2$ which means $x\in\{-2,2\}$. Applying of the square root operation does *not* imply $x=\sqrt 4=2$ .

Comment: @lonestudent yes, and when you "divide" by $2$ mod $6$, you get result mod $3$ like Bill Dubuque wrote and not mod $6$. I don't see what's bothering you with my comparison?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

It's clearer triangularized: by (fraction-free) Gaussian elimination the system is equivalent to

$$\begin{align} x\ &=\  5\\ 2y\ &= -6\end{align}\qquad$$

But $\,2y \equiv -6 \equiv 0 \pmod{\!6}\iff y \equiv 0\pmod{\!3}\iff y\equiv 0,3\pmod{\!6}\,$ by [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2053174/242).

Essentially you missed the solution $\,y\equiv 0\pmod{\!6}$ due to improper modular cancellation, i.e. not **cancelling $\color{#c00}2$ everywhere** (i.e. from the modulus too), as explained in the prior link, i.e.

$$\begin{align} \color{#c00}2y&\equiv \color{#c00}2\cdot 0\pmod{\color{#c00}2\cdot 3}\\
\iff\ y&\equiv\ \ \ \ \  0\pmod{\ \ \ \ 3}\end{align}\qquad$$

or, divisibility-wise: $\,\color{#c00}2\cdot 3\mid \color{#c00}2y-\color{#c00}2\cdot 0\iff 3\mid y-0\,$ by cancelling $\color{#c00}2,\,$ i.e. $\,6\mid 2y\iff 3\mid y.$

**Remark** $ $ Generally your wrong inference is $\,nx\equiv na\pmod{\!nm}\iff x\equiv a\pmod{\!nm},\,$ but correct is $\,x\equiv a\pmod{\!m},\,$ so $\,\color{#0a0}{x\equiv\, a},\ a\!+\!m,\ a\!+\!2m,\ldots, a+(n\!-\!1)m\pmod{\!nm},\,$ so your wrong inference yields only *one* of the $\,n\,$ solutions $\!\bmod nm,\,$ viz. $\,\color{#0a0}{x\equiv a}\pmod{\!mn}$.

The "reason why it works" is that the direction $\,x\equiv a\pmod{\!mn}\,\Rightarrow\, nx\equiv na\pmod{\!mn}\,$ is *always* true. This multiplication (scaling) is a special case of the [Congruence Product Rule](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/879262/242). It's the cancellation in the opposite direction $(\Leftarrow)$ that fails without cancelling from the modulus too.

Answer (score 9):

The unique solution in $\Bbb Z$ gives of course a solution in $\Bbb Z_6.$ But *your "dividing by 2" made you lose a second solution* mod 6: $x=5,y=0.$

In $\Bbb Z_6,$ your initial system clearly determines only $2y,$ not $y.$

It can be solved without this faulty division as follows, applying Gaussian elimination more carefully:
$$\begin{align}\begin{cases} 2x + 2y &\equiv4\bmod6 \\ 3x + 4y &\equiv3\bmod6 \end{cases}&\iff \begin{cases} 2x + 2y &\equiv4\bmod6\\ (3x + 4y)-2(2x+2y) &\equiv-5\bmod6 \end{cases}\\&\iff \begin{cases} 2x + 2y &\equiv4\bmod6\\x&\equiv5\bmod6 \end{cases}\\&\iff \begin{cases}2y &\equiv0\bmod6\\x&\equiv5\bmod6,\end{cases}\end{align}$$
and
$$2y\equiv0\bmod6\iff y\equiv0\text{ or }3\bmod6.$$

Comment: Maybe it's purely a matter of taste, but I would prefer to use the additive inverse of $2$, which is $4$.  Something like the following $$(3x + 4y)+(-2)(2x+2y) = (3x + 4y)+4(2x+2y) = x$$

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo It is indeed purely a matter of taste. To me, the additive inverse of $2\bmod6$ can as well stay written $(-2)\bmod6,$ exactly like I (implicitely) wrote $3-2\cdot4\equiv-5\bmod6$ where you would seem to prefer rewriting it $3+4\cdot4\equiv1\bmod6.$ Btw, $(3x + 4y)+4(2x+2y)\equiv-x,$ not $x.$

Answer (score 6):

If you multiply the equation $2x + 2y = 4 \pmod 6$ by $\frac12$, you should get $x+y=2\pmod 3$, or equivalently:

$$
\begin{cases}
x+y=2,\text{or} \\
x+y=5
\end{cases}
$$

You miss the second equation and consequently, another solution to the original equation system.

Comment: What does it mean to divide by $2$ if $2$ has no multiplicative inverse in this finite ring?

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo Think it broader: Find the equivalent equation(s) where every coefficient is divided by 2 whenever possible.

Answer (score 3):

Equality is much stronger than congruence. If you find a solution and you are able to state that $x=x_o$ and $y=y_o$ and they are in $\mathbb{Z}$, they will clearly satisfy a modular version of the original equation.

It is a coincidence that the solution is indeed in $\mathbb{Z}$ though. And it could be that there are other solutions if you consider the weaker modular version.

Comment: +1 for being the only one to add the (obvious) remark that such a system might also have solutions in some $\Bbb Z_n$ but none in $\Bbb Z$ (e.g. $2x=1$ has a solution modulo every odd $n$ but $\frac12\notin\Bbb Z$). I wonder whether if a linear system with integer coefficients has a solution modulo every $n\ne0$ then it has a solution in $\Bbb Z.$

Comment: What an interesting ideia, I have no idea how to approach the general case. Here is a very particular linear system: for $ax=b$ and $(a,b)=1$ your conjecture must be true. If $a=\pm 1$, there is a solution in $\mathbb{Z}$ (and for every modular version). Otherwise there is only a solution in $\mathbb{Q}\setminus \mathbb{Z} $. Suppouse there is a modular solution for every $\mathbb{N}$. If we take  $n$ sufficiently large such that $|a|^n> a,b$ and let us consider things $\mod |a|^n$.  As $(b,a)=1$, $(b,|a|^n)=1$ and then $a(zb^{-1})=1$. $a$ is invertible, which is absurd as $(a,|a|^n)=|a|>1$.

Comment: If an IMO world-class mathematician wonders about how to do it, I - a mere mortal- certainly won't be able to solve it. But when you do solve it, I would very much like to see it. :) Thanks for sharing this problem.

Answer (score 2):

Let ${\Bbb Z}_6 := \left( \{0, 1, \dots, 5 \}, +, \cdot \right)$ be a [finite ring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_ring). Consider the following system of [linear equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_equation_over_a_ring) over ${\Bbb Z}_6$.

$$ \begin{aligned} 
    2x + 2y &= 4 \\ 
    3x + 4y &= 3  \end{aligned} $$

Adding the 2nd equation to the 1st one,

$$ \begin{aligned} 
    5x + 0y &= 1 \\ 
    3x + 4y &= 3  \end{aligned} $$

because $2 + 4 = 0$ and $4 + 3 = 1$. Multiplying the 1st equation by $3$ and adding it to the 2nd one,

$$ \begin{aligned} 
    5x + 0y &= 1 \\ 
    0x + 4y &= 0  \end{aligned} $$

because $3 \cdot 5 = 3$ and $3 + 3 = 0$. Consulting the [multiplication table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplication_table) for ${\Bbb Z}_6$, because $5 \cdot 5 = 1$ and $4 \cdot 0 = 4 \cdot 3 = 0$, we obtain $\color{blue}{x = 5}$ and $\color{blue}{y \in \{0,3\}}$.

---

**Matrices**

Working with [augmented](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Augmented_matrix) and [elementary matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_matrix) instead, we obtain the following quasi-[RREF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row_echelon_form)

$$ \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 3 & 1 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} 2 & 2 & 4 \\ 3 & 4 & 3 \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 5 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 4 & 0\end{bmatrix} $$

Note that all entries of these matrices are in the [finite ring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_ring) ${\Bbb Z}_6$. No $\frac12$ to be found.

---

**Tables**

The addition and [multiplication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplication_table) tables for ${\Bbb Z}_6$ are as follows.

$$ \begin{array}{c|cccccc} + & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\ \hline 0 & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\ 1 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 0 \\ 2 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 0 & 1 \\ 3 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 0 & 1 & 2 \\ 4 & 4 & 5 & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 \\ 5 & 5 & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \end{array} \qquad  \begin{array}{c|cccccc} \cdot & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\ \hline 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\ 1 & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\ 2 & 0 & 2 & 4 & 0 & 2 & 4 \\ 3 & 0 & 3 & 0 & 3 & 0 & 3 \\ 4 & 0 & 4 & 2 & 0 & 4 & 2 \\ 5 & 0 & 5 & 4 & 3 & 2 & 1\end{array} $$

Alternatively, $\TeX$ code can be found [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/210670).