# Finding $a + b + c$ given that $\;a + \frac{1}{b+\large\frac 1c} = \frac{37}{16}$

Tags: integer-programming

Please help me to find the needed sum:

> If $a,b,c$ are positive integers such that $\;a + \dfrac{1}{b+\large \frac 1c} = \dfrac{37}{16},\;$
>   find the value of $\;(a+b+c)$.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you at least find $a$?

Comment: Did you expand your expression out to get a single fraction with polynomials in $a,b,c$ top and bottom?

Comment: Yea expanded everything and got terribly stuck!

Comment: Have you studied continued fractions?

Comment: Nope! Thanks guys!

Answer (score 7):

$$\;\color{blue}{\bf a} + \dfrac{1}{\color{red}{\bf b}+1/\color{green}{\bf c}} = \dfrac{37}{16} =  2 + \dfrac 5{16} = 2 + \dfrac 1{\frac{16}{5}} = \color{blue}{\bf 2} + \dfrac 1{\color{red}{\bf 3} + 1/\color{green}{\bf 5}}$$

Now, match up: $\;\color{blue}{\bf a = \;?}\;\quad \color{red}{\bf b = \;?},\quad \color{green}{\bf c = \;?}$

And then find the sum: $$\quad a + b + c = \;\;?$$

Comment: Wow, totally didn't think of this solution at all!
Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome, Raymond!

Comment: You still need to argue that this solution is unique, which is not very hard but missing ;)

Comment: N.S. We can leave some work to the OP!

Comment: Leaving out the sum at the end after you've written explicitly the values of $a,b,c$ seems a bit humorous.

Answer (score 4):

**Hint**

$$a< a + \dfrac{1}{b+1/c}< a+1$$

Answer (score 1):

This is asking for the [Continued Fraction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continued_fraction) expansion of $\frac{37}{16}$. We can use the [Euclid-Wallis Algorithm](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/68021) to compute the expansion:
$$
\begin{array}{r}
&&2&3&5\\\hline
1&0&1&-3&16\\
0&1&-2&7&-37\\
37&16&5&1&0\\
\end{array}
$$
The continued fraction is above the horizontal line:
$$
\frac{37}{16}=2+\cfrac1{3+\cfrac1{5}}
$$
Then, $a+b+c=2+3+5=10$.