# Extended Euclidean Algorithm in $GF(2^8)$?

Tags: field-theory, cryptography

I'm trying to understand how the S-boxes are produced in the AES algorithm. I know it starts by calculating the multiplicative inverse of each polynomial entry in $GF(2^8)$ using the extended euclidean algorithm. However I am having some trouble understanding how to perform the euclidean algorithm with polynomials in a field. Could someone please explain how to do this with a step by step example?

Comment: You don't have to use exactly that way to find the multiplicative inverses. Any way to find them is valid, including just drawing up the 65536-element multiplication table and searching for products that happen to be $1$.

Comment: @Islands I haven't seen that notation before (very new to this). Can you explain the difference?

Comment: @Justin984: are you talking about [this version of $\mathrm{GF}(2^8)$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_field_arithmetic#Rijndael.27s_finite_field), where the elements are viewed as polynomials?

Comment: @robjohn Yes, that's it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using [Rijndael's finite field](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_field_arithmetic#Rijndael.27s_finite_field), the reducing polynomial is $x^8+x^4+x^3+x+1$.

Suppose we want to compute the inverse of $x^5+1$ in this field. We want to solve the equation
$$
a(x^5+1)+b(x^8+x^4+x^3+x+1)=1
$$
I like to use the [Euclid-Wallis Algorithm](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/68021). Since we are dealing with polynomials, I will write things rotated by $90^\circ$.

$$
\begin{array}{c|c}
x^8+x^4+x^3+x+1&0&1&\\\hline
x^5+1&1&0\\\hline
x^4+x+1&x^3&1&x^3\\\hline
x^2+x+1&x^4+1&x&x\\\hline
\color{#C00000}{1}&\color{#C00000}{x^6+x^5+x^3+x^2+x}&\color{#C00000}{x^3+x^2+1}&x^2+x\\\hline
0&x^8+x^4+x^3+x+1&x^5+1&x^2+x+1
\end{array}
$$
The fifth row tells us that in $\mathbb{Z}_2[x]$
$$
(x^5+1)(\color{#C00000}{x^6+x^5+x^3+x^2+x})+(x^8+x^4+x^3+x+1)(\color{#C00000}{x^3+x^2+1})=\color{#C00000}{1}
$$
Thus, $x^6+x^5+x^3+x^2+x$ is the inverse of $x^5+1$ in $\left.\mathbb{Z}_2[x]\middle/(x^8+x^4+x^3+x+1)\mathbb{Z}_2[x]\right.$.

Comment: Took me a while to wrap my head around around your explanation of Euclid-Wallis, but that is a really great algorithm. Thanks!

Comment: @Justin984: thanks for the comment. I have added some arrows to the explanation of the algorithm. Perhaps this might make it easier to understand.

Comment: I guess the first 2 steps are always the same, however further more steps are a little bit unclear. Can You give me a hint or a step by step explanation how is a round calculated according to this table?

Comment: @ampika: All the steps, are pretty much as given in the [Euclid-Wallis Algorithm](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/68021). We just use polynomials and polynomial division.

Comment: I translated your the X^5+1 field and the solution to binary and hex format:
$$x^5+1 --> 00100001 --> split half - 0010 --> 2, 0001 --> 1$$. 
These are the x,y coordinates the [lookup table](http://wiki.crypto.rub.de/Buch/en/download/Understanding-Cryptography-Chapter4.pdf). at Page 13.
$$x^6+x^5+x^3+x^2+x --> 01101110  --> split half - 0110 --> 6, 1110 --> E$$. So the table's value is matching with the converted value.
I tried with x^4+1, and I got this:x^6+x^5+x^4+x+1, which is incorrect, according to the lookup table. I recalculated 3 times, but I could not get the correct result.

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: I figured out how Euclid-Wallis Algorithm works. I'm trying to calculte the Rijndael S-Box. According [this article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rijndael_S-box) I need to determine the multiplicative inverse for a given number in $GF(28) = GF(2)[x]/(x^8 + x4 + x3 + x + 1)$. And then, transform using affine transformation. I did exact same thing, like you, but I wanted to practice, so I computed the inverse of $x^4+1$ in the field, instead of $x^5+1$.

Comment: Using the method above, I get the inverse of $x^4+1$ to be $x^7+x^5+x^4+x^2$.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the java code for EEAP for polynomials .
There are two Polynomials f(x) and G(x) over the finite field M(x) and primeNumber.

package polynomial;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;

class PolyFunction {
    private int degree;
    private int coeff[];

```
PolyFunction(int deg, int coef) {
    this.coeff = new int [deg+1];
    this.coeff[deg] = coef;
    this.degree  = deg;
}
int getDegree() {
    int d = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < coeff.length; i++)
        if (coeff[i] != 0) d = i;
    return d;
}
void checkMode(int primeNumber) {
    for (int i = 0; i <= getDegree(); i++) {
        coeff[i] %= primeNumber;
        if (coeff[i] < 0) 
            coeff[i] += primeNumber;
    }

}

PolyFunction addition(PolyFunction gx,int primeNumber) {
    PolyFunction fx = this;     
    PolyFunction fPlusG = new PolyFunction(Math.max(fx.degree, gx.degree),0);
    for (int i = 0; i <= fx.degree; i++) {
        fPlusG.coeff[i] += fx.coeff[i];
    }
    for (int i = 0; i <= gx.degree; i++) {
        fPlusG.coeff[i] += gx.coeff[i];
    }
    fPlusG.checkMode(primeNumber);
    return fPlusG;
}

PolyFunction minus(PolyFunction gx, int primeNumber) {
    PolyFunction fx = this;
    PolyFunction fMinusg = new PolyFunction(Math.max(fx.degree, gx.degree), 0);
    for (int i = 0; i <= fx.degree; i++) {
        fMinusg.coeff[i] += fx.coeff[i];
    }
    for (int i = 0; i <= gx.degree; i++) {
        fMinusg.coeff[i] -= gx.coeff[i];
    }
    fMinusg.checkMode(primeNumber);
    //fMinusg.degree = fMinusg.getDegree();
    return fMinusg;
}

PolyFunction multiple(PolyFunction gx) {
    PolyFunction fx = this;
    PolyFunction fMulg = new PolyFunction(fx.degree + gx.degree, 0);
    for (int i = 0; i <= fx.degree; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j <= gx.degree; j++)
            fMulg.coeff[i+j] += (fx.coeff[i] * gx.coeff[j]);

    return fMulg;
}

PolyFunction[] PLDA(PolyFunction gx, int primeNumber) {
    PolyFunction fx  = this;

    fx.checkMode(primeNumber);
    gx.checkMode(primeNumber);

    PolyFunction []qr = new PolyFunction[2]; 
    qr[1] = fx;
    qr[0] = new PolyFunction(0,0);

    int degofQ = fx.getDegree() - gx.getDegree() ;

    if (degofQ == 0 && gx.getDegree() == 0) {
        //System.out.println("deg is zero");
        int temp [] = EEA(primeNumber, gx.coeff[0]);
        int divResult = (qr[1].coeff[qr[1].getDegree()] * temp[1]);

        divResult %= primeNumber;
        if ( divResult < 0) 
            divResult += primeNumber;
        qr[0] = new PolyFunction((qr[1].getDegree()-gx.getDegree()), divResult);
        qr[1] = new PolyFunction(0, 0);
        return qr;
    }

    if (degofQ < 0) {

        qr[1] = gx;
        qr[0] = fx;
        return qr;
    }

    while((qr[1].getDegree() >= gx.getDegree()) && (qr[1].getDegree()!=0 && qr[1].coeff[0]!=0)) {

        int [] temp = EEA(primeNumber,gx.coeff[gx.getDegree()]);

        int divResult = (qr[1].coeff[qr[1].getDegree()] * temp[1]);

        divResult %= primeNumber;
        if ( divResult < 0) 
            divResult += primeNumber;
        PolyFunction tx = new PolyFunction((qr[1].getDegree()-gx.getDegree()), divResult);

        qr[0] = qr[0].addition(tx,primeNumber);

        PolyFunction txgx = tx.multiple(gx);

        qr[1] = qr[1].minus(txgx,primeNumber);

        qr[0].checkMode(primeNumber);
        qr[1].checkMode(primeNumber);

    }
    return qr;
}

PolyFunction[] EEAP(PolyFunction gx,int primeNumber) {
    PolyFunction fx = this;
    PolyFunction []qr = new PolyFunction[2];

    if ((gx.getDegree() == 0) && gx.coeff[0] == 0) {            
        int [] temp = EEA(primeNumber,fx.coeff[fx.getDegree()]);

        int divResult = (1 * temp[1]);
        divResult %= primeNumber;
        if ( divResult < 0) 
            divResult += primeNumber;

        qr[0] = new PolyFunction(0, divResult);
        qr[1] = new PolyFunction(0, 0);
        return qr;
    }
    else {
            PolyFunction []R = new PolyFunction[2];
            qr = fx.PLDA(gx,primeNumber);
            PolyFunction q = qr[0];
            PolyFunction r = qr[1];
            R = gx.EEAP(r,primeNumber);

            PolyFunction ux = R[1];
            ux.checkMode(primeNumber);

            PolyFunction vx = R[0].minus(q.multiple(R[1]), primeNumber);
            vx.checkMode(primeNumber);
            return new PolyFunction[]{ux,vx};
    }
}

public int[] EEA(int a, int b){        
    if(b == 0){             
        return new int[]{1,0};                        
    } else {
        int q = a/b; 
        int r = a%b;
        int[] R = EEA(b,r);   
        return new int[]{R[1], R[0]-q*R[1]};
    }
}
public String toString() {
    if (degree ==  0) return "" + coeff[0];
    if (degree ==  1) return coeff[1] + "x + " + coeff[0];

    String ret = coeff[getDegree()] + "x^" + getDegree();

    for (int i = getDegree()-1; i >= 0; i--) {
        if      (coeff[i] == 0) continue;
        else if (coeff[i]  > 0) ret = ret + " + " + ( coeff[i]);
        else if (coeff[i]  < 0) ret = ret + " - " + (-coeff[i]);
        if      (i == 1) ret = ret + "x";
        else if (i >  1) ret = ret + "x^" + i;
    }
    return ret;
}
```

}

public class GF2 {
    private PolyFunction fx;
    private PolyFunction gx;
    private PolyFunction mx;
    private int primeNumber;

```
GF2(String file) {
    fx = gx = mx = null;
    if (readInput(file) == -1) 
        return;
    System.out.println("PrimeNumber is " + primeNumber);
    System.out.println("mx is " + mx);
    System.out.println("fx is " + fx);
    System.out.println("gx is " + gx);
}
private int readInput(String file) {
    int mxDeg = 0, fxDeg = 0, gxDeg = 0;
    try {
        int counter = 1;
        FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(file);
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);
        String data = null;

        while(( data= bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
            switch(counter) {
            case 1:
                primeNumber = Integer.parseInt(data);
                break;
            case 2:
                mxDeg = Integer.parseInt(data);
                break;
            case 3:
                String [] mxToken = data.split("\\s+");
                PolyFunction []p = new PolyFunction[mxToken.length+1];
                for(int i=0; i < mxToken.length; i++) {
                     p[i] = new PolyFunction(mxDeg-i, Integer.parseInt(mxToken[i]));
                }
                mx = p[0];
                for(int i=1; i < mxToken.length; i++)
                    mx = mx.addition(p[i],primeNumber);
                break;
            case 4:
                fxDeg = Integer.parseInt(data);;
                break;
            case 5:
                String [] fxToken = data.split("\\s+");
                PolyFunction []pf = new PolyFunction[fxToken.length+1];
                for(int i=0; i < fxToken.length; i++) {
                     pf[i] = new PolyFunction(fxDeg-i, Integer.parseInt(fxToken[i]));
                }
                fx = pf[0];
                for(int i=1; i < fxToken.length; i++) 
                    fx = fx.addition(pf[i], primeNumber);
                break;
            case 6:
                gxDeg = Integer.parseInt(data);
            case 7:
                String [] gxToken = data.split("\\s+");
                PolyFunction []pg = new PolyFunction[gxToken.length+1];
                for(int i=0; i < gxToken.length; i++) {
                     pg[i] = new PolyFunction(gxDeg-i, Integer.parseInt(gxToken[i]));
                }
                gx = pg[0];
                for(int i=1; i < gxToken.length; i++) 
                    gx = gx.addition(pg[i],primeNumber);
                break;
            }
            counter++;
        }   
        bufferedReader.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("Input file is not able to open");
        return -1;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return -1;
    }
    return 0;
}
void dmas() {
    System.out.println("Addition is : " + fx.addition(gx, primeNumber));
    System.out.println("Subtraction is : " + fx.minus(gx, primeNumber));
    PolyFunction fMulg = fx.multiple(gx);
    if (fMulg.getDegree() >= mx.getDegree()) {
        fMulg = fMulg.PLDA(mx,primeNumber)[1];
        fMulg.checkMode(primeNumber);
    }
    System.out.println("Multiplication is : " + fMulg.toString());

    PolyFunction fDivg = mx.EEAP(gx,primeNumber)[1];
    fDivg = fx.multiple(fDivg);
    if (fDivg.getDegree() >= mx.getDegree()) {
        fDivg = fDivg.PLDA(mx,primeNumber)[1];
        fDivg.checkMode(primeNumber);
    }

    System.out.println("Division is : " + fDivg);

}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String file = "src\\polynomial\\myinput.txt";
    GF2 obj = new GF2(file);
    obj.dmas();
}
```

}

//
In “input.txt”: 
1.  First line is the prime number p.
2.  Second line is the degree n of the irreducible polynomial m(x) over Zp.
3.  Third line is the coefficients of m(x), from the leading coefficient to the constant, separated by one blank space.
4.  Fourth line is the degree of f(x) over Zp.
5.  Fifth line is the coefficients of f(x), from the leading coefficient to the constant, separated by one blank space.
6.  Sixth line is the degree of g(x) over Zp.
7.  Seventh line is the coefficients of g(x), from the leading coefficient to the constant, separated by one blank space.
//
Suppose we have data in input is
1> 7
2> 3
3> 1 0 0 3
4> 2
5> 2 0 1
6> 1

### 7> 3 2

output is
1> PrimeNumber is 7
2> mx is 1x^3 + 3
3> fx is 2x^2 + 1
4> gx is 3x + 2
5> Addition is : 2x^2 + 3x + 3
6> Subtraction is : 2x^2 + 4x + 6
7> Multiplication is : 4x^2 + 3x + 5

### 8> Division is : 6x^2 + 6x + 3

Comment: Are you sure that this is an  answer to the question ?