# Multiplicative Inverse in $GF(2^8)$ using Extended Euclidiean Algorithm.

Tags: galois-theory, cryptography

We know that the AES S-box is generated by determining the multiplicative inverse of a given number in GF$(2^8)$. Considering this information, we have to explain:

what is $\{07\}^{-1}$ in GF$(2^8)$? This problem must be solved with Extended Euclidean algorithm.

Could someone please explain how to do this with a step by step example?

Comment: What is $\{07\}$?

Comment: It is much easier to calculate the log and power tables for the AES generator `0x1b`.
Then the inverse of $x\ne 0$ is `x'=PowerTab[255-LogTab[x]]`. With this you find, that the inverse of `0x07` is `0xD1`. The tables can also be used for fast multiplication and division in $GF(2^8).$

Comment: Assuming you also use the field defined by $p(x)=x^8+x^4+x^3+x+1$ (so that
$\{07\}$ stands for the coset of $x^2+x+1+\langle p(x)\rangle$), you can use the method described [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/529238/11619).

Comment: In software you can, of course, use a discrete logarithm table as apparently suggested by @gammatester. However, I find it strange to call `0x1b` a generator. I realize that when doing field arithmetic you will XOR with `0x11b`whenever you get an overflow to bit in position $8$, but I wouldn't call `0x1b` *a generator* because of this. The multiplicative group is generated by `0x02`, i.e. the coset $x+\langle p(x)\rangle$ (= the base of thet discrete log table). But, if that's standard AES-slang, fine :-) Shrug.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen: Sorry it was my 'slang'. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_field_arithmetic#Rijndael.27s_finite_field) uses the term
*reducing polynomial*.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Thanks. Your solution help me to calculate my problem. I just use Extended Euclidiean Algorithm instead of  Euclid-Wallis Algorithm.