# Multiplicative inverse of a polynomial in $GF(8)$

Tags: number-theory, galois-theory, finite-fields, cryptography

I am trying to find the inverse of $x ^3+x +1$ in $GF(8)$ defined on the quotient ring $GF(2)[x]/\langle x^3+x+1\rangle$.
I have done the Euclidean algorithm but I am stuck in the forward process to get the inverse. Please explain how to do it from reverse.

Comment: Do it [this way](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2959891/242) - much less painful and less error-prone.

Comment: Normally $x$ stands for an indeterminate, when $x^3+x+1$ is a polynomial. Polynomials don't have inverses in a finite field. If, as I suspect, $x$ stands for some element of $GF(8)$ you need to tell us which element. Or at least, tell us its minimal polynomial. You see, very often the field $GF(8)$ is defined as the quotient ring $GF(2)[x]/\langle x^3+x+1\rangle$. But, in that field the coset of $x^3+x+1$ is equal to zero. Again implying that it has no inverse (can't divide by zero).

Comment: The (only) other alternative is to have defined $GF(8)$ as the quotien $GF(2)[x]/\langle x^3+x^2+1\rangle$. In that case the coset of $x^3+x+1$ equals the coset of $x^2+x$ (because $(x^3+x+1)-(x^3+x^2+1)=x^2+x$). You can find the inverse of that by the usual process involving extended Euclid. You see, to positively id an element of the quotient ring we customarily reduce them by the polynomial defining the field.

Comment: By saying finite field, i mean the polynomial of the field, which is x^8+ x^4+ x^3+x+1. So i have to find the inverse of the first polynomial modulus this one

Comment: What do you mean by $x^8 + x^4 + x^3 + x + 1$ being the "polynomial of the field"?

Comment: But, Mariam, the polynomial $x^8+x^4+x^3+x+1$ defines the version of the field $GF(2^8)=GF(256)=GF(2)[x]/\langle x^8+x^4+x^3+x+1\rangle$ IIRC used in AES cryptosystem (among other things).

Comment: For finding inverses in the AES field with Extended Euclid I recommend that you take a peek at [this old thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/529156/11619). Robjohn spelled it out!

Comment: [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/591254/11619) I spell out what $GF(8)$, also known as $\Bbb{F}_8$, looks like. If I were to use $GF(256)$ in a computer program I would build a similar logarithm table for $GF(256)$ and use it calculate inverses.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: The field $GF(8)$ is isomorphic to $GF(2)[x]/\langle x^3+x+1\rangle$ or to $GF(2)[x]/\langle x^3+x^2+1\rangle$. The polynomials $x^3+x+1$ and $x^3+x^2+1$ are the only irreducible polynomials over $GF(2)$ (and they are conjugate).
The elements of $GF(8)$ are the residue classes of the polynomials $ax^2+bx+c$, where $a,b,c\in GF(2)$. So maybe you should rethink about your question.

Comment: What do you mean by those polynomials being conjugate?

Comment: The comment thread under the question sounds a lot like the OP didn't actually mean $GF(8)$ but $GF(2^8)$, represented using the primitive polynomial $x^8+x^4+x^3+x+1$.