# The inverse of $x^3+1$ modulo $x^8+x^4+x^3+x+1$ over $\Bbb F_2$?

Tags: abstract-algebra

I'm thinking a problem related to bloch cypher AES. In a step of AES, I need to solve the thing stated below: How to solve the inverse of $x^3+1$ modulo $x^8+x^4+x^3+x+1$ over $\Bbb F_2$? Namely find $g(x)$ s.t. $(x^3+1)g(x)\equiv1~(\text{mod}~x^8+x^4+x^3+x+1)$.

Comment: Extended Euclidean algorithm?

Comment: See  [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/529156/11619) for a description of the method together with an example run.