# Euclidean algorithm to find integers $s$ and $t$ such that $sa+tb=1$

Tags: number-theory

$a=19845$, $b=218$

I got this far but am now stuck and don't know what to do.

```
19845 % 218 = 7
218 % 7 = 1
1 = 218 - (7*31)
7 = 19845 - (218*91)
1 = 218 - ((19845-218*91)*31)
```

Then from there I do not know how to simplify it to get the values for $s$ and $t$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the distributive law:
\begin{align}
1 &= 218 - (19845-218\cdot 91)\cdot 31 \\
&= 218 - 19845\cdot 31 + 218\cdot 91\cdot 31 \\
&= 218 \cdot (1 + 91\cdot 31) + 19845\cdot (-31) \\
&= 218\cdot 2822 + 19845\cdot (-31)
\end{align}
Thus, $s=-31$ and $t=2822$.

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, you can use the [Euclid-Wallis Algorithm](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/68021):
$$
\begin{array}{r}
&&91&31&7\\\hline
1&0&1&-31&218\\
0&1&-91&2822&-19845\\
19845&218&7&1&0\\
\end{array}
$$
This says that
$$
2822\cdot218-31\cdot19845=1
$$
The bookkeeping incorporated in that algorithm takes care of the difficulty that often accompanies the Euclidean Algorithm.

Comment: Is this just the [Extended Euclidean Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm) written sideways?

Comment: That article seems to have gone under many changes recently, but the algorithm seems to be the same. It is a common algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

$ 218t+19845s = 1\iff \bmod 218\!:\ s\equiv\dfrac{1}{19845}\equiv \dfrac{1}7\equiv \dfrac{-217}7\equiv -31$