# 444x = 148 in Z964

Tags: number-theory

The question is to find all solutions of each equation:
$$444x = 148 \in \Bbb Z_{964}$$

$$39x = 37 \in \Bbb Z_{53}$$

I've googled the answer and got no results.  I think I'm supposed to use extended gcd algorithm but I'm not sure how

Comment: Googled... *the answer* ? It is internet, not black magic! What've you tried so far?

Comment: I've tried finding a method of answering this question online (googled it) and I didn't find anything.

Comment: @observeRReacts: Maybe you should consult a software like WA or Mathematica.

Comment: Should it be $44x$ or $444x$?

Comment: @Cameron Buie 444x

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll work the second one first. Note that $$53=39+14\\39=2\cdot14+11\\14=11+3\\11=3\cdot 3+2\\3=2+1\\2=2\cdot 1+0,$$ so $$1=3-2\\2=11-3\cdot 3\\3=14-11\\11=39-2\cdot14\\14=53-39.$$ Hence, by repeated substitution, we have $$\begin{align}1 &= 3-2\\ &= 3-(11-3\cdot 3)\\ &= 4\cdot 3-11\\ &= 4\cdot (14-11)-11\\ &= 4\cdot14-5\cdot11\\ &= 4\cdot14-5(39-2\cdot14)\\ &= 14\cdot14-5\cdot39\\ &= 14(53-39)-5\cdot39\\ &= 14\cdot53-19\cdot39.\end{align}$$ This means that in $\Bbb Z_{53},$ we have $1=39\cdot-19,$ so multiplying both sides of $39x=37\pmod{53}$ by $-19,$ we have $$\begin{align}x &= -19\cdot 37\pmod{53}\\ &= -703\pmod{53}\\ &= 14\cdot53-703\pmod{53}\\ &= 742-703\pmod{53}\\ &= 39\pmod{53},\end{align}$$ and so $x=39+53n$ for some $n\in\Bbb Z$.

---

For the first one, note that $$964=2\cdot 444+76\\444=5\cdot76+64\\76=64+12\\64=5\cdot12+4\\12=3\cdot4+0.$$ Hence, $4$ is the greatest common divisor of $964$ and $444$. In particular, working our way back through, we end up with $$4 = 76\cdot444-35\cdot964.$$ So multiplying both sides of $444x=148\pmod{964}$ by $76,$ we have $$\begin{align}4x &= 22\cdot 148\pmod{964}\\ &= 11248\pmod{964}\\ &= -11\cdot964+11248\pmod{964}\\ &= -10604+11248\pmod{964}\\ &= 644\pmod{964},\end{align}$$ so $4x=644+964n$ for some $n\in\Bbb Z,$ and so $x=161+241n$ for some $n\in\Bbb Z$.

Comment: This is fantastic but could you do it for 444x?

Comment: Fixed. Take a look.

Comment: You are the man, THANK YOU. I just needed an example that broke it down like this so that I could do more.

Comment: There are 4 answers that I know of.  I don't see yours?

Comment: Well, since you're probably assuming for the first one that $0\le x\le 963,$ then we can restrict our attention to $x=161+241n$ for $n=0,1,2,3.$ That is, $x=161,402,643,884.$ Does that match up? Note that (for example) when $n=4,$ we get $1125,$ but $$\begin{align}1125 &= -964+1125\pmod{964}\\ &= 161\pmod{964},\end{align}$$ so we didn't really get anything new.

Comment: On the first one, did you mean x= 39 + 53n? And here, do you mean 161, 402, 643, 884?  THanks again.

Comment: Yes, on the first one, I meant $x=39+53n$. That was a typo. And here, I did mean that. If you refresh the page, you should see that I corrected that comment.

Comment: how did you multiply 444x by 76 and get 4x?

Comment: **Hint**: Don't forget that $964=0\pmod{964}.$ We will do the same sort of thing that we did to get $-19\cdot37=39\pmod{53}.$

Comment: ok, i get that 35*964 = 33740 r 4 but why 76?

Comment: You need to work your way through the repeated substitution, as in the first part, where we started with $$\begin{align}1 &= 3-2\\ &= 3-(11-3\cdot3)\\ &\vdots\end{align}$$

Answer (score 0):

The answers are [here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Solve%5BMod%5B444%2ax%2C964%5D%3D148%2Cx%5D) and [here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Solve%5BMod%5B39%2ax%2C53%5D%3D%3D37%2Cx%5D). Maybe you just weren't using the right keywords?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a start:

The [Euclid-Wallis Algorithm](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/68021) is an implementation of the Extended Euclidean Algorithm.
$$
\begin{array}{r}
&&21&1&10\\\hline
1&0&1&-1&11\\
0&1&-21&22&-241\\
964&44&40&4&0\\
\end{array}
$$
So we get that
$$
(22)44+(-1)964=4
$$
Multiplying by $37$ and adding the homogenous solution, we get
$$
(814-241k)44+(-37+11k)964=148
$$

---

Even if the numbers are changed, the process is the same:
$$
\begin{array}{r}
&&2&5&1&5&3\\\hline
1&0&1&-5&6&-35&111\\
0&1&-2&11&-13&76&-241\\
964&444&76&64&12&4&0\\
\end{array}
$$
So we get that
$$
(76)444+(-35)964=4
$$
Multiplying by $37$ and adding the homogenous solution, we get
$$
(2812-241k)444+(-1295+111k)964=148
$$
We can adjust $k$ to get a smaller particular solution:
$$
(161-241k)444+(-74+111k)964=148
$$

Comment: @ robjohn so so sorry it's 444x

Comment: @observeRReacts: the algorithm and process is the same.