# Understanding extended Euclid Algorithm

Tags: number-theory

I have the ecuation:

$$42x \equiv 12 \text{ mod } 60$$

Using my logic the answer should be:

$x = \frac{43 \cdot ?}{12}=$ something $r$ $60$  but since that was an exam subject don't think that is so simple.

Answer (score 4):

Since $(42,60)=6$, divide the equation by $6$: $7x\equiv2\pmod{10}$. Now these numbers are small enough to use a brute force approach, but we can also use the [Euclid-Wallis](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/68021) implementation of the [Euclidean Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm) without first dividing:
$$
\begin{array}{r}
&&1&2&3\\\hline
1&0&1&-2&7\\
0&1&-1&\color{#C00000}{3}&\color{#0000FF}{-10}\\
60&42&18&\color{#00A000}{6}&0
\end{array}
$$
This says that $(60,42)=6$ and $42\cdot\color{#C00000}{3}\equiv\color{#00A000}{6}\pmod{60}$. Multiply by $2$ to get
$$
42\cdot6\equiv12\pmod{60}
$$
The last column says that we can add integer multiples of $\color{#0000FF}{-10}$ to this solution to get all the solutions.

Comment: +1 Finally an answer that employs the euclidean algorithm as (apparently) requested.

Answer (score 1):

Divide by 6 and get $7x \equiv 2 \pmod {10},\,$ with a solution $x\equiv 6 \pmod {10}$ - either by guessing or with $7^{-1}\equiv 3 \pmod {10}.\,$ Now verify that $6\times 42 \equiv 12 \pmod {60},\,$ i.e. $6$ is also a solution to your original problem (as indicated in the comments there are more solutions, actually $x\equiv 6+10k\pmod{60}, k=0\dots 5\,$).

Comment: $x\equiv6\pmod{10}$ *is* the solution (i.e. there are $6$ solutions $\bmod{60}$). No multiplying back necessary. Fortunately, $36\equiv 6\pmod{10}$, therefore that happened to work.

Comment: @ccorn No, as written, the method *does* require *verfiying* the solution(s) because the proof's inferences are *unidirectional,* i.e. employ $\,\Rightarrow\,$ vs $\,\iff\ \ $

Comment: @BillDubuque: Getting to $7x\equiv 2\pmod{10}$ is bidirectional. Remember that $gA\equiv gB\pmod{gN}$ means $gN\mid(gA-gB)$ which is *equivalent* to $N\mid(A-B)$ for $g\neq 0$, hence equivalent to $A\equiv B\pmod{N}$

Comment: @ccorn My point is: that is true *only if* you explicitly write the proof in such bidirectional form, which is not true above. Confusion between unidirectiona and bidirectional inferences is a very common source of errors for students, so one needs to be explicit about such.

Answer (score 0):

First thing you can do here is simplify the problem by dividing through by 6.

i.e. if $42x \equiv 12$ mod $60$, then $7x \equiv 2$ mod $10$.

What does $2$ mod $10$ mean? It means that the number ends in a 2.

Hope this helps.