# Showing that $x^{11} \equiv 5 \pmod{47}$ has only solution $x \equiv 15$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, problem-solving

[image]

I don't understand the proof. Where did they get the first line from, i.e.,  $21 \times 11=1+5 \times 46$?

Fermat's theorem in my view is $a^{46} \equiv 1 \pmod {47}$.

Comment: basic arithmetic: $\;21\cdot 11=231=5\cdot46+1\;$ ...what's unclear here?

Comment: Since $(21,46) = 1$, they want to find the $r,s\in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $21r+46s = 1$, and then apply Femat's theorem on the 2nd line. Admittedly, the proof is a little convoluted.

Comment: So if I get the same question in the exam. Where do i get this 21 from? It is not given in the question

Comment: The 21 is the inverse of the 11, when you work modulo 46.

Comment: Unless there's a special context, it seems quite odd to call that a lemma; I think "example" would be the more appropriate term. Also, I wonder about the reputability of a source that writes such things as $\textsf x \times \textsf x$ instead of $x \cdot x$.

Answer (score 3):

By Fermat's Little Theorem, $x^{46}\equiv 1\pmod{47}$ for all $x\not\equiv0\pmod{47}$. Therefore,
$$
\begin{align}
\left(x^{11}\right)^{21}
&=x^{46\cdot5+1}\\
&=\left(x^{46}\right)^5\,x^1\\
&\equiv1\cdot x\pmod{47}\tag{1}
\end{align}
$$
for all $x\not\equiv0\pmod{47}$. On the other hand, if $x\equiv0\pmod{47}$, equation $(1)$ is true also. Therefore, if we know $x^{11}\bmod{47}$, we can compute $x$.

Using the [Square and Multiply Method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring), we get
$$
\begin{align}
5^0&\equiv\hphantom{0}1\pmod{47}\\
5^1&\equiv\hphantom{0}5\pmod{47}&&\text{multiply by $5$}\\
5^2&\equiv25\pmod{47}&&\text{square}\\
5^4&\equiv14\pmod{47}&&\text{square}\\
5^5&\equiv23\pmod{47}&&\text{multiply by $5$}\\
5^{10}&\equiv12\pmod{47}&&\text{square}\\
5^{20}&\equiv\hphantom{0}3\pmod{47}&&\text{square}\\
5^{21}&\equiv15\pmod{47}&&\text{multiply by $5$}
\end{align}
$$

---

**A Note on $\boldsymbol{11\cdot21=46\cdot5+1}$**

Using the Extended Euclidean Algorithm, as implemented in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/68021), we can solve $11x-46y=1$ (that is, $11x\equiv1\pmod{46}$):
$$
\begin{array}{r}
&&4&5&2\\\hline
\color{#00A000}{1}&0&1&\color{#00A000}{-5}&11\\
0&\color{#C00000}{1}&-4&\color{#C00000}{21}&-46\\
\color{#00A000}{46}&\color{#C00000}{11}&2&1&0
\end{array}
$$
This says that $21\cdot11-46\cdot5=1$.

Answer (score 2):

Checking the steps of a less messy proof (the one you copied it rather cumbersome), 
 and doing arithmetic modulo $\;47\;$ : since $\;15=3\cdot 5\;$ , and

$$\begin{align*}3^3=&27=-20\implies 3^4=-60=-13\implies3^5=-39=8\implies\\{}\\3^{10}=&64=17\implies\color{red}{3^{11}=51=4}\\
{}\\5^2=&25=-22\implies5^3=-110=-16\implies5^4=-80=14\\{}\\\implies5^8=&196=8\implies\color{red}{5^{11}=5^3\cdot5^8=-16\cdot8=-128=-34=13}\end{align*}$$

and thus

$$15^{11}=3^{11}\cdot5^{11}=4\cdot13=52=5$$