# System modular equation.

Tags: modular-arithmetic

Consider:
$$\begin{cases} x\equiv 2 \mod 4 \\ x \equiv 2 \mod 6 \end{cases} $$
And we would like use Chinese remainder theorem but we can't because $\gcd(4,6) > 1$ How can I deal with it.

Comment: Investigate using lcm(4,6) as the modular base.

Comment: ok, so we get one equation?

Comment: Either one or none, depending on the values. In this case, yes, you get one.

Comment: so, the solution for that is: 12k+2
yes?

Comment: Yes, can you see why other values (other than 2 that is) will not satisfy the equivalences?

Comment: No, I can not .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/20130/discussion-between-user180834-and-joffan).

Answer (score 5):

A more systematic approach:

By the Chinese remainder theorem, $x \equiv 2 \mod 6$ is equivalent to $x$ being both $2 \mod 2$ and $2 \mod 3$. So we can write a system of three equations:

$$\begin{cases} x\equiv 2 \mod 4 \\ 
x \equiv 2 \mod 2 \\
x \equiv 2 \mod 3 \end{cases} $$

The first two equations are modulo powers of the same prime, so we have to check whether they are compatible; they are (if they were not, we could immediately deduce that there are no solutions). So the condition $x \equiv 2 \mod 2$ is superfluous, it is already implied by $x \equiv 2 \mod 4$. So we end up with the following system:

$$\begin{cases} x\equiv 2 \mod 4 \\ 
x \equiv 2 \mod 3 \end{cases} $$

Now we have coprime numbers $4$ and $3$, so we can use the Chinese remainder theorem to finish and find the solution $x \equiv 2 \mod 12$.

Answer (score 2):

$ \begin{array}{}{\bf Hint}\!\!\!\! &&x\equiv a\pmod{\!m}\\ &&x\equiv a\pmod{\!n}\end{array}\!\iff\, m,n\mid x\!-\!a\iff {\rm lcm}(m,n)\mid x\!-\!a$

Comment: +1.    Could you add  $\ .... \iff x \equiv a\  (\mod \text{lcm} (m,n)\ )$ ?

Comment: @orangeskid It's a hint, so some things are left for the OP.

Comment: Oh, OK, makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

Starting with
$$\begin{cases} x\equiv 2 \mod 4 \\ 
x \equiv 2 \mod 6 \end{cases} $$
we can investigate whether these conditions can be combined. The shortest cycle that contains 4 and 6 is the lcm(4,6) = 12.

$x \equiv 2 \mod 4$ gives $x\equiv \{2,6 \text{ or } 10\} \mod 12$

$x \equiv 2 \mod 6$ gives $x\equiv \{2 \text{ or }8\} \mod 12$

Clearly only 2 can meet both conditions.

The combined condition is therefore $x \equiv 2 \mod 12$

If, instead we had been looking for, say, 
$$\begin{cases} x\equiv 3 \mod 4 \\ 
x \equiv 2 \mod 6 \end{cases} $$

there would have been no solutions.

Comment: The only solution for it is: 2?

Comment: to modularity 12, yes. In the integers, 2, 14, 26, etc.

Comment: ok, and is it true?
$$\begin{cases} 2x\equiv 4 \mod 8\\ x \equiv 2 \mod 6 \end{cases} \iff $$\begin{cases} x\equiv 2 \mod 4 \\ x \equiv 2 \mod 6 \end{cases} $$

Comment: Please somebody confirm it.

Comment: Well, it is actually true that $2x \equiv 4 \mod 8 \implies x \equiv 2 \mod 4$, but division in modular numbers is not always straightforward.

Comment: I know. So this $\iff$ is true and first system has also solution $2$?

Comment: Yes, that's correct

Answer (score 1):

$x\equiv 2\pmod 4\implies x=2+4n$ for some $n\in\Bbb Z$. So,

$$2+4n\equiv 2\pmod 6 \implies 4n\equiv 0\pmod 6$$. If $m=4n$, then $6|m$, therefore
$m=12k$ for some $k$, and therefore the solutions are:

$$x=2+12k, k\in\Bbb Z.$$

Answer (score 0):

We can also approach this by dividing by the common factor.
$$
\begin{align}
x/2&\equiv1\pmod2\\
x/2&\equiv2\pmod3
\end{align}\tag{1}
$$

---

**If Luck is With Us**

If we notice that these are the same as
$$
\begin{align}
x/2&\equiv-1\pmod2\\
x/2&\equiv-1\pmod3
\end{align}\tag{2}
$$
we can immediately get the solution to be
$$
x/2\equiv-1\pmod6\tag{3}
$$
which is the same as
$$
x\equiv-2\pmod{12}\tag{4}
$$
or
$$
x\equiv10\pmod{12}\tag{5}
$$

---

**Extended Euclidean Algorithm**

If we don't notice a nice relationship as we did in $(2)$, then we can resort to the Extended Euclidean Algorithm. First we solve
$$
\begin{align}
x/2&\equiv1\pmod2\\
x/2&\equiv0\pmod3
\end{align}\tag{6}
$$
and
$$
\begin{align}
x/2&\equiv0\pmod2\\
x/2&\equiv1\pmod3
\end{align}\tag{7}
$$
and add twice a solution of $(7)$ to a solution of $(6)$.

Here we proceed as implemented in the [Euclid-Wallis Algorithm](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/68021) to solve $3x+2y=1$:

$$
\begin{array}{r}
&&1&2\\\hline
1&0&1&-2\\
0&1&-1&3\\
3&2&1&0\\
\end{array}\tag{8}
$$
$(8)$ gives the solution $3(1)+2(-1)=1$. This says that $x/2=3(1)$ is $1\bmod2$ and so solves $(6)$. It also says that $x/2=2(-1)$ is $1\bmod3$ and so solves $(7)$. Adding twice the solution to $(7)$ to the solution of $(6)$ gives 
$$
x/2\equiv-1\pmod6
$$
as a solution to $(1)$ as we got in $(3)$, which leads to the solution in $(5)$.