# Find the least number b for divisibility

Tags: elementary-number-theory, contest-math

What is the smallest positive integer $b$ so that 2014 divides $5991b + 289$?

I just need hints--I am thinking modular arithmetic?

This question was supposed to be solvable in 10 minutes...

Comment: We can get lucky. Note that $5991\equiv -51\pmod{2014}$, "so" we are solving $3b\equiv 17\pmod{2014}$. But it is undoubtedly better to use a general procedure, as per sasha's answer.

Comment: @AndréNicolas I dont get something in sasha answer. We have $5991b + 289 \equiv 0 \pmod{2014}$ how does that imply $5991b \equiv 1725 \pmod{2014}$? Wouldnt you just move to get: $-289$?

Comment: Well, $-289\equiv 1725\pmod{2014}$ or more informally replace $-289$ by $2014-289$.

Comment: How do you determine $-289 \equiv 1725 \pmod{2014}$ ? If you do $2014/-289$ the remainder isnt $1725$?

Comment: We are working mod $2014$. We are (sort 0f) finding the remainder when $-289$ is divided by $2014$. We have $-289=(-1)(2014)+1725$. Or more simply $-289=1725-2014$, so mod $2014$ the numbers $-289$ and $1725$ are "the same" (their difference is divisible by $2014$). By the way, did you find the answer using my comment? It takes a few seconds of additional work.

Comment: @AndréNicolas, I dont see it yet... How do you calculate $\pmod$? How is: $5991 \equiv -41 \pmod{2014}$ How is that solving $3b \equiv 17 \pmod{2014}$ ??

Comment: @AndréNicolas Nevermind. Iget how $5991 \equiv -51 \pmod{2014}$  But how is that solving $3b \equiv 17 \pmod{2014}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As 2014 divides the expression we have 
$$5991b+289=0 \pmod {2014}$$
$$5991b=1725 \pmod { 2014}$$

Now as you said you only want hint you just need to find modulo inverse of 5991 $\pmod{2014}$ and multiply both sides to get $b$. ( Note as 5991 and 2014 are co-prime the inverse modulo of 5991 $\pmod{2014}$ exists). Also If you are new to modular arithmetic then look up modulo inverse, when it exists and extended euclid gcd method to find it. Hope it helps.

Comment: Can you perhaps give me some links. Everything I look up about modulo inverse is too complicated?

Comment: Wikipedia has [a decent article on it](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_multiplicative_inverse). The extended Euclidean algorithm section tells how to compute it.

Answer (score 2):

Using the Extended Euclidean Algorithm as implemented in the [Euclid-Wallis Algorithm](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/68021):
$$
\begin{array}{r}
&&2&1&38&2&25\\\hline
1&0&1&-1&39&-79&2014\\
0&1&-2&3&-116&235&-5991\\
5991&2014&1963&51&25&1&0\\
\end{array}
$$
Therefore, $2014\cdot235-5991\cdot79=1\implies5991\cdot79+1\equiv0\pmod{2014}$.

Multiply the last equivalence by $289$ to get the equivalence
$$
5991\cdot b+289\equiv0\pmod{2014}
$$
for $b\equiv289\cdot79\pmod{2014}$.

Answer (score 0):

${\rm mod}\ 2014\!:\ b\equiv \dfrac{-289}{5991}\overset{\large\frown}\equiv\dfrac{0}{2014}\overset{\large\frown}\equiv\dfrac{-289}{-51}\overset{\large\frown}\equiv\dfrac{813}{25}\overset{\large\frown}\equiv\dfrac{-677}{-1}\ $ by [fractional ext. Euclidean.](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2053174/242)