# How to find inverse Modulo?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

Find the inverse modulo,

Modulo inverse of $5991 \pmod{2014}$ ?

I am aware of the Euclid algorithm, but I am not sure how to apply it here?

Comment: Use it the same way you use it always.. $5991=2014\cdot 2+x$. Then $2014=x\cdot y+r_1$... continue until you find the last remainder which is not zero

Comment: See the method linked to in [this answer.](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/765333/242) This is generally the easiest to perform (and to remember!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The (extended) Euclidean algorithm applied to $a,b$ does not only give the $\gcd(a,b)$ but also two integers $u,v$ such that $ua +vb = \gcd(a,b)$. Also, note that you can only find a modular inverse of $a \mod b$ if $\gcd(a,b)=1$.

Now, to use this to fine modular inverses proceed like this.

- Perform extended Euclidean algorithm on $5991$ and $2014$.
- You find $1=\gcd(5991, 2014)$ and $u,v$ such that $u\ 5991 +v\ 2014 = 1$.

So, $  u \ 5991 = 1 + v\  2014$. And this just means $u \ 5991 \equiv 1 \mod 2014$, that is $u$ is the modular inverse you searched.

This assumes knowing how to perform the extended Euclidean algorithm to find the GCD and the couple $(u,v)$ sometimes called Bézout coefficients. For details on this algorithm see [How to use the Extended Euclidean Algorithm manually?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/85830/how-to-use-the-extended-euclidean-algorithm-manually)

---

A way to do the extended Euclidean algorithm is to start from the following two equations:

- $5991 \cdot 1 + 2014 \cdot 0 = 5991$ (Eq 1)
- $5991 \cdot 0 + 2014 \cdot 1 = 2014$ (Eq 2)

Now perform the normal Euclidean algorithm on the right and keep track of what you do on the left. As $5991 = 2\cdot  2014 + 1963$:

- $5991 \cdot 1 + 2014 \cdot (-2) = 1963 $ (Eq 3 is Eq 1 minus two times Eq 2).

As $2014 = 1 \cdot 1963 + 51$:

- $5991 \cdot (-1) + 2014 \cdot 2 = 51 $ (Eq 4 is Eq 2 minus  Eq 3).

As $1963 = 38 \cdot 51 + 25$:

- $5991 \cdot 39 + 2014 \cdot (-74) = 25 $ (Eq 5 is Eq 3 minus 38 times  Eq 4).

As $51 = 2 \cdot 25 + 1$:

- $5991 \cdot (-79) + 2014 \cdot 150 = 1 $ (Eq 6 is Eq 4 minus two times  Eq 5).

As $1$ divides $25$, we have found that $1$ is the gcd and we also have in Eq 6 that

$$5991 \cdot (-79)   = 1 - 2014 \cdot (150) $$

So $5991 \cdot (-79)  \equiv 1 \mod 2014$ and $-79$ is the modular inverse. If you want one between $1$ and $2013$ add $2014$ to it. Then it matches the solution in another answer.

Comment: That has been the question all along, how do you find $v$?

Comment: This is one of the things the (extended) Euclidean algorithm returns. You said you knew that algorithm. For an explanation see http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/85830/how-to-use-the-extended-euclidean-algorithm-manually I also updated the answer.

Comment: I do know it, but I dont see how it works here.. Also, how did you know $\gcd(2014, 5991) = 1$?

Comment: I said at the start that you cannot find a modular inverse unless the gcd is $1$ so if the gcd were not one the question would make no sense, and you would find this out once you have completed the algorthm and found a different gcd. I just see I flipped the numbers relative to your question I will fix this.

Comment: That page is too difficult, I am not too experienced with matrices.

Comment: You do not need any experience with matrices. But okay I will spell it out. But next time do not claim you know something that you in fact do not know.

Comment: I performed Euclid's algorithm above: 
 Step 3: $1963/51 = (1)1938 + 25$
Step 4: $1938/25 = (1)1925 + 13$
Step 5: $1925/13 = (1)1924 + 1$
Step 6: $1924/1 = (1)1924 + 0$

Using Steps, 1, 2 from Mark.

Comment: This seems better. But why not a direct approach? Why are you using negatives?

Comment: Because this is what comes out of the extended Euclidean Algorithm performed in this way. Moreover a pair of Bezout coeeficients will essentially always be one positive one negative otherwise you could hardly write $1$ as sum of  multiples of $2014$ and $5991$.

Comment: Okay. So you found $1 \equiv 5991(-79) \pmod{2014}$ But how can you say that the modular inverse is $-79$ I thoght I knew a lot about this but I dont... THANKS!

Comment: The modular inverse of $5991$ is, at least in my mind, the residue class $u$, modulo $2014$ such that $5991 \ u$ is $1$ modulo $2014$. Now $-79$ is clear a member of that residue class as it has the property that $5991 \times (-79) $ is $1$ modulo $2014$ so it is an inverse. If your convention is that you always want representative in a given interval than add $2014$.

Comment: $2014 - 79 = 1935$ So $b = 1935$? If so, its incorrect. $b = 677$ is the answer.

Comment: Yes. And note it matches the result in an other answers.

Comment: Wait, I want to link this.  http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1115400/find-the-least-number-b-for-divisibility  $b$ cannnot be $1935$

Comment: For the **other** problem the answer $677$ seems to be correct. But this $b$ is not the modular inverse of $5991$.

Comment: How? Sasha's answer suggests that?

Comment: It is suggested to find the modular inverse and to then multiply **both** sides with the mod inverse. Your $b$ is (congruent to) the mod inverse *times the number on the right.*

Comment: I actually posted a new question on how to solve congruences. Since this is a congruence really.

Comment: @Amad27 you only need a simple calculator to check: it is $\;5991^{-1}=1935\pmod{2014}\;$

Comment: @Timbuc But how do I use that to solve $5991b \equiv 1725  \pmod{2014} $ Multiply by $1935$ so: 

$$b \equiv 1725*1935 \equiv 3337875 \pmod{2014}$$ Yikes, what can I do?

Comment: "Yikes"?? It's all you need ! Now just simplify 3337875 modulo $\;2014\;$ ...! It's **very** easy to check that $\;3337875=677\pmod{2014}\;$

Answer (score 2):

Hints:

Try to follow, understand and justify the following steps:

$$5991=-51\pmod{2104}$$

But:

$$\begin{align}&-51=2\pmod{53}\;,\;\;2^{-1}=27\pmod{53}\\&-51=6\pmod{19}\;,\;\;6^{-1}=16\pmod{19}\end{align}$$

and thus we need a solution for

$$\begin{cases}x=27\pmod{53}\\{}\\x=16\pmod{19}\\{}\\x=1\pmod2\end{cases}$$

and the Chinese Remainder Theorem (CRT) gives us:

$$x=27\cdot38\cdot\overbrace{7}^{=38^{-1}\pmod{53}}+16\cdot106\cdot\overbrace{7}^{=106^{-1}\pmod{19}}+1\cdot1007\cdot\overbrace{1}^{=1007^{-1}\pmod2}=20061$$

so that finally

$$5991^{-1}=20061=1935\pmod{2014}$$

Comment: You really also deserve an upvote for your efforts related to this.

Comment: @quid Thanks. Somehow the OP didn't think so and decided *only* to upvote and choose your answer which,  by the loooong array of comments below it, I gather (s)he didn't even understand. I think he's very confused and did try to solve **another** problem to begin with which, of course, gets solved once one knows what is $\;5991^{-1}\pmod{2014}\;$ .

Comment: @Timbuc, sorry buddy, I didnt see this answer. (+1) because even though this answer is difficult to understand, it still has rigour. It is (+1) worthy, I'm very sorry Timbuc. =)

Answer (score 1):

After using the Euclidean algorithm and manipulating the equations backward, you can find $a,b \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $$a \cdot 2014 + b \cdot 5991 = 1.$$

Working modulo 2014, we see that $b$ is the inverse of 5991.

Comment: Yes, but how should I find $b$?

Comment: Try doing the Euclidean algorithm first, and post it here. Then we'll work from there.

Comment: I dont know how to start using it? Help?

Comment: First two steps looks like this: 
$$\begin{align} 
\text{Step 1: } & 5991 = 2 (2014) + 1963 \\
\text{Step 2: } & 2014 = 1(1963) + 51.
\end{align}$$

Comment: Step 3: $1963/51 = (1)1938 + 25$
Step 4: $1938/25 = (1)1925 + 13$
Step 5: $1925/13 = (1)1924 + 1$
Step 6: $1924/1 = (1)1924 + 0$

what next?

Comment: There's something wrong with your computation ...

Comment: Can you point it out?

Comment: The previous divisor should be used as the next sum, and the previous remainder should be used as the next divisor.

$$ \text{Step 3: } 1963 = 38(51)+25.$$

Comment: I did thought didnt I? I did $1938/25$ ?