# Solve $5991x + 289 \equiv 0 \pmod{2014}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, divisibility, congruences

Solve:

$$5991x + 289 \equiv 0 \pmod{2014}$$

$$5991x \equiv -289 \equiv 1725 \pmod{2014}$$

I need to find the inverse of $5991$ modulo $2014$.

Start with Euclid's algorithm:

$$5991 = 2(2014) + 1963$$

$$2014 = 1(1963) + 51$$

$$1963 = 38(51) + 25$$

$$51 = 2(25) + 1$$

$$25 = 25(1) + 0$$

So how should I get the inverse?

Thanks!

Comment: How is this different from you two earlier questions?

Comment: @quid, because I wanted someone to go on from whereI left off. Perhaps that wouldhave helped more. =)

Comment: Okay. Since I already used an order of magnitude more time then I planed on this, and the argument is somewhat reasonable. Hold on. I will give it one more try.

Comment: Note there is a trick to simplify this which is not apparent in the duplicate. The original equation can be recast as $51x\equiv 289$. Then you can divide by $17$, which is not a factor of $2014$ to obtain $3x\equiv 17$. This reduces the work considerably, especially if you also spot that $2031$ is divisible by $3$.

Comment: @MarkBennet, how can it be written like that?

Comment: Well $3\times 2014=6042=51+5991$ so that $5991x=(6042-51)x\equiv -51x$. This means $-51x+289\equiv 0$ whence $51x\equiv 289$

Comment: Note I started by wanting to reduce $5991$ to something smaller to simplify. Looking for factors which can be cancelled to simplify such an equation is also a useful technique. You do have to check that any factors you cancel are co-prime with the modulus (if not there are then other things you can do)

Comment: Perhaps I am seeing double but less than $24$ hours ago there was the same question and in a comment I pointed out the $17$ trick. Don't remember who asked the question, but sasha gave a find the modular inverse answer.

Comment: Yes,but how do you use that trick? How did you do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To calculate the modular inverse one uses the [extended Euclidean algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm). Normally, one can perform this in parallel but with some methods it works also afterwards.

Set $s_0 =1$ and $s_1 = 0$, and calculate $s_{i+1}= s_{i-1}- q_i s_i$ where $q_i$ are the *quotients* you found. Then $s_{k+1}$ is your modular inverse; where $k$ is such that the $k$-th reminder is the $\gcd$. See the linked to site for details.

So:

- $s_2 = 1 - 2 \cdot 0= 1$,
- $s_3 = 0 - 1 \cdot 1 = -1 $,
- $s_4 = 1 - 38 \cdot (-1)= 39$,
- $s_5 = -1 - 2 \cdot 39 = -79$

You are done! The modular inverse is (the class of) $-79$. 
Note that the sequence of the $s_i$ so $1,0,1,-1, 39, -79$ is the exact same sequence and you performed the exact same computations that were performed [in my other answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1116406/how-to-find-inverse-modulo/1116468#1116468)

The only difference is that here we did all the calculations for the right-hand side first; this is what you did, and then did (half) the computations for the left-hand side afterwards. I say "half", as we only computed the coefficient for the $5991$ not for $2014$. Though you could compute it in about the same way; see the calculation of the $t_i$ on the linked to page though it is really the same recursion as for the $s_i$, only the starting values are flipped, so $t_0 = 0$ and $t_1 = 1$.

Comment: Okay. So I suppose next step is to multiply both sides by $-79$?

Comment: Yes. Then you have $(-79) 5991 b \equiv (-79) 289 \mod 2014$ and sicne $(-79) 5991 \equiv 1 \mod 2014$ we have $b \equiv (-79) 289 \mod 2014$. Thus we have found $b$. To make everything a bit nicer we can still compute the producr $(-79) 289$ and reduce it $\mod 2014$ to have a nicer representative.

Comment: so $b \equiv 22831 \equiv 677$ perfect answer!

Comment: Great. I am glad we figured it out in the end. :-)

Comment: Yeah, except that I got 2 downvotes =(

Comment: It is a bit unusual to ask three questions for one problem. So, some got a bit impatient I asume.