# Solve diophantine equation using modular arithemtic

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

Solve for integers, $x, y$

$4258x+147y=369 \implies 4258x \equiv 369 \pmod{147}$

I got this question from SE, but I want to try **this approach.**

I suppose we will find the inverse modulus of $4258 \pmod{147}$ using Euclid's algorithm. So:

$4258 = 28(147) + 142$

$147 = 1(142) + 5$

$142 =  28(5) + 2$

$5 = 2(2) + 1 \implies 1 = 5 - 2(2)$

$$1 = 5 - 2\bigg( 142 - 28(5)  \bigg) = 5 - 284 + 2(28(5))$$

$$= 5 - 284 + 2\bigg( 28\cdot (147 - 142)   \bigg)$$

$$= 5 - 284 + 2\bigg(  28\cdot(147 - 4258 + 28(147))   \bigg)$$

I still dont understand this.

But I am lost in this algorithm, how should I compute further?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that you have got a spare $5$ at the end. It is easier to deal with the brackets as they arise line by line. You will see that each line has two terms

$$1=5-2\cdot (2)$$

Replace $2$

$$1=5-2\cdot (142-28\cdot 5)=-2\cdot(142)+57\cdot (5)$$

Replace $5$

$$1=-2\cdot(142)+57\cdot(147-1\cdot (142))=-59\cdot (142)+57\cdot(147)$$

Replace $142$

$$1=-59\cdot(4258-28\cdot147)+57\cdot(147)\equiv -59\cdot4258 \bmod 147$$

Comment: So what is the strategy? In the end you should have $m\cdot(x)$ where you are trying find the inverse of inverse of $n$ $\pmod{m}$?

Comment: Note you get $-59\cdot 4258$ plus a multiple of $147$ - you don't have to calculate what this is, because you are only interested in the result modulo $147$. The inverse you are looking for is $-59$

Comment: Wait, we have: $1 = -59(4258 - 28\cdot 147) + 57(147)$ So with multiplies of $147$ we get: $-1652(147) + 57(147) = 147(-1605) \equiv 135$ I dont get the same as you. (FROm the LAST line).

Comment: @Amad27 Modulo $147$ we have that $147 \times$ anything $\equiv 0$. So I've just left the multiples of $147$ out, rather than do extra work. To solve your original question, multiply by $-59$ and reduce modulo $147$.

Comment: I dont see one thing here though. How is $-59$ the inverse by not $57$? Because in the last line you also have a factor $57\cdot (147)$?

Comment: @Amad27 That factor disappears because it is a multiple of $147$

Comment: I am confused now as to how to compute inverse modulo at all. Can you show me an easier example first?

Answer (score 1):

The Extended Euclidean Algorithm does just what you want. It keeps track of the forward and backward substitutions. There is an implementation explained in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/68021). Here is how it can be used to solve this equation:
$$
\begin{array}{r}
&&28&1&28&2&2\\\hline
1&0&1&-1&29&-59&147\\
0&1&-28&29&-840&1709&-4258\\
4258&147&142&5&2&1&0\\
\end{array}\quad
\begin{array}{l}
\\
\text{this row times }4258\\
\text{this row times }147\\
\text{their sum is this row}\\
\end{array}
$$
Because we each column is a linear combination of the two previous columns, the top row time $4258$ plus the middle row times $147$ equals the bottom row.

Thus, we have
$$
4258(-59+147k)+147(1709-4258k)=1
$$
Multiply the particular solution by $369$ to get
$$
4258(-21771+147k)+147(630621-4258k)=369
$$
Choose $k$ to get another particular solution. For example, $k=149$ gives
$$
4258(132)+147(-3821)=369
$$

---

Here is the algorithm unrolled to track the $\color{#00A000}{4258}$ and $\color{#C000FF}{147}$:
$$
\begin{align}
142&=\color{#00A000}{4258}-28\cdot\color{#C000FF}{147}\\
5&=\color{#C000FF}{147}-1\cdot(\overbrace{\color{#00A000}{4258}-28\cdot\color{#C000FF}{147}}^{142})=29\cdot\color{#C000FF}{147}-1\cdot\color{#00A000}{4258}\\
2&=(\overbrace{\color{#00A000}{4258}-28\cdot\color{#C000FF}{147}}^{142})-28\cdot(\overbrace{29\cdot\color{#C000FF}{147}-1\cdot\color{#00A000}{4258}}^5)=29\cdot\color{#00A000}{4258}-840\cdot\color{#C000FF}{147}\\
1&=(\overbrace{29\cdot\color{#C000FF}{147}-1\cdot\color{#00A000}{4258}}^5)-2\cdot(\overbrace{29\cdot\color{#00A000}{4258}-840\cdot\color{#C000FF}{147}}^2)=1709\cdot\color{#C000FF}{147}-59\cdot\color{#00A000}{4258}
\end{align}
$$

Comment: (+1)  But how can I do this using:

$$= 5 - 284 + 2\bigg(  28\cdot(147 - 4258 + 28(147))   \bigg)$$

$$= 5 - 284 + 2\bigg( 28\cdot 147 - 28\cdot 4258 + 28^2\cdot 147   \bigg)$$

$$1 \equiv -279 - 56\cdot 4258$$

But this isnt correct? I took out the $147n$ terms because $\pmod{147}$ results that in $0$?

Comment: @Amad27: I have added an unrolled version of the algorithm. Perhaps it is closer to what you want.

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of reverse substitution is to express $1=ar_1+br_2$ where $r_1,r_2$ are some consecutive remainders obtained in the algorithm.

So you need to combine the terms having $5$ after the second step, like so:

$1 = 5 - 2(142 - 28(5)) = 57(5)-2(142)$.

- $= 57(147 - 1(142)) - 2(142) = 57(147)-59(142)$.

Also, I have corrected your mistake: $18\to 28$.

Once you express $1=a(147)+b(4258)$, where $a,b$ are integers, take modulo $147$ on both sides, and you will get $b(4258)\equiv 1\quad(\text{mod }147)$. So $b$ is the inverse of $4258$ modulo $147$.
In the original equation, $x\equiv b(4258)x\equiv b(369)\quad(\text{mod }147)$.

To see why, $x=(a\times 147+b\times 4258)\times x$

- $=b\times 4258x+ax\times 147=b\times 369+c\times 147+ax\times 147$
- $=b\times 369+(c+ax)\times 147$

Comment: So what is the inverse? Mark Bennet said it was (-59) but here I think you are doing something different?

Comment: @Amad27 I didn't want to give you all the working. The idea is the most important.

Comment: I dont understand the idea. which is why I asked which one here is the inverse modulus?

Comment: @Amad27 See my edits.

Comment: I would appreciate it, if you could keep it simple? I am new to this? please see my edits (to the question) and try to comply?

Comment: @Amad27 Do you understand what is the definition of modulo inverse? Given integers $x$ and $n$, we want to find a $a$ so that $ax\equiv 1 \mod n$, which is the same as saying that there is an integer $b$ so that $ax=1+bn$. So this is the **same** as trying to find $a,b$ so that $ax+bn=1$.

Comment: Wait, what is the VALUE of $b$?