# Chinese Remainder Theorem example

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic, chinese-remainder-theorem

$$x = 4 \bmod 18$$

$$x = 52 \bmod 96$$

$$x = 6 \bmod 20$$

My current algorithm thinks the answer is $x \equiv 1066 \bmod 1440$ but I don't think there should be a solution to this.

The algorithm:

```
function solve_congruences(values, moduli):
    u = first value in values
    M = first modulus in moduli
    u = u mod M //just in case

    for each v,N pair from values and moduli:
        v = v mod N
        if u==v:
            M = lcm(M,N)
            skip the rest of this loop (next pair)
        gcdmn = gcd(M,N)
        if u mod gcdmn  isn't equal to v mod gcdmn :
            return NO SOLUTION
        g,a,b = egcd(M/gcdmn , -N/gcdmn ) //extended gcd
        newmod = lcm(M,N)
        u = (u+a*M) mod newmod 
        M = newmod
    return u,M
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @A.P. It seems clear that he's asking some subset of the following: "Is there a solution to the problem I gave? Is 1066 a solution? Does my code work?"

Comment: The program's solution is wrong; 1066 doesn't work mod 52.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We will work these two at a time.

---

Note that $(18,96)=6$ and $4\equiv52\pmod{6}$, so the first two equations are solvable. We need to solve
$$
\frac{x-4}{6}\equiv\begin{bmatrix}0\\8\end{bmatrix}\text{mod}\begin{bmatrix}3\\16\end{bmatrix}\tag{1}
$$
Using the Extended Euclidean Algorithm as implemented in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/68021), we get
$$
\begin{array}{r}
&&5&3\\\hline
1&0&1&-3\\
0&1&-5&16\\
16&3&1&0
\end{array}\tag{2}
$$
which says that
$$
16(1)+3(-5)=1\tag{3}
$$
which tells us that
$$
16\equiv\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\end{bmatrix}\text{mod}\begin{bmatrix}3\\16\end{bmatrix}\tag{4}
$$
and
$$
-15\equiv\begin{bmatrix}0\\1\end{bmatrix}\text{mod}\begin{bmatrix}3\\16\end{bmatrix}\tag{5}
$$
If we add $0$ times $(4)$ to $8$ times $(5)$ we get
$$
-120\equiv\begin{bmatrix}0\\8\end{bmatrix}\text{mod}\begin{bmatrix}3\\16\end{bmatrix}\tag{6}
$$
which solves $(1)$. Therefore, $\frac{x-4}{6}\equiv-120\pmod{48}$, so that
$$
\begin{align}
x
&\equiv-716\pmod{288}\\
&\equiv148\pmod{288}\tag{7}
\end{align}
$$

---

Next we need to solve $(7)$ and the third equation from the question. The GCD of the moduli is $(288,20)=4$, but $6\not\equiv148\pmod{4}$, so the third equation can not be solved with the first two.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct, there is no solution since the final two congruences are inconsistent when reduced mod the gcd of their moduli $\, = 4 = \gcd(96,20),\,$ becoming $\,x \equiv 0,\ x\equiv 2\pmod{\!4}\,$ resp.

Generally a system of congruences is [solvable $\iff$ pairwise solvable.](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1857626/242)