# When a congruence system can be solved?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, systems-of-equations, congruences

How to prove that a congruence system with $n$ equations can be solved if and only if all the equations can be solved two by two?

\begin{cases} x \equiv a_1 \phantom ((mod\phantom mm_1) \\ x \equiv a_2 \phantom ((mod\phantom mm_2) \\ ... \\ x \equiv a_n \phantom ((mod\phantom mm_n) \end{cases}

I know that if $n=2$, the system can be solved if and only if $\gcd(m_1,m_2)\mid a_1-a_2$.

The thesis is: the system is solvable $\Longleftrightarrow$ $\gcd(m_i,m_j)|\mid a_i-a_j$ for all $i\neq j$.

Comment: Do you know the Chinese Remainder Theorem?

Comment: @Crostul This can only be applied if the $m_i$ are pairwise coprime. What can we do if this is not the case ?

Comment: @Ronteg Assuming you know CRT, you can write every $m_i$ as a product of prime powers. Hence, you can add the hypothesis that all the $m_i$ are actually prime powers. Now, consider those having the largest exponent, and you are done.

Comment: So I use CRT and I get an equivalent system where I have more equations with $(mod \phantom n{s_{ij}}^{a_{ij}})$ where $s_{ij}$ is a prime factor of $m_i$. And then?

Answer (score 4):

**Hint** $\ $ Suppose for induction there is a solution $\,x = a\,$ to the first $\,n\!-\!1\,$ congruences, i.e.

$$a\equiv a_i\!\!\pmod{m_i},\,\ i=1,\ldots n-1\tag{#}$$

Combining the solution with the final congruence we obtain the system

$$\begin{align} &x \equiv a\! \pmod m,\ \ m  = {\rm lcm}(m_1,\ldots m_{n-1})\\
 &x\equiv a_n\!\!\!\! \pmod{m_n}\end{align}$$

[We know](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2060729/242) this is solvable iff $\,(m_n,m)\mid a-a_n.\ $  Since [gcd distributes over lcm](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/147992/242) we have

$$(m_n,m) = (m_n,{\rm lcm}(m_1,\ldots m_{n-1}) = {\rm lcm}((m_n,m_1),\ldots,(m_n,m_{n-1})) =: \ell $$

Hence $\ (m_n,m)\mid a-a_n \iff \ell\mid a-a_n\iff (m_n,m_i)\mid a-a_n,\ $ for all $\,i \le  n-1$

$\ \ (m_n,m_i)\mid m_i\mid a-a_i\,$ since $\,a\,$ is a solution of the first $\,n-1\,$ congruences $\,({\#})$

$\qquad\ \  (m_n,m_i)\mid a_n\!-\!a_i\,$ by hypothesis. Therefore it divides their difference, i.e.

$\qquad\ \ (m_n,m_i)\mid a-a_n = a-a_i -(a_n - a_i).\ $  Therefore a solution exists.

**Remark** $ $ Domains that satisfy an analogous Chinese Remainder Theorem (CRT) solvability criterion are known as Prüfer domains. They are non-Noetherian generalizations of PIDs and Dedekind domains. Their ubiquity stems from a remarkable confluence of interesting characterizations, e.g. or Gauss's Lemma for polynomial content ideals, or for ideals: $\rm\ A\cap (B + C) = A\cap B + A\cap C\,,\  $ or the $\rm\, GCD\cdot LCM\,$ law: $\rm\, (A + B)\ (A \cap B) = AB\,,\ $ or $\,$ "contains $\rm\Rightarrow$ divides" $\rm\ A\supset B\ \Rightarrow\ A\,|\,B\ $ for finitely generated $\rm\,A.\,$ See [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/14122/242) for a couple dozen characterizatons (likely over $100$ are known).