# Chinese Remainder Theorem Confusion

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

I need to use the Chinese Remainder Theorem to find
six consecutive integers, each divisible by a prime squared
greater 5.

So I chose to solve these 
$$x\equiv 0 \pmod {49}$$
$$x+1\equiv 0 \pmod {121}$$
$$x+2\equiv 0 \pmod {169}$$
$$x+3\equiv 0 \pmod {289}$$
$$x+4\equiv 0 \pmod {361}$$
$$x+5\equiv 0 \pmod {529}$$

I wrote a program to try and solve it but wasn't able to find a solution, could someone help get me started on how to use the CRT to solve this problem?

I'm not quite sure how to apply it to even tackle this problem..

Comment: That would only be five numbers.   Did you want to require that $x\equiv 0 \pmod {49}$?  That's what you had the first time you posted this question, no?

Comment: Hint:  do it step by step.  Assuming you wanted to require that $x$ was divisible by $49$, write $x=49y$.  Then we need to solve $49y\equiv -1\pmod {11^2}$.  That's easily done via the euclidean algorithm, so we'll end up with some class $\pmod {(7\times 11)^2}$ which satisfies the first two congruences.  Now do the third, and so on.  The numbers will get very large, so you'll want to do it with a machine.

Comment: See [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1897593/242) for an example of the pairwise step-by-step CRT solution method mentioned by @lulu

Comment: Maybe your program ran into some integer size limitations. I put the query `ChineseRemainder[{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, {49, 121, 169, 289, 361, 529}]` to Wolfram Alpha and the answer was almost $32$ trillion.

Comment: The details of the general proof of the CRT can be used to give an algorithm fof solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's solve just one pair of those congruences:
$\begin{align}
x+4&\equiv 0 \bmod {361} &\implies x&\equiv -4 \bmod {361}\\
x+5&\equiv 0 \bmod {529} &\implies x&\equiv -5 \bmod {529}\\
\end{align}$

We can jump into the [extended Euclidean algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm) to find a combination of $361$ and $529$ that solves to their GCD of $1$:

$\begin{array}{|c|c|} \hline
\quad n \quad & \quad s \quad & \quad t \quad & \quad q \quad \\\hline
529 & 1 & 0 &  \\
361 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\
168 & 1 & -1 & 2 \\
25 & -2 & 3 & 6 \\
18 & 13 & -19 & 1 \\
7 & -15 & 22 & 2 \\
4 & 43 & -63 & 1 \\
3 & -58 & 85 & 1 \\
1 & 101 & -148 &  \\ \hline
\end{array}$

where each line solves $n=529s+361t$ and $q$ is a multiplier used to get to the reduced $n$ on the following line. From the last line we see Bézout's identity of $101\cdot 529 -148\cdot 361 =1$, giving $-148\cdot 361 \equiv 1 \bmod 529$.

Then $x=361k-4 \implies 361k+1\equiv 0\bmod 529  \implies k-148 \equiv 0\bmod 529 $ using the result from the Bézout identity, so $k=148$ is a result consistent with the $\bmod 529$ equivalence , and we get

$$ x \equiv 361\cdot 148 -4 \equiv 53424 \bmod 190969 (=361\cdot529)$$

Then this result can be combined with one of the other equivalences, and so on to a (very large) solution.