# how to find the solution to simultaneous congruences

Tags: congruences, chinese-remainder-theorem

Can anyone please help with this problem. We covered the Chinese Remainder Theorem in class, but I'm very confused so if anyone could be please explain each step simply I'd be very grateful.

Find the solution to the simultaneous congruences

x ≡ 17 (mod 37)

x ≡ 9 (mod 17)

x ≡ 6 (mod 7)

Comment: Do you know how to find multiplicative inverses?

Comment: No I don't know

Comment: Please read up on concepts and come back, because while I can explain this, I don't have time to do so. Try working with smaller sums first, and then build up. I am sorry, it's just that I don't know where you are with concepts so I can't answer until that is cleared.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

${\rm mod}\ 37\!:\ x \equiv 17\iff x = 17\!+\!37j\ $ for some integer $\,j$.

${\rm mod}\ 17\!:\  9\equiv x = 17\!+\!37j\equiv 3j\iff j\equiv 3\iff \color{#c00}{j = 3\!+\!17k}\,$ for some integer $\,k$.

Hence $\ x = 17\!+\!37\color{#c00}j = 17\!+\!37(\color{#c00}{3\!+\!17k}) = 128 + 17\cdot 37\, k$

Therefore $\ x\equiv 128\pmod{27\cdot 37}\ $ is equivalent to the first two congruences.

Next solve $\ x\equiv 6\pmod 7\ $ combined with the prior, in the same way as above, i.e.

${\rm mod}\ 7\!:\,\ 6\equiv x\equiv 128 + 17\cdot 37\, k\equiv 2-k \iff k\equiv \,\ldots$

**Remark** $ $ This method of iteratively replacing two congruences by a single equivalent congruence works for any number of congruence - [see here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1857626/242) for a proof.

Comment: how do you go on after this?

Comment: @mathsgirl Exactly the same as when we solved the first two congruences. Solve for $\,k\,$ to get $\,k\equiv a\pmod 7\,$ then substitute $\, k = a + 7n\,$ into $\, x = 128+17\cdot 37\,k.\ \ $

Comment: where  did a come from?

Comment: @mathsgirl That the value of $\,k\,$ that you need to finish solving for above, cf. the $\,\ldots\,$ in the answer.