# On Chinese remainder theorem

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, chinese-remainder-theorem

Suppose we know $x\equiv 3 \bmod 11$ and $x\equiv 7\bmod 13$ and $0<x<143$ holds then CRT gives that  $x=3\times 13[13^{-1}\bmod 11] + 7\times 11[11^{-1}\bmod 13]=39\times 6 + 77\times 6=696$ gives a solution but it is not within $0$ and $143$. So we take $696\bmod 143$ and choose $124$ as solution.

My query is say instead of $3$ we choose $3+11k$ and instead of $7$ we choose $7+13\ell$ for some $k,\ell\in\Bbb Z$ can we still recover $124$?

Instead of $696$ is there a direct way to get $124$?

We have $696=124+4(143)$. In general what is the quantity that goes in instead of $4$?

Answer (score 1):

The direct way to $124$ would be to start with $7$ and see how many $13$s to add to make it into a number that is $3\bmod 11$.

Since $13\equiv \color{red}2 \bmod 11$, we can see that we need $(3-7)/\color{red}2 = -2\equiv 9\bmod 11$ copies of $13$. $7+9\cdot 13 = 7+117 = 124$.

Answer (score 0):

we have $$x=3+11m,x=7+13n$$ from here we get the Diophantine equation
$$11m-13n=4$$ with Solutions $$m=11+13k,n=9+11k$$ plugging this in the equations for $x$
$$x=124+11\cdot 13k$$ thus we obtain $$x=124$$ for $$k=0$$

Comment: it must be $11m$ sorry

Answer (score 0):

Some people do CRT theorem problems like this.  If $x\equiv 3\pmod{11},$ then $x = 3+11k$.  Plug that into $x \equiv 7 \pmod{13}$ to get $3+11k \equiv 7 \pmod{13}$ which reduces to

$$11k \equiv 4 \pmod{13}$$

$$-2k \equiv 4 \pmod{13}$$

$$k\equiv -2 \equiv 11 \pmod{13}$$

So $x = 3+11\cdot 11 =124.$

Comment: nice $\mbox{     }$

Comment: does this always work??? even if we do mod 13 first  and 11 second and also for any pair (replace 13 and 11 by variables and 3 and 7 by variables) of modular residues

Comment: Yes.  And if you have more congruences, you can continue by plugging in $x = 124 + 142n$ into the next congruence and repeat.  The official CRT requires the moduli to be relatively prime, but this method doesn't.  It will find the solutions (if they exist.)

Comment: Well, with all those variables flying around, it's going to be harder to solve the second congruence, for sure.  And if you don't know the values of these 4 variables, it will be hard to know how big or small your answer is.

Comment: In my case instead of 3 I have a $2Ak_1+3Bk_2$ and instead of $7$ I have $5Ak_1-3Bk_2$ where $A,B$ are known coprime and $k_1,k_2>0$ are unknown but smaller than $A,B$ and instead of $11$ I have $2A-B$ and instead of $13$ I have $2A+B$ ($A,B$ have to be treated as known variables). I do not see how to still express $k$ in your setting properly without introducing another $k_3$ since I know $x>0$ is of size $<AB$. I will get $k\equiv \alpha A+\beta B\bmod 2A+B$ and if I use $x=2Ak_1+3Bk_2+(2A-B)(\alpha A+\beta B)$ I will get incorrect $2Ak_1+3Bk_2+(2A-B)(\alpha Ak_1+\beta Bk_2)>AB$

Comment: clarified above comment

Comment: @Robut See [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1857626/242) for a proof that it always works. You can find worked examples in the list of linked posts there.