# Is it possible to solve this congruency system?

Tags: modular-arithmetic, chinese-remainder-theorem

I need help to determine if this congruency system can be solved and if it can be solved how do I do it:
$$\begin{cases}x\equiv2\text{ (mod $3$)}\\
x\equiv4\text{ (mod $6$)}\\
\end{cases}$$

I do know that from the system I obtain the following:

$$\begin{align}
x\equiv2\text{ (mod $3$)}\\
x\equiv4\text{ (mod $2$)}\\
x\equiv4\text{ (mod $3$)}\\
\end{align}$$

I do not know what to conclude from here. I think this system doesn't have solution, but if it is so how do I prove it.

Comment: kind of like a regular system of equations with $x=2$ and $x=4$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$x=6k+4\implies x=3(2k+1)+1$$

Thus if $$x\equiv 4\pmod {6} $$ then $$x\equiv 1\pmod 3$$

That is the system

$$\begin{cases} x\equiv 2 \pmod{3} \\ x\equiv 4 \pmod{6} \end{cases}$$

is not consistent.

Answer (score 3):

Doesn't have solution, since 
$$\begin{cases} x\equiv 2 \pmod{3} \\ x\equiv 4 \pmod{3} \end{cases}$$
they implie $2\equiv 4 \pmod{3}$, but this is false.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork Not true, why do you believe that?  The answer is fine as written.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork  It seems you may be confusing congruences with remainders. See e.g. [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/614944/242) for the definitions.

Answer (score 1):

$\begin{align} {\bf Hint}\qquad\ \ \  2+3j &= x = 4 + 6k\,\Rightarrow\ 3\,j-6\,k = 2\,\Rightarrow\, 3\mid 2,\,\ \rm contradiction.\\[.5em]
{\rm generally}\ \ \ a+mj &= x = b + nk\,\Rightarrow\, \color{#c00}mj-\color{#c00}nk = b-a\,\Rightarrow\, \bbox[6px,border:1px solid #c00]{\color{#c00}{\gcd(m,n)}\mid b-a }\end{align}$

i.e. $ $ they're consistent $\!\iff\!$ they become  equivalent when  reduced mod the $\rm\color{#c00}{gcd}$ of the moduli.

The above *necessary* condition for a solution to exist is also a [sufficient](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2060729/242) condition. Furthermore,  a system of congruences is [solvable $\iff$ pairwise solvable](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1857626/242) as above.

Answer (score 1):

$6k+4=3y+2\implies y=k=-{2\over 3}$ repeating every time k changes by 1 (y by 2) ,  which then means, they aren't integer solutions for k snd y.