# About the solvability of a system of congruence

Tags: modular-arithmetic

I am asking if there is any method to decide if the following system of congruence is solvable or not:

$x_{1}$≡$a_{1}$ $mod (y_{1})$

$x_{2}$≡$a_{2}$$mod (y_{2})$

$x_{3}$≡$(a_{1}+a_{2})$$mod (y_{3})$

Here $y_{1},y_{2},y_{3}$ are not necessarily coprime integers

Comment: By the [CRT solvability criterion](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1856879/242)  it is solvable $\iff (y_1,y_2)\mid a_1\!-\!a_2,\,$ $\,(y_1,y_3)\mid a_2,\,$ $\,(y_2,y_3)\mid a_1$ $\qquad$

Comment: @BillDubuque: We have not the same $x$ as in the CRT. We have three distinct integers.

Comment: Oops, missed that. Now reopened. Which symbols are variables (vs. constants or parameter), i.e. what are you solving for?

Comment: @BillDubuque: the variables are x1,x2,x3.

Comment: So we are given all $a_i$ and $y_i$ and you seek to find $x_i$ satisfying those congruences?  If so they are independent and you can trivially solve each separately, e.g. $\,(x_1,x_2,x_3) = (a_1,a_2,a_1+a_2)\,$ is a solution.

Comment: @BillDubuque: They are not independent as equation 3

Comment: Independent means that a variable $x_i$ doesn't appear in more than one equation so you can solve for $x_i$ from the lone equation it occurs in.

Comment: @BillDubuque: Can we find sufficient and necessary condition for the solvability.

Comment: It's always solvable. I gave one simple solution above.