# Number Theory - Remainders

Tags: number-theory

A number is of the form $13k_1+12$ and of the form $11k_2+7$

That is $N = 13k_1 + 12 = 11k_2 + 7$

Now why must N also equal $(13 \times 11)k_3 + 51$ ?

Thanks

Comment: What've you tried?

Comment: @ArpitKansal I've tried getting k1 in terms of k2. 51 seems to be the smallest value of N that satisfies the above conditions

Comment: Note that N=7(mod 11) and N=12(mod13) Can you say something from here?

Comment: @ArpitKansal Not really. A little new to this. Sorry

Comment: Do you know CRT(Chinese Remainder Theorem)?

Comment: @ArpitKansal Nope. Will look it up. Thank You

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alternately, $N=13k_1+12 = 11k_2+7 \implies N-51 = 13(k_1-3)=11(k_2-4)$

Thus $N-51$ must be a multiple of both $13$ and $11$.

Comment: Elegant and beautiful

Comment: Usually the trouble is in finding $51$, which @robjohn has so meticulously explained in his post below...

Answer (score 0):

Let me give a trick. We have $N + 92 = 13k_1 + 104 = 13(k_1 + 8)$ and $N+92 = 11k_2 + 99 = 11(k_2 + 9)$.

Then, $N+92 = 11\times 13 k_3$ or $N = 143k_3 -92$ or $N=143k_4 + 51$.

See also [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem)

Comment: Don't re-use $k_3$ for another value. $N=143(k_3-1)+51$.

Comment: Uhm, OK, I changed it to $k_4$. :)

Answer (score 0):

$N$ as defined is $12$ mod $13$ by first definition and $7$ mod $11$ by second definition, since both $13$ and $11$ are relatively prime (in fact primes) thus $N$ should have same mod ($13 \times 11$) as well, rest follows by manipulating the $12$, $7$ remainders with $13$, $11$

Answer (score 0):

**Finding a Solution**

To find an $N$ so that
$$
\begin{align}
N&\equiv12&\pmod{13}\\
N&\equiv7&\pmod{11}
\end{align}\tag{1}
$$
we can start by solving
$$
13x+11y=1\tag{2}
$$
using the Extended Euclidean Algorithm. The implementation described in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/68021) gives
$$
\begin{array}{r}
&&1&5&2\\\hline
1&0&1&-5&11\\
0&1&-1&6&-13\\
13&11&2&1&0\\
\end{array}\tag{3}
$$
which implies
$$
13(-5)+11(6)=1\tag{4}
$$
Using $(4)$, we can show
$$
\begin{align}
66&\equiv1&\pmod{13}\\
66&\equiv0&\pmod{11}
\end{align}\tag{5}
$$
and
$$
\begin{align}
-65&\equiv0&\pmod{13}\\
-65&\equiv1&\pmod{11}
\end{align}\tag{6}
$$
$12$ times $(5)$ plus $7$ times $(6)$ gives
$$
\begin{align}
337&\equiv12&\pmod{13}\\
337&\equiv7&\pmod{11}
\end{align}\tag{7}
$$
Subtracting $2\cdot11\cdot13=286$ from the left sides of $(7)$ gives
$$
\begin{align}
51&\equiv12&\pmod{13}\\
51&\equiv7&\pmod{11}
\end{align}\tag{8}
$$

---

**Finding a General Solution**

If $N_1$ and $N_2$ are any two solutions to $(1)$, then
$$
\begin{align}
N_1-N_2&\equiv0&\pmod{13}\\
N_1-N_2&\equiv0&\pmod{11}
\end{align}\tag{9}
$$
Therefore,
$$
N_1-N_2\equiv0\pmod{11\cdot13}\tag{10}
$$
Putting together $(8)$ and $(10)$, we get that all the solutions of $(1)$ are given by
$$
N\equiv51\pmod{143}\tag{11}
$$