# Solve an algebra equation

Tags: abstract-algebra

Solve in $Z_{601}$ the following equation:

$327x + 208 = 0$

How do you solve this one ? I am clueless, I have searched everywhere and I cannot find a somewhat close solved example.

Comment: Have you looked at the [extended Euclidean algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm)? Use that to solve $327x-1=0$ in $\Bbb Z_{601}$, then use that solution to find your desired one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to find the inverse of $327\bmod601$. This done done with the *Extended Euclidean algorithm:*

$$\begin{array}{l@{\qquad}rrrr}
     \hline
\text{Successive Divisions}& r_i & u_i & v_i & q_i\\
 & 601 & 0 & 1 & \\
601= {\color{red}1} \times 327 +\color{blue}{274} & 327 &1 & 0 & \color{red}1 \\
327 = {\color{red}1} \times 274 + \color{blue}{53} & \color{blue}{274} & -1 & 1 & \color{red}1 \\
\hline
274 = {\color{red}5} \times 53 + \color{blue}{9} & \color{blue}{53} & 2 & -1 & \color{red}5 \\
 53 = {\color{red}5} \times 9+ \color{blue}{8} & \color{blue}{9} & -11 & 6 & \color{red}5 \\
 9 = {\color{red}1} \times 8+ \color{blue}{1} & \color{blue}{8} & 57 & -31 & \color{red}1 \\
  & \color{blue}{1} & -68 & 37& \\
     \hline 
\end{array}$$
Thus we have the *Bézout's relation:* $\;-68\cdot327+37\cdot 601=1$, which implies 
$$327^{-1}\equiv -68\mod 601$$
and
$$x=-327^{-1}\cdot 208=68\cdot208\equiv 321\mod 601.$$

Comment: what does $u_i$ and $v_i$ represent?

Comment: The Extended Euclidean algorithm asserts that not only the last non zero remainder has Bézout's coefficients $u$ and $v$, but also all intermediate remainders $r_i$ have too; it is these coefficients that I denote $u_i$ and $v_i$ (the index $i$ corresponds to the $i$-th division of the Euclidean algorithm). The two given numbers are considered as remainders of index $-1$ and $0$  respectively. Is that clear?

Comment: not really, I don't understand how to compute them for each step, and why at the end they equal to $-68$ and $37$....

Comment: Well, there is a linear recurrence relation between the successive remainder: from the $i$-th division, $\;r_{i-1}=q_ir_i+r_{i+1}$, which can be written as $$r_{i+1}=r_{i-1}-q_ir_i$$. By projection we have the same relation between Bézout's coefficients: $u_{i+1}=u_{i-1}-q_iu_i$. Thus to create a further line, you take what is found two lines above, and substract $q_i$ times the above line.

Comment: why is $ 601 $ $0$ $1$ as starters? are $0$ and $1$ chosen arbitrary ?

Comment: No: it means $601=0\cdot327+1\cdot 601$ (and similarly $\;327=1\cdot327+0\cdot 601$). That is the initialisation of the recurrence (which is of order $2$, I recall).

Comment: I understand now, thank you so much :)

Comment: You're welcome. I didn't give a full justification of the computations, hoping  the layout  of the algorithm would speak for itself, maybe with the help of Wikipedia…

Answer (score 3):

We want to solve

$$\begin{align}327x &\equiv -208 \pmod {601}\\
&\equiv 393 \pmod{601}\end{align}$$

By using the [extended euclidean algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm) one has

$$327 \cdot (533) + 601 \cdot (-290) = 1$$

or taking everything modulo $601$,

$$327 \cdot 533 \equiv 1 \pmod {601}$$

By the definition of inverse, $327^{-1} = 533$ (in $\mathbb{Z}_{601}$). Hence,

$$\begin{align}x &\equiv 393 \cdot 327^{-1} \pmod{601}\\
&\equiv 393 \cdot 533 \pmod{601}\\
&\equiv 321 \pmod {601}\end{align}$$

so we conclude that if $x$ gives a remainder of $321$ when divided by $601$, then it is a solution. Hence $x = 321 + 601n$ for $n \in \mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, but I don't understand why $393 * 533 (mod 601) ≡ 321$, can you please elaborate?

Comment: You may multiply out $393 \cdot 533 = 209469$ as per normal and use long division by $601$ to show that $393\cdot533 = 209469 = 348\cdot 601 + 321$.

Comment: So after I did $393⋅533$ and got $209469$ I divided it by $601$ and the result is $348.5341$ but I still don't understand how to come up with $321$

Comment: You need to use the non-calculator method to come up with the quotient and remainder for the division. The remainder will turn out to be $321$.

Comment: ohh I see now, it's $209469 - 348*601 = 321$ got it, thanks :D

Comment: another question, how do I know that $327^{-1} = 533$ ? in $Z_{601}$ , I mean, how do I find it fast? without computing every number from 0 to 600 in order to find it.

Comment: From the extended euclidean algorithm, we have shown that $327 \cdot 533 \equiv 1 \pmod {601}$. Since $533$ is the number that gives $1$, the identity element, when multiplied with $327$, then by the definition of an inverse element, $533$ must be the inverse element of $327$.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another implementation of the Euclidean Algorithm.

Using the [Extended Euclidean Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm) as implemented in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/68021) to solve
$$
327x+601y=\gcd(327,601)
$$
we get
$$
\begin{array}{r}
&&1&1&5&5&1&8\\\hline
1&0&1&-1&6&-31&37&-327\\
0&1&-1&2&-11&57&-68&601\\
601&327&274&53&9&8&1&0
\end{array}
$$
This says that
$$
601(37)+327(-68)=1
$$
which means that in $\mathbb{Z}_{601}$
$$
327(-68)=1
$$
Multiply by $-208$ to get
$$
327(14144)=-208
$$
so the answer is $14144=321$ in $\mathbb{Z}_{601}$.