# Modular arithmetic for a beginner

Tags: discrete-mathematics, modular-arithmetic

I am a student who is struggling terribly with Discrete Mathematics 2. I've already changed my major from computer science to IT because it's just not a great fit for me but I'd still like to leave this course with some knowledge seeing as I've spent a great deal of money on college to begin with.

I am having trouble understanding modular arithmetic and I have to solve these two problems by hand:

$$89 ^ {307} \bmod 713$$

$$49 ^ {307} \bmod 713$$

If anyone could show me how to even approach this I'd be thankful. My class is learning through theorems which isn't helpful at all. I need this to be broken down like it's being taught to a 3 year old. Thank you for your help in advanced.

Comment: https://www.khanacademy.org/computing/computer-science/cryptography/modarithmetic/a/what-is-modular-arithmetic

Comment: What do you mean with "by hand"? Can you specify which operations are permitted? Your teacher sounds a bit sadistic...

Comment: @A.P. this doesn't take all that much computation given a few tricks-see below. Without the tricks, well...

Answer (score 3):

Start by factoring into primes, $713=23\times 31$. We'll first find $89^{307}$ modulo $23$ and $31$, and combine those answers to get the final one. Modulo $23$, $89$ is equivalent to $-3$, since it's $4*23-3$. So we're calculating $(-3)^{307}$ modulo $23$.

Now you need to use one of these theorems, namely "Fermat's little theorem," which says that $n^{p-1}\equiv 1\pmod p$ for any prime $p$. That tells us that $(-3)^{22}\equiv 1 \pmod{23}$, in this case.  Then $(-3)^{44}=((-3)^{22})^2\equiv 1^2\pmod{23}$, and similarly for bigger multiples of $22$: this leads to the common strategy in problems like this of cancelling out multiples of $p-1$ from the power we're taking. That is, since $307=308-1$ and $308$ is a multiple of $22$, $(-3)^{301}\equiv (-3)^{-1}\pmod{23}$. So we have to find the multiplicative inverse of $-3\pmod{23}$, i.e. we need $x,y$ so $-3x+23y=1$. We have $2=23+7(-3)$ and $1=-3+2*2$, so $-3x+23y=-3+2*2=-3+2(23+7(-3))=15(-3)+2(23)$, which shows $15$ is the inverse of $-3$ modulo $23$. What I've done here is run the Euclidean algorithm backwards-if you don't know the algorithm you'd better look it up.

Now, modulo $31$, we're doing $89\equiv -4$ to the $307\equiv 7$, and here we basically just calculate directly: $(-4)^7=(-4)(-4)^2(-4)^4\equiv (-4)(-15)(8)\equiv 15(\pmod{31})$. So, $89^{307}$ is $15$ modulo both $23$ and $31$, and so it's also $15$ modulo $713$! This follows from another theorem, usually called the Chinese Remainder theorem.

Comment: Just to clarify my comment: of course I looked at the CRT and Fermat's little theorem! The whole computation would have flown fairly well for me -- although maybe it would have taken me a bit longer to find the multiplicative inverse of $-3$ modulo $23$ -- if it weren't for the very first step. Maybe you have some trick for it, but factoring $713$ by hand is almost too computational heavy for me to do by hand, even though I do have a master's degree in mathematics... :P

Comment: Factoring 713, @A.P.? You can see at a glance that it’s not divisible by any prime less than $17$. For that prime, add $713+17=730$, $73+17=90$, so not divisible by $17$; for $19$, add $57$ to get $760$, so not divisible by $19$. Subtract $23$ from $713$ and get $690=30\cdot23$, so there’s your factorization. No pencil.

Comment: @Lubin a nice technique!

Answer (score 1):

Two tools are required for this kind of problems: the *Chinese remainder theorem*, which is used to solve systems of simultaneous congruences via  *Bézout's identity*, and the *little Fermat's theorem*. I'll try to show from the first problem.

First, as $713=23\cdot 31$ and the factors are (co)prime, $\;\mathbf Z/713\mathbf Z\simeq \mathbf Z/23\mathbf Z\times \mathbf Z/31\mathbf Z$. The interesting isomorphism is from right to left: if you have a pair of congruence classes: $\alpha\pmod{23}$ and $\beta \pmod{31}$, it corresponds to the congruence class of 
$$ 23u\beta+31v\alpha\mod 23\cdot31, $$
where $u$ and $v$ are the coefficients of a *Bézout's identity* between $23$ and $31$, say
$$ -4\cdot 23+3\cdot 31=1. \tag{1}$$
Now as $89\equiv 20\mod23$, we have $89^{307}\equiv 20^{307}\mod 23$. Furthermore, by *Little Fermat*, $20^{22}\equiv 1\mod23$, so $20^{307}\equiv 20^{307\bmod22}=20^{-1}\mod23$.

We find the inverse of $20\bmod23$ with *Bézout' identity*:
$$7\cdot 23-8\cdot 20=1$$
which shows $\;20^{-1}\equiv-8\equiv\color{red}{15}\mod23$.

Similarly, $89\equiv -4\mod31$, and
$$89^{307}\equiv -4^{307\bmod30}=-4^7=-2^{14}\mod31.$$
Furthermore, $2^5\equiv 1\mod 31$, hence $$89^{307}\equiv -2^{-1}\equiv \color{blue}{15}\mod31. $$

Thus we have to solve the system of congruences $\;\begin{cases}x\equiv 15\mod23\\ x\equiv15\mod31\end{cases}$. We just have to apply formula $(1)$:
$$x\equiv-\color{blue}{15}\cdot4\cdot23+\color{red}{15}\cdot3\cdot31\equiv15\mod713.$$

Comment: I fixed a couple of typos for you. Hope you don't mind...

Comment: @AP.:Not at all. I know I should re-read what I write more carefully. Thanks!

Comment: Where you find the inverse of 30 mod 23 with Bezout' Identity, where does the 7 multiplied by 23 and the 8 multiplied by 20 come from?

Comment: It comes from the *extended Euclidean algorithm*. You'll find an example of how it runs in an answer to [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1476934/extended-euclidean-algorithm-what-is-our-answer/1477045#1477045)