# fine the inverse of $[2]$ and $[23]$ in$ \mathbb{Z}_{41}$

Tags: inverse, equivalence-relations, congruence-relations

I know the inverse of [23] is

[23] * [25] = 575

575 congruent to 1 mod 41

[25] is the inverse

I have started the other one but I am doing something wrong I got

[2] * [41] = [82] = [0]

82 congruent to 0 mod 41

I thought 41 would be the inverse but it is not.

Comment: What about $21$, what happens when you multiply by $2$?

Comment: it seems like that would work so would 21 be the inverse then?

Comment: Yes The inverse of $2$ modulo any odd number is easy.

Comment: You are welcome. In more general situations, and in particular when the modulus is not small, something systematic like the Extended Euclidean Algorithm needs to be used.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a general method for finding the inverse of $a$ in $Z_n$:

- Set $x_1=1$
- Set $x_2=0$
- Set $y_1=0$
- Set $y_2=1$
- Set $r_1=n$
- Set $r_2=a$
- Repeat until $r_2=0$:

  - Set $r_3=r_1\bmod{r_2}$
  - Set $q_3=r_1/r_2$
  - Set $x_3=x_1-q_3\cdot{x_2}$
  - Set $y_3=y_1-q_3\cdot{y_2}$
  - Set $x_1=x_2$
  - Set $x_2=x_3$
  - Set $y_1=y_2$
  - Set $y_2=y_3$
  - Set $r_1=r_2$
  - Set $r_2=r_3$
- If $y_1>0$ then output $y_1$, otherwise output $y_1+n$

---

And here is an equivalent code in C:

```
int Inverse(int n,int a)
{
    int x1 = 1;
    int x2 = 0;
    int y1 = 0;
    int y2 = 1;
    int r1 = n;
    int r2 = a;

    while (r2 != 0)
    {
        int r3 = r1%r2;
        int q3 = r1/r2;
        int x3 = x1-q3*x2;
        int y3 = y1-q3*y2;

        x1 = x2;
        x2 = x3;
        y1 = y2;
        y2 = y3;
        r1 = r2;
        r2 = r3;
    }

    return y1>0? y1:y1+n;
}
```

Calling `Inverse(41,2)` returns $21$.

Calling `Inverse(41,23)` returns $25$.

Comment: That is an implementation of the *Extended Euclidean algorithm*.

Comment: @Bernard: Thank you for the enlightenment, I wasn't aware of that (I just used it "as is" during Cryptography course for hw assignments, etc).

Comment: You might be interested in a ‘naive’layout in the form of a table that can be performed by hand, and may be easier to follow for non-programmers. I gave a few examples in some answers, such as [this one](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1476934/extended-euclidean-algorithm-what-is-our-answer/1477045#1477045).